# Site JavaScript broken when trackers are blocked

Tags: support, new-nav

As of this morning, the JavaScript that powers at least the dropdowns in the nav (related to [the A/B test?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav)) loads only through tracker scripts instead of being embedded directly, which means that users who use Ghostery or other privacy tools have broken functionality.

I'm getting a "jQuery is not defined" in the console, followed by knockon errors.

Comment: What do you mean "through tracker scripts"?

Comment: Check your access to all of the domains listed in [this MSE answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/262823). It's likely because you can't access either cdn.sstatic.net or ajax.googleapis.com.

Comment: @Oded Meaning that instead of including jQuery through a `<script>` tag, it's relying on (for example) the Google Analytics script to load it instead.

Comment: @ArtOfCode It's not because I "can't access" them. It's because trackers are *blocked*. There's no good reason to break the rest of the site's functionality if someone has privacy extensions enabled.

Comment: No repro. It's still loading jQuery in a `<script>` tag for me. You should know Stack Exchange better than to assume they hate you for using privacy extensions by now.

Comment: We *do* include jQuery through a `<script>` tag. You should be able to see it in the page source: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` - if `ajax.googleapis.com` is being blocked on your end, that's the problem and the solution is to not do that.

Comment: Most of stackoverflow just broke for me in the last half hour for the reason described in this post. I use Ghostery as well. My browser error console shows all kinds of errors that were not there an hour ago. I had to use the Stackexchange app on my phone to post this comment.

Comment: I couldn't even log in until I disabled ghostery... : /

Comment: It seems that I can get things working again if I tell Ghostery to allow Google AJAX Search API. This wasn't an issue an hour ago. I don't know what changed.

Comment: @rmaddy - probably the lists that Ghostery uses to block stuff. Guess those got updated, you got the update, and the update borked Stack Overflow. I am not a Ghostery user, so don't know if it is possible to add an exception for Stack Overflow or to inform them of this issue.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Ghostery, it looks like they are now blocking the Google AJAX Search API.

I don't know why, but this is likely what's causing the problems.

---

I've contacted Ghostery and they said they are looking into this issue. Hopefully this will result in a quick update to their block rules that will resolve the issue.

---

Latest news from Ghostery - they are pushing a fix, so this should be resolved soon!

Comment: Anyone using Ghostery should totally switch to [uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin). It's open source and it isn't made by an advertising company.

Comment: You can also add an exception for this website in the Ghostery settings or simply allow the Google AJAX Search API (which is disabled in my version too)

Comment: @Stijn Sadly, uBlock Origin [does not support macOS](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/issues/977).

Comment: It seems Ghostery fixed the issue.