# Low contrast in the nav headers in the New SO Nav (currently in testing)

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar, a-b-testing

[image]

Overall, I love the new nav that's [currently being tested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav).

The organization makes more sense to me, and it's got a nice, updated look. My one suggestion:

**Consider more contrast/visual signals for the text, containers, and glyphs.** Aesthetically, I love the subtle, clean look.  But my aging eyes have trouble finding the various boxes, and have to work a bit to read the text, and make out what each icon is.  It's not that I *can't* read em, but it takes some real focus.

I think this issue is a *lot* more common for folks like me who are... past their thirties, shall we say?

Comment: I didnt know we were going to a new one...one request I have please make it easier to "ASK A QUESTION" it is very difficult to find or see this button.  For pete's sake you guys did it well in other SE sites such as workplace.stackexchange.

Comment: I'm in my twenties and find it hard on the eyes.

Comment: @JonH For reference: [We're Soon to be A/B Testing Some Changes to the Top Nav](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav)

Comment: That's arguably a feature on Stack Overflow, @JonH...

Comment: @animuson yes now I see it - thanks!  I for one like the change as I found black not so nice!

Comment: Is there any way we can opt-in to this?

Comment: Log out and IP-hop until you see it, @Undo.

Comment: Undo I dont think so - it looks to be something that just randomly comes up for anon users?

Comment: Another request - make it easier to log out...Most places have the log out on the top right - SE goes against this and tucks it away on the top left menu?  WTF.

Comment: @Shog9 - I hope you're kidding I know you guys want to avoid people asking questions but its just plain old wrong for the wrong reasons.

Comment: Go look at the screenshots in the linked post, @jon - may not work, but... Getting folks to read more before asking ain't a bad goal.

Comment: @JonH making it easier to log out is something we're going to fix in phase 2.

Comment: Put the search bar on a new line. Make it the entire width. Make the font size large. Change the search button to say "Ask". Move the ask question button to the bottom of the search page with a banner saying: "Didn't find what you were looking for? Ask a new question". This would force the user to have to look at search results for their question before asking a new question. It might also benefit from a better search algorithm(s)

Answer (score 1):

I like the minimalist look and abscence of the black stripe makes it overall better design. I cannot however agree with one-line layout. It makes it too condensed and as you mention, too low contrast makes it hard to distinguish elements.

What I would like to see (it is just a rough sketch):

[image]

So more **space**, bigger logo, glyphs, and I would still like to see more graphical filling, probaly a very slight texture or color for main buttons.
And I'd remove initial capitals from button names.

Most important: new design should not contradict with user styles, namely I never use white background, which hurts my eyes. So if I slightly change background color, it should still be more or less consistent.