# Mysterious new site header appears on Sundays with dates ending on 8

Tags: support, design

I have been using Stack Overflow every day (except for 23rd-26th December) for the last couple of months on several different desktop PCs.

On Sunday 18th December 2016 and on Sunday 8th January 2017 the old black site header (the one that Stack Overflow had for a while and appears on every other Stack Exchange site) got mysteriously replaced with this header:

[image: mysterious new header]

but only as long as I *wasn't logged in*. On every other day Stack Overflow had the same, old black bar header.

The first time this happened I thought it was just some redesign deployment hiccup - somebody accidentally pushed HTML/CSS to live servers - but now I'm just bamboozled.

What's going on?

I see that the new design is [an upcoming beta design](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav), but why is it appearing on live servers for a single day at time and for anonymous users only?

Comment: The devs [mentioned that it's random](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288662/new-stack-overflow-navigation-bar/288663#288663) :)

Comment: That uncanny ability of humans to [see patterns everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia)...

Comment: I hope they use that design. It looks so much better.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Presumably, they are doing some Google-style A/B testing on the new nav-bar concept.
But they're only doing it for anonymous users because they haven't yet figured out what to do with the "extra stuff" that is displayed for established users.

> […] Also not pictured is the 10k / mod icons and stuff. Right now we're just confirming some assumptions regarding how it will better distribute the anon traffic across the various parts of the site. If we get that right, then everything else can fall into place. If the test fails, then there's little sense in working on this concept much more.
>
> [– Tim Post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav#comment411722_337745)

I still wish they'd increase the contrast a little or otherwise demarcate the header more clearly from the body of the page. It doesn't have to be **black**, but it shouldn't be the same white, either.

Comment: I personally wish the borders offered less contrast. I like the new nav bar for the most part, I just don't like how boxed-in it looks with those borders.

Comment: @tiny I *like* the boxing off. Maybe a good compromise would be putting the thick orange bar *underneath* the top nav, instead of at the top? That would create a clear visual separation between it and the main page content.

Comment: I do like the separation between the bar and the page content, I just don't like the obnoxious visual block between nav elements. IMO, they don't even need borders between nav elements, a slightly darker background color on hover would suffice.

Comment: Oh, right. The things that are supposed to be buttons, but can't actually be buttons because they are flat. The Xerox Alto called, it wants its UI back.

Comment: Didn'cha hear? [Everything is flat now](https://envato.com/blog/deeper-look-flat-web-design-trend/). At least it isn't all [Web2.0](https://www.google.ca/search?q=web+2.0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-7428mrPRAhUCjlQKHaMUA50Q_AUICSgC&biw=1743&bih=864) or [skeumorphic](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/skeuomorphism).

Comment: Where can I express the fact I despise the change?

Comment: I'm guessing by posting an answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav), @jpmc. Or by starting a new Meta rant—err, I mean question. :-)