# Tags with boolean search gone,after opting for beta

Tags: discussion, bug

Yesterday,i opted for beta phase of [new navigation system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon?cb=1)..Now i don't see either new navigation system or the tags i used to use for boolean search..

All i could see is below

[image]

**Update:**
Will it be possible to go back  to old navigation system (along with my boolean tags) or the  new one ..I unticked the options  and its been three hours

I was able to get boolean search back

Comment: [499 rep or below only](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon?noredirect=1&lq=1), unfortunately.

Comment: This is [new navigation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing), what you're referring to is the new top bar (confusingly also called *navigation*). And above that, if you opted in: what @approxiblue said is true for the first 1 - 3 weeks (probably 6 to 8 weeks) after that higher reps can opt-in.

Comment: Thanks Guys,how can i get my  old view @rene

Comment: remove the tick in the new navigation in your profile?

Comment: @rene:I did it three hours back,but still no luck