# Pop-up messages shown under the new top-bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

I got the [new top-bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon?cb=1) (even if I'm >34k rep).

The issue is, pop-up messages such as the "successfully created job alert" one are displayed *under* the new top-bar.

[image]

Tested with Vivaldi browser, so I assume it's the same with chrome (at least).

Comment: thanks for reporting that. will fix it asap.