# The new menu doesn't fit on a 1080px screen

Tags: bug, status-norepro, top-bar

I do have a second monitor which is vertical.

The new menu doesn't fit in 1080px and I can't see everything in it.

Would it be possible to use % instead of px ? Or at least manage to have a responsive menu on md and gt-md screen ?

Comment: Don't hold your breathe for a response... I've found this community isn't very [responsive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design)...

Comment: According to [this comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon?cb=1#comment434464_341837), the width should still be the same as before

Comment: Browser/Version/OS?

Comment: @Tanner: right, you tried to make a joke. Sorry if I missed it! Perhaps if you added *italics* for emphasis instead?

Comment: @Tanner I missed it too! Sorry! (Too used to people complaining about the community and being serious.)

Comment: @BSMP Chromium 55.0.2883.87 Built on Ubuntu, running on Ubuntu 16.10 (64-bit)

Comment: I wanted to take a screenshot but the menu has been rolled back to the previous one.

Comment: @Maxime Something's wonky with the A/B testing, if you refresh a few times you should get the new menu again (hopefully).

Comment: You were not supposed to be part of the A/B test, so this isn't really something we can respond to at this time. The width of the top bar has not changed, but what you have seen may be due to it being designed for lower reputation users than you.

Comment: I have tested with 1080px, and the top bar exactly fits that resolution.

Comment: I have the "does not fit"-problem with the old bar too.  Chromium on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: @Oded Ubuntu also has the vertical launcher (with icons) which makes the screen narrower.

Comment: @Thor - be that as it may, the point is that the top bar width has not changed.

Comment: I did test that on my second screen and I don't have the menu bar on that screen