# How to go back to the old top bar?

Tags: support, top-bar

How can I change the theme of the site back to the normal black bar and all of the rest? It just changed right now without any warning and I want it back. Currently, it looks like this:

[image: screenshot of front page with new top bar]

How it used to look like (this is the top-bar from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)):

[image: screenshot of front page with old top bar]

Comment: Agreed. Do not like.

Comment: Didn't anybody backup the old navs HTML?

Comment: Get the CSS of the old one and create a Stylish profile for stackoverflow.com and if you like to change the DOM, then you could use a Greasemonkey script.

Comment: @TomášZato It's only active on SO and MSO currently. The rest of the network still uses the "old" top bar.

Comment: I personally like the change, I think it looks a lot cleaner. I just wish it had been rolled out to the other sites at the same time.

Comment: What don't you like about it? It looks cleaner, fits with the site better and all the old stuff is still there....

Comment: I notice your avatar failed to load.

Comment: Personally, I do not care for it either. There is too little contrast and visual distinction between the elements. Too much solid white (or even gray) and everything blurs together IMO.

Comment: I didn't like it at first, but I got used to it in about a day... meh.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, that's just because I was using a internet that blocked some IPs and other stuff. Couldn't even come [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) unless I used google translater to show me the page with no CSS nor JavaScript.

Comment: So many upvotes and that, I guess I'm not the only one searching and discusting this topic. I don't mind that they change, but please add a button for the people who want it as it was.

Comment: Damn I hate change.  You'd think they would have given people a choice for a year or so and see which one people preferred. Guess I'll get used to it and just +1 my (relatively low) resentment counter for SO.

Comment: Most people don't like it when you change the UI, even if the newer UI is substantially better, so UX folk wait for a few weeks before they start considering feedback :)

Comment: My biggest concern isn't aesthetic, but rather that when I double-click some text the search bar to edit (such as the text between `[..]`), it expands to the left and doesn't actually select (usually catches the trailing `]`)

Comment: For me the problem is that the notifications have moved far to the right, and if I zoom in the page they disappear :(. I was happy with the notifications always present on the top of the page.. Is there a way to reverse this?

Comment: So much irony in this new theme! Programmers don't tend to like bright things!

Comment: I literally clicked one link after another within seconds and saw the change happen in front of my eyes – fascinating. I like the new theme; if I didn't, I'd just have to suck it up like any other change I've seen, disliked, but knew deep down was coming soon enough.

Comment: Wow, this is my most popular question, and first one on meta (migrated). Extreme explosion, thank you all. Hope we do get the option to choose one day. The change got me out of nowhere. Sites tend to try to change  eventually but they should know that people love the original way they remember the site as. Anyway, I won't be discusting nor arguing any of this.

Comment: @Hrishi Most people don't like it when you change the UI, so it'd be nice if UX folk would only do that when the new version *is* significantly better.  Consistency with users' expectations is important.  We were all used to the old version, and now everything is in a new place for no clear gain.  (It'll probably be a bit less annoying once the rest of SE changes too; at least then I won't be getting my old reflexes reinforced every time I go to another SE site.)

Comment: My biggest problem is that the things that I'm used to being on the left are now on the right, and vice versa.

Comment: I looks soooo much better on Meta. The only different is the black vs. orange top bar. That makes a real difference. Can we please use the black bar for the main site also? I think the orange was just to bright for me. Anybody else feel the same?

Comment: @TheBitByte They've been testing it for weeks and feedback has been consistently quite negative.

Comment: You, my friend, is institutionalized . Give it time!

Comment: Personally, the layout changes do not concern me much. I can adapt to those in time. However, the lack of contrast created by the flat, almost-white-on-white theme presents some real usability issues to those without perfect vision, and unfortunately that is not something that will be solved by "giving it time". The eyes have to work just a little bitter harder every time they search the screen, and when you consider how many times a day that happens it makes for a less than pleasant experience IMO.

Comment: MAH CHEESE!? where has it gone?

Comment: @Leigh, +1, it is very reasonable... well explained my own thoughts... Guys common.. you change was liked only by half of community.. give us black theme magic button...

Comment: @Maxim - A theme button would be great. After trying it for a day, I finally gave up and resorted to creating a quick and dirty theme using Stylish. It is not very "pretty", but it gave my eyes some sorely needed relief ;-)

Comment: huge usability issues by the flat white on white color theme, and the damn bar won't go away. Hate it. yuk

Comment: @Diederik not every complaint about the new bar is a "who moved my cheese" type complaint. Most are, but not all, most notably the loss of contrast.

Comment: related - https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296965/256963

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is the new top navigation. It was available for testing during the past weeks/months, and just now went live for everyone. For some info, see [Top Navigation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update) and related posts. There's also [a blog post](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/?cb=1) explaining the design decisions.

You cannot change it back into the old one, but you can do some things to change it to something you like better:

- If you don't like it being sticky, [there's a preference to change that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation).
- If you don't like the light theme and prefer a dark theme instead, [you can apply a community-provided dark theme](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343106/247702). You can also vote on the answer if you wish to see an official dark theme.

Comment: Was it really that difficult to have an official dark theme that one could easily switch to?

Comment: @camden_kid: Nothing else on the site is themed. Why should this be?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit "You can also vote on the answer if you wish to see an official dark theme". That seems to me that an official dark theme is a possibility. So why not just implement it if it's not difficult? If it is difficult to do then fair enough.

Comment: @camden_kid: In engineering, you need a reason to do things, not a reason to not do things.

Comment: `If you don't like it being sticky, there's a preference to change that.`  It's a pity that you have to select that option on **every** site.

Comment: @YowE3K I can't find the source right now, but the devs have said that there are some technical challenges to overcome for that to be possible.

Comment: @YowE3K: All two sites, such a burden.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - I had thought that the intention was to role this out to **all** sites at some (not too distant?) future time.  So, although it is only two sites at the moment, why wait until it annoys a **lot** of people before fixing an issue.

Comment: @YowE3K: That'll take a fair amount of design effort, so while it's certainly nice to get on it, it's not quite as urgent as all that.

Comment: Don't worry, the preferences will be SE wide along with the keyboard shortcuts one @YowE3K someday... we have hope!

Comment: hmm, I don't need a switchable theme - but more contrast between the nav bar and the site would be nice^^

Comment: @camden_kid Where do you read that quote about voting on an answer in order to get an official dark theme?

Comment: @TylerH It's the last sentence of the second bullet point.

Comment: Disable sticky bar preference doesn't work correctly. :( Works on the preference page only. how strange. Neigh

Answer (score 25):

I made a similar comment [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343738/new-navbar-live#comment447484_343738):

> I don't particularly dislike the new theme but I spend my time on 3 SE
>   sites regularly. It's very annoying to switch between the two layouts.
>   **Wonder if I can stick to the old one until the change is rolled out to**
>   **all SE networks** so that I can get some sense of consistency? From what
>   I have seen on meta so far, **I think the answer is no?**

[Oded♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) [replied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343738/new-navbar-live#comment447533_343738):

> NSNoob - sorry, I don't think I got you. **There will be no way to
>   revert.** We are going to consolidate the design on other SE sites to
>   match this new design.

So no there is no way provided officially by SE to revert to the old navigation and there are apparently no plans to provide an option to users either.

Comment: *"So no there is no way to revert to the old navigation."* No way provided by SE, but an individual user still can revert the top bar using browser plugins like Stylish (for CSS styles) and Greasemonkey (for JavaScript). Just sayin'.

Comment: Cheers, edited to reflect that.

Comment: @Oded♦: So just consolidate everything to the old design, what's the big deal?

Comment: @einpoklum - very funny.

Comment: @Oded♦: (shrugs) I call'em like I see'em.

Answer (score 14):

For Firefox/Chrome/Vivaldi, install the Stylish extension:

- [Link for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/stylish/)
- [Link for Chrome-based browsers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish-custom-themes-for/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=fr)

Then install a custom theme that looks like the old one:

- Get this one that looks nice: https://userstyles.org/styles/138640/stack-black-slim-header?autofb#discussions-area
- Click on the "Install" button

Then do not forget to disable the stickyness in your profile ("Edit Profile & Settings" tab):

[image]

Then to get rid of those useless buttons (I'm talking about "Jobs", "Documentation", the search bar (you want to use google instead) and the [distracting review icon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343663/870604)), add the following rules to your favorite ad-blocker:

```
stackoverflow.com###nav-jobs
stackoverflow.com##.js-review-button.-link
stackoverflow.com###nav-docs
stackoverflow.com##.js-search-field.f-input
```

*Et voilà*, something usable again:

[image]

Comment: +1 for practical solution. This is much better than having SO team spend time to add and maintain legacy modes every time they change something.

Comment: Thaks for posting this. By the way I actually use SO search quite often for searching tags, my own posts etc...

Comment: Any help for Safari browser users in terms of going back to the old theme (black bar & narrower)?

Comment: It looks very ugly, because icon and text colors are not adjusted.