# Header is too tall

Tags: support, design, top-bar

Something has happened just now: the header has grown too tall and it blocks the top part of the content:

[image]

This happens in Firefox and in Safari, logged in or out.

---

### Added:

The issue is solved now.

Comment: what version of browser do you have?

Comment: Clicked on this question expecting a complaint about the team's design choices but... nope, this is a little worse than that.

Comment: @Paweł Safari 5.0.6, Firefox 16.0.2.

Comment: Wow...that is an old version of firefox.

Comment: i'm sory @michael.hor257k we don't support those browsers anymore..

Comment: @Paweł Not a good answer. I don't expect support - I do expect backwards compatibility.

Comment: @michael.hor257k We always shoot for graceful fallback _where it's possible_, but it isn't always possible. Hate that this inconveniences you, but there's just no way we it could fail in a better way on a browser that old. Safari, for instance, is at 10.0.3 - _five_ releases ahead.

Comment: Is there a good reason to not update your browser? These updates also include security related fixes, so it should be important for everyone.

Comment: @Tom Yes, there is.

Comment: @michael.hor257k and that is?

Comment: Even if you need these old versions for something specific which doesn't support the newer versions (which already sounds _really_ bad), I would prefer a different browser which I keep up-to-date and use for everything else. Like another installed Firefox or even something else, like Chrome.

Comment: @Tom If I had the option to use another browser, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: @michael.hor257k well, Stack Overflow is a modern site. If it would always support all browsers, even 20 years back, it will never be able to move forward.

Comment: That said, I do agree that in this specific case, some fallback is expected, even showing some basic navigation for old browsers. Worth a new feature request.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Have you tried "Disable Stickyness" in your Settings to see if it at least scrolls off the top of the screen?

Comment: Can you tell your browser to stop using all of the CSS altogether? It won't be pretty but it should prevent things from overlapping.

Comment: @ShadowWizard To be honest, I'd go one step further and disagree that fallback should be expected. There's no good reason for the general public to be running browsers this far behind.

The more websites that take the hard lined approach of not supporting them, the quicker web developers can move on to using modern CSS / JS features without worrying about crappy fallbacks for a user base refusing to move past 2012.

Comment: @berry120 I agree, but fact is that many users just have no choice, and SO will simply lose good users for a pretty lame reason. Even if only 0.01% of the people still using those old browsers, that's thousands of people. And I'm not talking about making everything work for them, just the basic stuff.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Where should the cut off be if you think 0.01% is unreasonable? Or do you think there shouldn't be a cut off at all?

Comment: @BSMP Any browser that supports HTML 4 and CSS 2 should be usable.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Eh? You mean HTML5, right? Or you're saying that Stackoverflow, in 2017, should basically support all browsers from the late *90's* onwards?! That's what - IE5.5+, all versions of Firefox, all versions of Chrome, all versions of Opera created since they abandoned their trial model...

Comment: @michael.hor257k Strongly disagree. It's on you to upgrade to a reasonably modern browser. Stack Overflow has absolutely no obligation to continue to support your browser just because your browser happened to work in the past. You're using Firefox from 2012 and Safari from 2010. If you can't upgrade, **that** is the problem you need to address.

Comment: @meagar Your pontificating is not helping anyone, least of all me.

Comment: @michael.hor257k did you EVER code something on the web dude? If you have you will quickly realize that maintaining previous versions is untennable. As much as I do sympathize... I don't believe we can expect Stack to NOT update because of users on 5 year old browsers...

Comment: @michael.hor257k clearly your issue is not going to be addressed by StackExchange, and their stance is understandable. For your immediate needs however, have you considered writing some custom CSS to fix the header in your browser? I'd normally recommend a Firefox addon like Stylish but it probably won't be compatible with something as old as FF16.

Comment: Expecting anyone to develop something that doesn't keep up to date with the latest advances in that field is just baffling, either way I've voted to close this as it doesn't appare to seek input or discussion and honestly appears more like a troll.

Comment: Is "PowerPC" part of the reason you can't upgrade? If so, TenFourFox exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a Firefox 18 to test, but maybe [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343937/new-navigation-bar-layout-is-completely-broken-in-ie-10/343979#343979) is going to help you. If not, I'm sorry, but that's all we're going to do.

Comment: If by "this" you mean something that happened within the last hour or so, that's actually not too bad, so thank you. I disagree with you on the priorities, but as I said before, I am not here to argue. Just FYI, you have helped not only me, but also the people that I help here.

Comment: Yes, it was deployed shortly before you posted your comment (and the word "this" is a link to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343937/new-navigation-bar-layout-is-completely-broken-in-ie-10/343979#343979, I could have been a bit clearer about that).

Answer (score 29):

Your browsers are too old and no longer supported. See [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) for additional information:

> So here's the bottom line for this question: we support the last two versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use. This does not include beta/dev releases, which are not supported.

Comment: By the way, don't we have a canonical version of this on MSO yet? I tried searching but couldn't find any.

Comment: Not a good answer. You changed something, and now you're shifting the blame to me. I suggest you fix whatever you broke just now and let me get on with my life.

Comment: I'm not a developer, I'm a user like you. And you are using outdated browsers that aren't even supported by the browser vendors anymore, it's unrealistic to keep supporting such old browsers. Safari 5 is nearly 7 years old, and Firefox 16 is nearly 5 years old.

Comment: Can I add, that for various reasons, I have the same problem. Given that the last title bar worked, is there any way in which there can be a title bar for old browser users (e.g. like the old title bar)? I cannot update my browser for a while...

Comment: @A.N.Other [No, that's not possible](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343735/how-can-i-go-back-to-the-old-top-bar). If it's any consolidation, it's not yet active on the rest of the network, just on SO and MSO currently.

Comment: I am not interested in arguing. I am in no position to upgrade now. I got along just fine up until about 20 minutes ago. I continue to get along on other sites. Please FIX THIS.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't have, nor plan to have, an instance of IE 7 handy. But try to use Gmail o Google Maps, or Google Docs, with IE 7 and see how close you get to the real experience. While I'm all for backwards compatibility, I know it comes with an associated cost. Personally, I'd prefer SE to devote resources to other rather than to keep an "SO Basic" for old, unsupported clients. But that's my opinion only, I see what you are saying and find it respectful nevertheless.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Things are only going to get worse as time goes on. For example, Bootstrap in version 4 has dropped support for older browsers and is fully flex box. When that is released, I suspect you will see *many* sites not working for you any more. So yeah, I have sympathy if you absolutely cannot upgrade your browser, though you haven't given us a reason for that so it's hard to say more than that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use "Mobile view" instead (until the new header is also implemented to mobile view, but seems it won't)

The link to switch to "mobile"/"full site" is on the footer.

[image: mobile view switcher on footer]

Answer (score 1):

```
body > div.container {
  padding-top: way more than 60px;
}
```

Your browser doesn't support flexbox. If you can add your own styles through your browser, you can push the container div down more than the 60px of padding the site currently gives it.

Alternatively, you could turn off all CSS in your browser.