# New navigation bar layout is completely broken in IE 10

Tags: support, design, top-bar

The new top bar layout is completely broken in IE 10, I was barely able to ask this question because the search bar is on top of the title input box!

[image: Top bar in IE 10]

Looks like it might be the same problem as [in Safari here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343755/header-is-too-tall) but IE 10 is just one version behind so I believe SO is supposed to support it.

Comment: IE10 is old and not supported. It doesn't support flexbox which is standard now. We can't hold back the web forever just because an old version of IE doesn't work properly.

Comment: @TinyGiant isn't the policy the current version and the previous one? IE11 is latest, so IE10 should be supported, no? *we support the last two versions of the browsers that we see the vast majority of our visitors actually use.*  from http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: @TinyGiant that's making it sound like supporting IE10 would make introducing the new nav impossible. Which isn't correct. It's rather a question of cost (the effort to write the additional CSS needed for things to display ok in IE10) vs. benefit. Personally, my gut feeling would be that investing the time to support IE10 *is* worth it - a lot of folks can be trapped in ancient working environments that are beyond their control. Hell, I've seen recent questions on SO about how to add a certain feature to *IE6*.

Comment: IE Edge is the latest, IE11 is the previous @rene

Comment: I'm not even asking for full support but at least in non-fixed bar mode it should be able to contain its brokenness inside a div at the top.

Comment: @TinyGiant Edge claims to be on a new engine. IE11 is the latest Internet Explorer, IE10 being the previous one. Edge is mentioned separate in the MSE post as well.

Comment: Interesting. Well, I don't support supporting browsers that don't support standards, but if SO wants to support it then I guess that's fine @rene.

Comment: @TinyGiant I see. I already got a very slight feeling, hardly obvious, that you didn't like IE10....

Comment: Where would you ever get that idea? :P @rene

Comment: 10 isn't even supported by MS is it? Wasn't it just 9 and 11, until they recently dropped 9?

Comment: @KevinB No, it is still supported on Windows Server 2012 and Windows Embedded 8 and other places where you cannot get IE 11. IE 11 is the last version of IE ever so 11 and 10 will always remain the two most recent versions.

Comment: Not supporting browsers that don't stick to standards is respectable, but in the real world people sometimes don't have a choice.

Comment: [Microsoft has officially dropped support for versions older than IE11](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) except the following: Windows Vista SP2 (IE9), Windows Server 2008 SP2 (IE9), Windows Server 2008 IA64 Itanium (IE9)
Windows Server 2012 (IE10). I personally think SO should just introduce a basic HTML / CSS only version for older browsers that don't support current standards. That way we could actually move ahead in the world because there will never (AFAICT) be a new version of IE, or we will always be stuck with what IE10 supports and nothing more.

Comment: eh, i'd say just keep it broken in said old browser.

Comment: I can only reproduce this when I put my IE11 in IE9 mode, I cannot reproduce it when I put it in IE10 mode. Can you check with F12 if the page is rendered with an older version?

Comment: @rene By the "IE11 is latest, so IE10 should be supported" logic, we would have to support IE10 until the end of time because IE11 is the *last* IE.

Comment: @balpha For a site as big and as relevant as SO, 10-15 years after release should be expected as far as support for major browsers goes.

Comment: @Magisch 10 years?! Are you serious? Nobody should have to support 10 year old browsers.

Comment: Don't understand the downvotes. Even if Tiny's answer is valid (I tend to think it is), that doesn't make the question bad or wrong. And yes I know how votes work on meta!

Comment: For the record I upvoted this because it's a good duplicate target for others having the same issue.

Comment: Maybe this is a dumb question, but why does the new top bar require flexbox functionality anyway? You built a responsive navbar on a site whose content is not responsive.

Comment: @Cory it's mainly for the expanding search bar and making the search bar fill the remaining space AFAICT. There are other ways of going about it, but none of them are as clean and maintainable as flexbox.

Comment: @DavidG I was asked to make a training course that ran on "both IE6 and iOS Safari using the same code" only 3 years ago (the client even had the audacity to say "HTML5" as the spec). Maybe it was 4 now.  Even if it was *five* years ago, that still made IE6 **11 years old** at the time.  TL;DR I was successful, it looked like ass, and the client decided that that really wasn't what they wanted (so we rebuilt it in Flash).

Comment: @Draco18s Well yes, there's always someone who has to do these horrible things. But, for "real life", especially SO nobody should have to do that. The SO team are in control of the list of browsers they choose to support, and I imagine that the ones they don't support account for less than 0.1% of all traffic.

Comment: @DavidG And those choices are reasonable choices. Not saying they're not. Just saying that there are some people who are stuck on browsers they can't update because the organization that controls their device can't allow an update because it would break a critical piece of software they spent a million dollars on and don't want to have to pay someone another million to rebuild it on a newer platform. (haha "a piece" haha, more like *everything they use*).

Answer (score 38):

All recent browsers (in particular, all browsers that we support, which excludes IE10) support `flexbox`. Making the new top bar work correctly in non-`flexbox` would be a significant amount of extra work that we're not willing to do for the very few people stuck on those old browsers.

That said, I just played with it for a few minutes, and found a cheap way to make the top bar not completely unusable in those older browsers. This will be in the next build of the site, but it comes with a few caveats:

- It requires JavaScript. Doing it in pure CSS puts an extra maintainability burden on us.
- I'm not promising anything. It's making the page slightly less broken for certain browsers, but this doesn't mean that we consider that case supported now, and if something is *still* broken with this hack applied, that doesn't mean that I'm going to fix that.
- I'm also not committing to having hacks like this in there forever.

I know that nobody *wants* to continue using those old browsers; in many cases, it's corporate IT policy that prevents an upgrade. But we have to pick our priorities; at some point, we cannot justify the amount of work anymore.

Comment: You know that just then you'll make a huge amount of people who really need it and can't upgrade browsers unable to properly use SO at all, right?

Comment: You know that those people are probably used to the web being broken and barely usable if at all, right? The future is nigh, regardless of how many IT departments want to live in the insecure dark ages. @Magisch

Comment: Something has changed now and I can see the top bar getting fixed after the page loads, thanks!

Comment: @Magisch Then maybe they'll finally upgrade their browsers once they notice that their programmers' productivity plummets.

Comment: @Magisch Understand IE10 and older do not support TLS 1.1 and 1.2 by default (it can be enabled for IE10). The PCI consortium had to back off their TLS 1.2 mandate for that reason, but they will still require that change soon (June 2018 is their deadline). If corporations can't be convinced to upgrade the Internet in general will leave them behind (SHA1 deprecation is already doing this). A CSS header is the least of their worries

Comment: @Anders do you have a new screenshot to see how _less-broken_ it looks now?

Comment: "*Making the **new top bar** work correctly in non-flexbox would be a significant amount of extra work...*". Then don't do it for the new top bar, the old top bar worked fine just backdrop to it for older browsers.

Comment: Since corporate IT users will probably also be using Stack Overflow (and SuperUser) then perhaps the new top bar will be a great catalyst to get them to upgrade their users!

Comment: I was going to complain about this, but to be fair IE10 is barely used any more according to statistics. Then again, some backward-compatibility would be kind.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia It looks great now after the fix, the site logo is not exactly centered in the bar but everything else looks pixel perfect and seems to work correctly! (You can see it is broken initially as the page loads but then the onLoad? handler snaps every element back into the top bar)

Comment: Thank you so much for fixing this - this has solved the problem for me completely!!!