# Get new navbar icons back on the left again?

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

I feel like I am just so used to the inbox/etc icons being on the left. As if somehow I "memorized" them being on the left all the time, so any change just makes them look a bit "weird" to me.

Could you consider adding an option to allow users to revert the position of the icons? That also includes getting the search bar back on the top right like it was.

On an unrelated note, this might be only me, but I also don't like a permanent search bar every time I scroll.

My suggestion would be to have options that reduce the search bar's size, or just keep it at the top like it was.

This means you can keep doing improvements for the rest of the users, and those who do not like them can simply un-select the options they do not want, instead of removing them entirely.

Comment: It is very unlikely that SO is going to implement a setting for every part of the new top bar that someone doesn't like.

Comment: Of course. You're just suggesting to do it for _this thing that you don't like_. Then once that gets implemented, everyone else is going to come on asking for a setting to change the thing that they don't like. Eventually we have a page full of settings that require a manual to navigate.

Comment: And I'm sure everyone else who finds something they don't like about the site would rather have an option on the site instead of implementing a userscript. It just isn't feasible.

Comment: Related to "permanent search bar": [We're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343483/2675154)

Comment: Also somewhat related: [How can I go back to the old top bar?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343735/2675154)

Comment: I would personally prefer to have the icons back on the left again.  Just like EVERY other StackExhange site.  Just my .02 cents but judging from the amount of negative comments I've seen, I'm far from the only one who hates things being on the right now.  The age old engineering adage comes to mind here:  "If it ain't broke, why fix it?"

Answer (score 4):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159766/33499), the following userscript does the basic reordering:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        so-reorder
// @namespace   wimh
// @description top-nav reorder
// @include     *://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @version     2
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// allow pasting
// ==/UserScript==

// css is sufficient for the basic reordering
GM_addStyle ( "                                    \
    .so-header .-container { display: flex; }      \
    .so-header .-container .-main { order: 2; }    \
    .so-header .-container .-actions { order: 1; } \
" );

// move the logo and siteswitcher back to the front
try {
  var container = document.evaluate("//*[contains(@class, 'so-header')]//*[contains(@class, '-container')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; 
  var logo = document.evaluate("//*[contains(@class, 'so-header')]//*[contains(@class, '-logo _glyph')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; 
  var siteswitcher = document.evaluate("//*[contains(@class, 'js-site-switcher-button')]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; 
  container.insertBefore(siteswitcher, container.firstChild);
  container.insertBefore(logo, container.firstChild);
} catch(e) { /*alert(e);*/ }

// fix position of site switcher dialog if button has been moved.
GM_addStyle ( ".siteSwitcher-dialog { top: 50px !important; left: 50px !important;}" );
```

Comment: Thanks!  What would it take to get the site-switcher button to be all the way on the left, instead of after the logo, user name/badges, and help link?  Is that easy or hard?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I updated the script. Note that I had to fix the position of the site-switcher popup too, I set it to 50 pixels from the top left, which might not be good for every window size. So you might have to change that. If you or anybody else wants to improve the script, go ahead!

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I don't have edit privs here on meta, but if you make the URL match `*://*stackoverflow.com/*`, it works on MSO too (and both http and https).

Comment: See also [Option to bring comments and inbox to the left side of the navigation bar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344231/33499)