# User configurable header strip in Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

Earlier today, I signed up for Ask Ubuntu to post a couple of questions.

Ask Ubuntu reminded me quite how much I prefer the old-style black-backgrounded status-header thingie than the wishy-washy pale one SO regrettably acquired earlier this year. I realise this is just a personal preference, but why can't it be a user-configurable preference on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Do you want the old top bar, or do you want the new top bar in black?

Comment: @Chicken:  Either, really.  I suppose a black new top bar would be easier to implement,

Comment: Fairly sure someone's done a theme thingy for this somewhere...

Comment: Here's a dark theme: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343106/6214222

Answer (score 2):

There are currently no plans to enable the dark theme for the new top bar on SO. Quoting [New top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live):

> Color - The top bar needs to be black on network sites, since that works best with the many themes. The SO top bar color was a branding decision and won't be changed to black.

You cannot go back to the old top bar either. One of the reasons is probably because maintaining two versions of the top bar drains resources. See [this quote from a developer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343764/247702):

> NSNoob - sorry, I don't think I got you. **There will be no way to
>   revert.** We are going to consolidate the design on other SE sites to
>   match this new design.

Comment: It's a strange "branding" decision if users actively dislike it and can't change it.