# The new top bar covers the "JavaScript is needed" banner

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface, top-bar

When browsing Stack Overflow without JavaScript enabled, or when the JavaScript code failed to load for some reason (before the introduction of the [new top bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon?cb=1)), one would get a red banner at the top of the page telling you that JavaScript is needed or that "scripts from another domain are blocked or failed to load".

Now, the new top bar covers that banner (presumably due to z-index ordering) - if I delete it with developer tools, I can see that it's still there, just covered:

[image: Screenshot]

Can the z-index ordering for this be fixed?

Comment: Make sure you fix it with JavaScript though ;).

Comment: This is the problem with removing the header (topbar) from the flow of the page.

Comment: I am surprised, how can anything that hides a "JS is needed" message not be called a feature?

Comment: It's back. Since ~12:00 EDT.

Answer (score 12):

One main problem with creating a "sticky" or non stick top bar was that using `position:fixed` *or* `position:absolute` will remove the element from the document flow. This means that other elements do not consider the header when positioning themselves. To combat this, the main content of Stack Overflow unilaterally has a padding to the top of 60 pixels.

If you look at the `noscript` HTML it looks like this:

```
<noscript><div id="noscript-padding"></div></noscript>
```

Looking at the included CSS, the definition for #noscript-padding is

```
#noscript-padding {
    padding-top: 1.9em;
}
```

Which is insufficient to overcome the top bar. This definition should be

```
#noscript-padding {
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

In order to be visible starting after the top bar.

Optionally it could also be:

```
#noscript-padding {
    padding-top: 60px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

which would avoid pushing the main content down another 60 pixels creating a rather large gap, so long as the message saying <strike>"needs more jQuery"</strike> "works best with JavaScript" is not taller than the 60 pixels whitespace allotted between the top bar and the content.

Comment: They could also prepend it to whichever element is offset by `60px` already.

Comment: This seems to call for a convoluted evolution of the infamous spacer gif.

Comment: As noted, the definition for padding-top is already present. In addition, padding-top is already in use in the main content of the page to offset the top bar (in fact, this has been used in many places, such as making the colored underline for current tab). Convoluted? I am sorry that this seems hard to follow, but it is rather direct and inline with already in use practices. Perhaps you should read up on this at the W3C https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_static_and_relative_positioning , https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS_absolute_and_fixed_positioning , https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html

Comment: Looks like this was fixed a while ago now... By making the JS banner push the topbar down instead of the reverse.

Comment: @Shog9 - It appears what they did was to include a style rule inside of the noscript element, `body,.top-bar{margin-top:1.9em}` which essentially gives the message the space it needs.

Comment: Yep, that's the one. @TravisJ