# Stack Overflow has a different design for HTTP and HTTPS. How do I use this feature for our sites?

Tags: discussion, design

I have found this changes on Stack Overflow from a few days back.

I have seen two different designs on the Stack Overflow site on `http` and `https`.

**Link**: https://stackoverflow.com/

**Design**:

[image: HTTPS design for Stack Overflow]

**Link**: https://stackoverflow.com/

**Design**:

[image: HTTP design for Stack Overflow]

**I am curious: How are they changing the design for the same site for a different protocol?**

The question is not related to this question:

*[We're Soon to be A/B Testing Some Changes to the Top Nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav)*

The question is:

**How is Stack Overflow managing the changes only for some users or some protocols? How can we also implement this feature for our system?**

Comment: The updated question, "How can we also implement this feature for our system?", is off-topic here.

Comment: @CodyGray Could you migrate it to stackoverflow?

Comment: No, I cannot. No one can. Nor would it be on-topic there.

Comment: So i suppose it is a trash question then. Deleting the question if that is so.

Comment: You will need to make the question a lot more specific and detailed if you want to ask it on Stack Overflow. Describe exactly what you're trying to do, how your web server is configured, etc.

Comment: It IS a duplicate of the A/B testing question, which contains the clue that "If you arrive to the site anonymously".  Your browser maintains separate sets of HTTP and HTTPS cookies; **the site is not acting on the protocol, but on the cookies sent by your browser**.

Answer (score 6):

That's the [new Stack Overflow navigation bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav). It's randomly assigned to testers and the [developers have stated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon?cb=1) that "users with 499 rep or below stand a good chance of seeing the new top navigation".

You're one of the lucky few that made it to the [test group](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288662/new-stack-overflow-navigation-bar).

Comment: I have got the answer you have stated, but my question doesn't mean` why  am i getting the changes` but it is for `how are they doing the changes??`