# Help test the new Top Nav: phase 3 testing runs this week

Tags: discussion, top-bar

We’ve completed [two](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav) [rounds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon) of A/B tests  and we’re ready for phase 3, a final round of testing before we release the new site wide navigation to all users on Stack Overflow (English) and MSO. If you’d like to participate, just [go to your user settings under Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current#newheader-status) and opt in to the "New Site Navigation test".

**Results of the previous tests**

Both previous tests showed great results: users shown the new top nav clicked navigation links 143% more than those shown the current design. This leaves us reasonably confident in the utility of making these tools more accessible. But, there are still a large number of people (including most of our most avid users) who haven’t been involved, so for this final round of testing we want to open it up to everyone; if you weren’t part of the A/B tests, now is your chance to kick the tires!

The goal of this week’s test is to uncover any bugs we missed. Once we’ve resolved any major bugs, we’ll roll it out for everyone. Please create a new post with the [top-bar](/questions/tagged/top-bar) tag or post an answer to this question if you find new bugs.

As always, we appreciate your feedback.  While there won’t be any major feature changes between now and the first full release, we’ll consider all your ideas for future updates.

Comment: @Andy thanks for the heads up. Will have someone look into it!

Comment: Can we opt back out if we opt in?

Comment: Also do you consider color improvements to be a 'major feature change'?

Comment: Finally! I've been waiting for this my entire life.

Comment: @TylerH yes, you can for the duration of the test.

Comment: @TylerH yes any design change like color would have to be retested before releasing. Will make note of the request though as feedback to consider as we iterate.

Comment: Is more clicks necessarily a good thing? I'd think that you'd want to minimize the number of clicks users make, a more than doubling of clicks sounds concerning.

Comment: @bjb568: That depends on whether it's an increase in *clicks per task* or *tasks clicked on*; it doesn't seem plausible that it's entirely one or the other, so a breakdown would be necessary.

Comment: FYI: it looks like auto-activation is disabled for this, meaning someone has to manually approve folks after they check the box. I don't know if this is an oversight or if there's some intent at rate-limiting here, so I'll wait for a dev to check the queue in the morning (probably the UK morning, so relatively soon). In the meantime, nothing's broken - there are currently 72 of you waiting for your access to be activated.

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga not sure what you're talking about. we've added some sort of responsiveness for slightly smaller screen sizes than 1060px. should works fine. can you post a screenshot or something? maybe separate question tagged as bug if you consider it as a bug..

Comment: @AmaniKilumanga the way you can opt-in is described in question you're commenting :) (you may also need to [wait](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week?noredirect=1#comment443712_343103) until someone manually activate it for you)

Comment: is it by design that the ask question button is dropped when you are on the home tab? I'm also using new nav in case that matters.

Comment: So how sure are you that the +143% nav link clicks are not due to the lack of contrast confusing people, leading to misclicks all the time? :P

Comment: @rene 'ask question' button has been moved to top of the sidebar of some views.

Comment: @AndrasDeak 50% sure :)

Comment: I have enabled auto activation and enabled the new header for everyone who opted in before that.

Comment: FYI, I forgot the bar was sticky. I opted out again as soon as I noticed. (So, as soon as I left the preferences and started scrolling. ~5 seconds, maybe?)

Comment: @HermannDöppes i think you're super fast, that's really impressive.

Comment: @Paweł Thank you. Would you sign my petition to make this an Olympic discipline?

Comment: Yet more pointless blank space eating up my screen. Please reduce the vertical spacing everywhere outside text blocks.

Comment: Please leave the navigation bar as is. White is a bad choice, and sticky is a bad choice. Change for the sake of change is no good.

Comment: @HermannDöppes I didn't know it was sticky, opted in, kinda liked it at first and then quickly opted out when I scrolled down and realized it

Comment: Every phase I have looked in on this I see complaints about the contrast and sticky bar. It makes me wonder if you really "appreciate your feedback.". Considering the comments and posts are consistently the most heavily upvoted.

Comment: Am I the only one who still likes the old design of the site? :/ *cries*

Comment: @WhiteShadow Obviously not, that's why we all are complaining.(OK, technically we just might hate the current design less than the new one, but this is a minor nitpick.)

Comment: @HermannDöppes same here.  Removing sticky headers is one of my most frequently created custom adblock rules.

Comment: The colors and the positions of elements make the new bar a *regression*. You should consider reworking it *before* a first release.

Comment: I actually like the sticky bar. I've had a Tampermonkey script running for a while to make the old one sticky. The new design does feel like it takes up a bit of space but maybe that's just me getting used to it. I also agree that a dark theme is needed. I've already started running the dark theme linked by Steven Penny to compensate.

Comment: Even though I know the difference between the "new nav" and the "new top bar," I was still confused by this question--I read it quickly enough that I thought for sure it was about the new nav until I scrolled down and saw a question complaining about contrast.

Comment: Does unchecking "Opt in" opt me out again? Don't wanna test anymore :-)
... and btw. yes it does, can take some minutes.

Comment: Haven't read all the comments, so maybe someone already mentioned this, but couldn't an uptick of people clicking things in the toolbar just mean that people are exploring / getting used to the new toolbar?

Comment: Oh no, [they've done it on the blog too....](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/What-Programming-Languages-Weekends/?cb=1)

Comment: @NathanArthur some novelty effect definitely impacted the upticks and will likely fade over time, which is why we ran the tests for multiple weeks. Plus the upticks were so great that we expect a healthy portion to continue over time based on what we see in other, similar tests.

Comment: @Paweł I opted in now and it appears everything fits perfectly. Even better than the old nav. Beautiful.

Comment: I'll leave my thoughts in separate discussions/feature requests around here, but so far, it's pretty slick.

Comment: In new design, when there is rep change, the background color for showing rep change is blue. But when I refresh it, it changes to green.

Comment: @AJ we're working on fix

Comment: Here's [the bar with minor changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B67KT.png) - No obnoxious orange line, no obnoxious box shadow, and the best gray background (#f3f3f3), and a 1px bottom border.

Comment: I am inspired and humbled by the 7 votes to my previous comment. Here is a Stylish css: https://gist.github.com/kobi/ff7188a93e1111745c8e06ede363df97 , based on Steven's answer.

Comment: It looks great but I'd appreciate a dark theme

Comment: I'm really sorry but... I don't like it, not because it's new or a change, but because I just don't think it works. Its like a jack of all trades and master of none. Perhaps it would be better if it wasn't sticky but nobody needs that much information at their constant beck and call, its a waste of vertical space.

Comment: What's any of this *for*? Such a huge amount of time spent here, by the devs and the community, and for what, exactly? I've read all 3 Meta posts about these design changes and still have no idea what purpose even a single one of the changes is supposed to serve. Wouldn't soliciting feedback be more effective if you told the community what your objectives are?

Comment: But still, i like how things have been placed, the most anoying is the sticky part

Comment: @Kobi Fantastic. I think I speak for everyone who liked your comment: Great work. Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed _a ton_ of little fixes have happened since you posted this. At some point, it would be great to have a list of things that have been fixed as a result of feedback. Maybe an edit to this post or, even better, a new meta question once you have a chance.

Comment: @JonEricson a new post is coming in the near future. The team's still working through a few details.

Comment: I really like the amount of contrast (or lack thereof). If I look at the middle of the page, I don't even notice that the nav bar is there, and if I look at the top of the page I clearly see the nav bar, because of the subtle drop shadow that separates it from the rest of the page. Maybe I'm weird, but I like how this turned out.

Comment: Personally I don't mind at all if the nav stays sticky, and I don't think meta is the best place to gauge how the community feels about it (mostly people who dislike it will be speaking up about it). The one thing we can say for sure is that there is a significant group of users who feel really strongly about it, and therefore I think something should be done. But I am one of the users who *like* the stickiness, so if you change it, I would hope you would make it optional somehow.

Comment: I just realized that the new navbar is missing a link to the help center. Of course stackoverflow.com/help is an easy way, but I think there should be a "Help" button somewhere at least for new users.

Comment: @RenéVogt I believe it is (it is for me; see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343167/4957418). The reason why you can't see it is probably because your rep is high enough.

Comment: Why is "[clicking] navigation links [...] more" a goal? Yes, it leads to more ad impressions, but how does it build the ecosystem - if that's your presumed goal?

Comment: I finally got the new top bar. With the new floating option, I gotta say, nice work. Coming from somebody who likes nothing, this is awesome, and sort of goes back to SO's roots. Really glad to see the current scheme [finally put out of its misery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207796/is-the-meta-top-bar-resembling-googles-design-distinctive-enough/207806#207806).

Comment: I didnt read all your comments. My 2 pences: The general arrangement is good. The Sticky feature is uneccessary and will be annoying on some devices. I dont like the color scheme, I would prefer a dark background, the notifications are especially unotifiable without watching closely. Bring back clear RED/GREEN notifications please

Comment: the "obnoxious orange line" mentioned by @Kobi that appears under the current tab (like "Questions") must go too; its background color might be just tweaked instead to make it stand out. Would shave off 3-4 more wasted pixels!

Comment: Can I get dark theme back? Any way to switch back to old theme or somehow dark(black) theme?

Comment: i just encountered a repo change bug , the actual change and the change shown by notification is far different so should i post the bug with screen shot here or as a new post or this comment is enough ? basically i had a change of 20 and notification is showing only 2

Comment: Can we just get an option to go back to the old bar? 

Answer (score 489):

The new top nav [needs a dark theme](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341882). Since the design/moderation team
has gone through with the white/white theme, all I can do is to help people
get the dark theme back. To that end, you can use the
[Stylish add-on](//wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylish) with [Dimitri’s dark theme](//gist.github.com/g00glen00b/328bba7fdb392d3b8a7f2e6f7d468dbc):

> [image: alpha]

Comment: Maybe ask a new [tag:feature-request] question so we can properly discuss it?

Comment: Conditionally upvoting this… I strongly agree that a white toolbar against a white background is a bad choice, and think that the nav bar *desperately* needs more contrast. However, I don't actually support switchable "themes". The development cost isn't worth it, and things don't need to be that customizable—it just creates confusion. We don't need a "dark theme" and a "light theme". We just need a nav bar with reasonable contrast that stands out from the page's background.

Comment: I've flicked away and back to StackOverflow a few times since I've had this toolbar and my initial thought every time I land is the difficulty I have differentiating the start of the page content from the heading... +1

Comment: I'm not even strongly opposed to darkening the new top nav a bit, but the way you're turning this question into a narrative of "the people vs. those in power" because you disagree with something isn't helping your case. If "someone in charge likes it", maybe someone *not* in charge likes it as well? Maybe consider the possibility that a lot of people have worked on it (including "moderator Paweł", who by the way is one of the designers on this), and that those people (whether in charge or not) who have a different opinion from yours might have motivation beyond just ignoring users for sport.

Comment: For the record, [the same (but opposite) request existed for the dark top bar as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210012/would-it-be-possible-to-lighten-the-color-of-the-new-top-bar).

Comment: I have to agree, tried it for all of 5 minutes then switched it off...the white on white is just horrible.

Comment: @Lankymart 5 minutes isn't long enough to try a new UI when you've possibly been using the old one for years.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I know pretty quick whether I'm going to like something or not...did not like it from the get-go, there needs to be some contrast between the nav and main content.

Comment: I light gray color, such as `#F3F3F3` would be enough.

Comment: I messed around a bit and I agree, a darker color looks really nice. https://i.imgur.com/zvs35pG.png

Comment: 100% agree. White on white is bad for anyone's eyes. Dark theme would be good but even to add colour would be more useful to distinguish between the headers and search bar.

Comment: Dark themes are very much needed. Dark backgrounds are much easier on the eyes which is why I always use the dark theme on VS.

Comment: I'm not too bothered by the white toolbar... but that dark theme still looks a hundred times better so very much do want.

Comment: If someone wishes to use Stylish to change it into a dark theme, here are the things I messed with (not really finished): https://gist.github.com/g00glen00b/328bba7fdb392d3b8a7f2e6f7d468dbc Though I would appreciate it if an official dark theme would be implemented.

Comment: @balpha there's "just because you don't like it doesn't mean nobody does", and there's "we've been told on multiple independent occasions that the top bar is lacking contrast and we gave no feedback whatsoever". I mean supported responses [such as this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon/341882#comment434224_341806) and other comments therein. Probably cognitive bias on my part, but I can certainly understand Steven's frustration.

Comment: @AndrasDeak - contrast **was** added between the first shared screenshots and what we have now. Whether it was "enough" is more a matter of personal choice and opinion.

Comment: Just to be the contrarian here… Since most of the rest of the page is mostly white anyway, I fail to see what the big deal is. It's not like the narrow strip of white at the top is blinding me any more than the rest of the page is. Having grey elements on white I can see as an argument for more contrast, but that would equally apply to the rest of the page too.

Comment: @deceze but..but...clearly you're *one of them* :P

Comment: @Andras Arrrgh, that darn diamond is undermining my valid opinion.

Comment: LinkedIn just moved to a dark-top-bar theme today.

Comment: @Cœur: but GitHub uses a very light grey.

Comment: I definitely need a dark theme, going with this all white look is a mistake. Sure I am going to get used to it in some time, but that doesn't mean that a dark theme wouldn't be a lot easier on my eyes... Also as a side note, am I the only one who thinks that the distance between the top nav and the content is way too small? It's so close it looks like the content has been super glued to bar... Just a small increase of the padding would be nice...

Comment: I was hoping my comment was constructive, and I think it clearly expressed agreement that - for this user - the current white on white is not ideal?

Comment: "Being ignored" isn't the same as "not getting the outcome you hoped for."  And contrast *was* added between the first version and this. Personally, it hasn't fixed all *my* concerns, which is why I'm not only not "not ignoring" you, I'm personally *agreeing* with you. But in despite your suggestion in the post, I'm *not* forcing a designer or PM to make a change just because *I* think more visual contrast would help. I'm encouraging them to consider the feedback here in the context of the overall goals, and to weigh what's not here - no one's posting "keep it white"... cuz it's already white.

Comment: @XaverKapeller yeap, we gonna increase that padding before official launch.

Comment: Somebody posted links to some UI design articles in their comment for an answer to another question regarding the new nav bar, and in one of them, it said that, for sticky nav bars, its colour should contrast with the rest of the page. So if you're going to insist on it being sticky, then it shouldn't be white like the rest of the page. (I would prefer it to be not sticky, or at least give is a setting so that we can choose for ourselves.)

Comment: @StevenPenny the reason Pawel didn't respond regarding the color is because if we change the color, we would first need to run additional testing. The team's run multiple usability and A/B tests to ensure usability and effectiveness of the current version. Making it black would make it stand off from the rest of the content more, but a lot of users in this meta post don't want that. We also know that things that don't look like the rest of the site tend to get ignored by more people.

Comment: Because we don't answer immediately does not mean we're not listening. It's possible we launch with white and continue to test iterations.

Comment: @StevenPenny i don't ignore you. in addition to what Kurtis said: i've answered XaverKapeller comment because he brought up thing that hasn't been discussed before and has no feedback from me. one thing you have to understand is that i'm not here to argue with anyone. i'm here to help Community and do what i can to make experience better. i'm not an enemy. also one more thing to understand as well is that i'm trying to pay attention not only to feedback on meta but also other aspects: numbers we track, users not being on meta, branding, user interviews and really many other things.

Comment: @StevenPenny Sometimes, when you notice that people feel like they're being attacked, the best way to communicate what you think is important _isn't_ ramping up the amplitude on what you've been saying. We're hearing many people speaking at once, some saying that the nav is way _too_ noticeable, and we're trying to reconcile all of that along with feedback that it's way too subtle into something that we can actually do to improve it. You're _ramming_ your point here, quite loudly; if you perceive folks with their fingers in their ears, maybe turn down the volume?

Comment: @janhartmann Good call on the light grey. I tweaked g00len00b's gist: https://gist.github.com/tiesont/9b5eb8e15552a3790b6d47ec9ac2b7d8

Comment: @Jaydles: I'm not seeing __nearly__ as many _"I love white"_ answers as _"Dear god please make the menu dark again"_ answers. And have a look at the votes on those answers, it seems pretty clear the users here prefer a not-white menu. I guess what I'm trying to say is: We may not see a lot of _"keep it white"_ answers, but there isn't a lot of _"I like this new colour"_, either.

Comment: @Cerbrus it is natural that people usually express they don't like something rather than they like something. so you won't see too many posts saying "i love white" because of that. i suspect that if we create dark design (and not white) there would be lots of voices saying "i don't like dark, i wanna light" instead "i love dark".

Comment: @StevenPenny - can you please include the votes from all the people who do like the white on white (but because they are OK with it, didn't feel the need to pipe up)? Claiming you and the few hundred upvotes on different posts are representative of the community as a whole is disingenuous at best.

Comment: @Paweł, I'm sorry, but that's not a very strong "defense" against a well represented "(even) more contrast" opinion the community is voicing here. If it's more natural to "dislike" something, why isn't the "more contrast" feedback being downvoted that much? I can appreciate the effort that goes into a redesign like this, I just think a menu bar should have more contrast than "white" on white. (Note: I'm a little blunt here, but I mean well :-) )

Comment: @Cerbrus one thing that maybe wasn't clear: my comment was not "defense" and it definitely was not "defense" against _contrast_ opinion. it was just explanation why you can't see answers like "i love white".

Comment: You are the one tallying votes - just saying you are only doing it from one side, so not representative of anything.

Comment: Feature request: Polls for announcements. Allow the community to weigh in, in a _measurable, unbiased_ manner. For this specific example, the poll could be a choice of 3 different mock-ups: Light, dark, and somewhere in between. (@Oded)

Comment: @Pawel I wouldn't mind if this dark theme was toggleable (is that a word)? I guess both parties would be happy then? Though I understand that it would take a lot of extra dev/design/maintain time and it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @Cerbrus, what Pawel said is what I meant: "You can see the folks who dislike a specific piece of a prototype or proposal, but not most of those who like it". I apologize if that made it sound like I was suggesting MOST folks want it white. I have no idea, and personally have old eyes and would prefer some more visual distinction. :)

Comment: @Cerbrus - where's the feature request then? I didn't see you post one.

Comment: @Oded: I wasn't being very serious. I'm not sure it's within the scope of meta. Do you think a request like that has a chance?

Comment: Dunno - not sure how we could really do polls with the current Q&A system. Frankly - we have other priorities, and difficult to draw the line between things that should be brought to a community vote and things that do not, @Cerbrus (also, my response was somewhat tongue in cheek)

Comment: Oh the subtleties of plain text ;-)

Comment: @StevenPenny what about including this image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHcv1.png - from this answer below http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343218/1873567 so that you have two options? This image is a subtle grey, so doesn't change much yet adds the contrast needed

Comment: Isn't this what the voting system is for? if the majority of people disagreed with the dark theme you would see this post right at the bottom but it's being completely outweighed by people who like the idea and are upvoting. There's a reason this answer is the highest voted here.

Comment: FWIW, just adding myself to the chorus of respectful but firm dislike of the Blinding White Status Bar of Eternal Stickiness. It just screams as a solution in search of a problem. Tried it for a while, went back to the current one while its still available. I do wish someone on the SE side understood that Contrast Is A Good Thing.

Comment: @Oded Maybe a UserVoice would suffice? Or does that just duplicate Meta and it's voting system?

Comment: @Tie funny thing, very early on, before we had meta sites, there was a Stack Overflow uservoice. Going back is not a good option - sending people to yet another place.

Comment: The unstated reality here is that, in all likelihood, this unwanted change is almost certainly rooted in no small part to some mechanism to increase future ad space. That's why this is going though like a bulldozer despite so many user pleas (and nearly 300 upvotes) for an alternative.

Comment: @DavidW I can understand how you might think that. But I can assure you that this update has absolutely nothing to do with ad space, and everything to do with a theme that emerged from user interviews and focus groups that our current navigation was confusing to many users and that the current design didn't match more regular contemporary navigation patterns. Which makes sense — it was designed in 2008.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Confusion among the users who have somehow managed to contribute over 10 *million* questions, provided millions of answers, incited collaboration (and dispute)? Poll enough people, and you'll eventually find someone who tells you a light switch is too complex. Sorry, don't mean to snark, I just loathe change for change's sake, and the "damn the torpedoes" response mode here just kinda leaves me a little...sad. Then again, I'm nobody. I get that, too. In spades. Would have been nice to have been in one of the lucky focus groups that inspired the Blinding White Status Bar of Doom.

Comment: I upvoted this question in its original form. You've since added parts that I do not agree with. The biggest thing being, I actually like the sticky bar. There are other posts that discuss the sticky feature so don't mix it here with your contrast complaint. Let users vote on that separately. I also don't think the quotes add much to your answer. At this point, I'm not sure if I really would upvote this. Please stop changing your answer.

Comment: @DavidW I just don't think we're saying "damn the torpedoes." I'm trying to show that this wasn't just some designer's whim. The qualitative evidence gained from the interviews led to a hypothesis, which led to two sets of A/B tests with ~2 million users. This gave us quantitative data to back up our hypothesis (that many users don't see or use our navigation), and the new version was such a significant improvement in all measurable metrics. Of course some of this is novelty effect, but the performance was much greater than what we normally identify as passible criteria for an A/B test.

Comment: Regarding making the dark theme, we've said in previous comments that we're open to listening and carefully considering meta feedback when it comes to design and testing future iterations (we have a running list of future experiment ideas), but our testing process takes weeks if not months (not of design or developer time, but to run in the background at a 2.5% sample rate). A change like this isn't something we'd make without testing. We also want to hear the underlying feedback and pain points to make sure that we're addressing the problems in the best way to create a cohesive design system.

Comment: Well, well, well... look what GitHub did: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSujT.png

Comment: Reverse copycats, @NathanOsman

Comment: We just need a Dark themed nav bar, so we can actually SEE it!

Comment: Funny that GitHub just switched to a dark top nav and it looks terrible, and SO is switching to a white one and that looks terrible

Comment: @andrewtweber I think the old GitHub light gray was a nice compromise and that is why I used it as an example in my [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343247/4660897). I actually contacted GitHub to let them know that the new black is too dark.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Github uses a black bar.

Comment: @Cœur you do realise that they *just* changed that, right?

Comment: @andrew - just tells you that people are change averse. Almost doesn't matter what the change is, just that things are different.

Comment: As someone who has a vision impairment which makes a dark theme very attractive (and certainly would help with pain). I'm upvoting this, putting in my "we still need a dark theme" voice, and thanking you for posting this so I can add it to my own custom theme.

Comment: Agree, Dark title bar is a staple of the website and should at least remain an option

Comment: @Oded We are all just people. It's hard not to get caught up when a person perceives an injustice, which is happening to two opposing sides here. Can people with a diamond after their name be the bigger people?

Comment: @user3071284 - sorry, what exactly are you taking about?

Comment: @Oded See balpha's first comment and your last one (before my last comment). I read through these comments and felt that diamond folk who were for the white color were defensive of their opinion and dismissive of opposing opinions rather than trying to understand an opposing opinion.

Comment: @user3071284 - I see. Did you also read through the [revisions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/343106/revisions) of this answer? In particular the first ones? I think the tone of the original answer can explain the tone of our comments. What do you think?

Comment: @Oded I certainly understand why the reaction happened that way, and I don't agree with the approach the answer originally took. At the same time, I feel that mods should look past that and try to find the real issue and address that. What do you think? This is the most voted for answer here.

Comment: @user3071284 - related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343287/concerns-about-recent-stack-exchange-responses-to-users-suggestions

Comment: @Oded Thanks for including me in that thread by passing it along. For the new nav, is there somewhere SO has talked about why they like they way it looks now? I know brand identity is an important message, just wondering if adding something expository to the conversation helped or would help.

Comment: @user3071284 - expect a blog post tomorrow.

Comment: @Oded did you mean "reverse copyOctocats"?

Comment: Yes oh my white everywhere too much white. _Contrast_, people!

Comment: I've been using the new top bar since it was available and I still have to pause and think about where I need to put my mouse. I look at the navigation and see random words in a white bar. For me personally, some delineation between the tabs is needed in addition to some contrast.

Comment: Thanks for providing a link to the alternative theme, I found the new default a bit jarring. It's likely I may have gotten used to it, but I tend to favour dark themes when given the option; I'm probably slightly resistant to transitions to lighter themes in general.

Comment: [Really didn't like the change to a dark theme and still don't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207796/is-the-meta-top-bar-resembling-googles-design-distinctive-enough/207806#207806). Dark theme as an option, I'm down, but as the only theme, no thanks. Super stoked to see the color scheme go back to its roots.

Comment: Is there merit to a feature request asking for a very small pool of 2 or 3 themes (light, dark, and maybe something in between)? I would hope the implementation costs wouldn't be prohibitive to do this and it might mean that what seems like a very contentious issue for quite a few people could be resolved to most people's satisfaction?

Comment: Vote removed.  It is now a pale gray which is enough contrast to satisfy me.  It could could be a smidgen darker, since on one of my monitors it was indistinguishable from white until I adjusted monitor settings, but it is not a great monitor either.

Comment: There's actually quite a few nice styles for SO there (see https://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow) in addition to the ones listed in this answer. In particular, https://userstyles.org/styles/138640/stack-black-slim-header is dark and even lower height than the one in this answer.

Comment: @balpha "isn't helping your case?" Are you King Stackoverflow or what?? Users on the whole don't like the change. I see you work for SO, so make the case the majority of users are making, and get it changed back already!

Answer (score 198):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Bring back colour cues

I loved the visual distinction between new messages (red), new achievements (green) and new mod messages (blue).

That distinction is now almost entirely gone; everything but the achievements box is now blue on grey icons. I now have to judge by location what I am looking at, and it is rather noisy. Especially with the large numbers for the review queue and moderator flag queue, these drown out my inbox numbers for me, blurring together a bunch on now-contextless numbers:

[image: bunch of blue numbers]

---

Example of the current, fixed status:

[image]

Comment: to be clear: achievements are still green. as for moderators - we are working on something new for them, but don't tell anyone.

Comment: @Paweł: nope, achievements are blue, see screenshot.

Comment: @Paweł - does that include restoring the single click to get to the admin dashboard?

Comment: @MartijnPieters ok, that's definitely a bug. fix in progress..

Comment: @ChrisF yes it does.

Comment: @Paweł: fix applied? It *just* turned green.

Comment: Different code paths, @MartijnPieters - I am fixing the "initial load" one.

Comment: Yes, notifications in red is pretty crucial methinks. Otherwise it's too easy to ignore them among the other identically coloured badges.

Comment: Green on the first load is now fixed.

Comment: @Paweł - I've also had instance where the achievement shows up in blue (all notification blue). It is only after refreshing the page that it changes to green.

Comment: @Oded Mine is still blue on first load. Fix not published yet?

Comment: @Bradley: only on page load they are green. On websocket updates they are blue. Annoying.

Comment: This is more important than I assumed at first. I suddenly found myself ignoring replies because the color cue is the same as the one that is now always there, blue review. As the review one will *always* be there with some numbers, it is key that it has a different color, and it has to be a color that does not draw that much attention as the achievements/inbox.

Comment: inbox color will be red again. fix is waiting repo, so should be live after next build.

Comment: Started to see red on MSO now, SO still awaiting the refresh… Thanks, @Paweł!

Comment: @deceze - should see red, should see green too :) - I've fixed the real-time updates issue there.

Comment: @Oded: yay, I just saw red to indicate your comment was waiting! :-) I'm capped for the day, so green'll have to wait. Do badges still cause a change? I received a few today and I didn't see a change even after reloading the page.

Comment: That functionality hasn't changed, AFAIK - everything that used to notify on the old bar should notify here. If it doesn't, that's a bug.

Comment: @Oded icon highlight is still a bug. working on it.

Comment: @Paweł I can confirm that colors have returned (red, green, blue)

Comment: @Haney: I was just about to update the status. It isn't *quite* completed yet. Badges don't highlight the achievements box, and the work on the diamond status is still outstanding. The latter we can separate, the former not quite.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh my bad, feel free to adjust as you see fit of course!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - just got the achievements issue fixed, this will be in the next build.

Comment: @Oded: where's a new badge when you need it..

Comment: @MartijnPieters how about adding a new screenshot to the post showing the difference

Comment: @CalvT: there you go.

Comment: @MartijnPieters review queues notification has returned to orange

Comment: @Nkosi: that, and the moderator menus have been cleaned up too. I'm capped for the day, I'll have to see when I can update the screenshot again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am not a moderator so was not able to see that. I just updated what I could confirm. Cool.

Answer (score 158):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (ish) - [We're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation)

I'm still not a big fan of the bar being sticky. It doesn't take up as much vertical space as I feared, but it still takes up *some*, and unnecessarily so. What is the point of sticking the navigation into my face when I'm trying to comprehend a long post and want 1) as much vertical real estate as possible and 2) as little distraction as possible by any notifications?

Going back up to the navigation is one flick of a finger or one press of a button, so I'm not seeing what a permanently visible bar accomplishes.

Comment: Oh dear God no! The trend for sticky top navigation bars is horrendous, especially on constrained window devices such as phones. If I want the navigation bar I know where it is (*hint:* right there at the freakin page top, just like on every. Other. Single. Site!), it's not like I've forgotten in the time it took me to scroll down an inch!  >.<

Comment: @Toby we haven't done anything to mobile theme - header is still not sticky on mobile.

Comment: @Paweł And it's even easier to scroll up on desktop. Scrolling or pressing the home key isn't a massively onerous task, is it? Please please please, leave top navigation where it belongs, at the top!

Comment: @Paweł BTW, what's even worse is those sticky nav bars that disappear when scrolling down but then reappear when scrolling up... sure they're handy *sometimes* but I truly do find for the most part they are more often just in the way.

Comment: @Paweł FWIW, I use the desktop site on my phone, and the sticky nav bar is so obtrusive there, I immediately opted out after it finally activated. Please at least make it a user setting.

Comment: @Toby noooo, saying things like "sure they're handy sometimes" is exactly what's needed to rationalize these horrible inventions:P Watch your language! Baad, bad sticky bar.

Comment: @Paweł unless you're going to overhaul the mobile view at the same time, some actions are still only available in desktop view and the official response is "use desktop view on mobile for those." The sticky bar becomes much more obtrusive in that case.

Comment: Yep, please make it non-sticky and perhaps less shadowy. User CSS I’m running with in the meantime: `.so-header { box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(12, 13, 14, 0.1); position: absolute; }`

Comment: @Paweł also, since it's sticky, it doesn't scroll with the rest of the viewport when zoomed in on mobile, so it becomes unusable.

Comment: @Pawel: I can see the appeal of the sticky bar for *casual visitors*, that have dropped in for a quick answer and are now lost in a big page. But after using this for a full day as a power user the sticky top bar is distracting quite useless. I never need the Documentation, Jobs or Tabs links, the rest only occasionally, and when answering I want to glance at the question from time to time at which point the notifications are a distraction. Please separate your design goals into 'casual' and 'power' groups; it is the latter group that is complaining loudly about the stickyness, I suspect.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i understand your point of view but there are power users who actually use Documentation & Jobs. it is important for us to make our users aware of those sections and to let them know that we are no longer _only_ Q&A site, we're more than that. it is also important from business point of view. we're trying to build universal design for both: 'casual' & 'power' groups - both are equally important.

Comment: @Paweł Fine, that I can get on board with. But is that enough of a reason to make it sticky? Wouldn't it serve the same purpose as static navigation at the top of the page?

Comment: @Pawel: I'm not saying the links should be removed. I just don't need to see them *all the time*. Not when most of my time goes to interacting with the current page content. I want to be *here*, not somewhere else.

Comment: @deceze *majority* (like seriously a lot) of our traffic comes from google (both anonymous and loggedin). they very often land in the middle of the page on specific answer (or just quickly scroll down without paying attention to anything we have on top, very often omitting even question itself). so people simply ignore Stack Overflow as a website and everything we offer them, it's more like a place with answers. we're trying to do what's best for users, but we also need something from users because it's the only way this _ecosystem_ may exist. i hope that answer makes sense.

Comment: @Paweł I can follow that reasoning. But I still don't like the sticky bar, and it arguably serves zero purpose for me. Have you considered making stickiness a preference and/or limiting it to unregistered/new users?

Comment: @deceze we're currently discussing pros & cons of making it a preference. it's really not that simple as "ok, let's do it". it brings lots of consequences in long-term that we need to think about.

Comment: @Paweł Totally, I for one wouldn't want to be in charge of maintaining that. ;-P But I'd very much appreciate you implementing it.

Comment: For people with small monitor laptops this nav is a big problem... Literally... Please please make the stickiness optional in the settings. Its just too robust and takes too much of the screen to easily interact with the app

Comment: What I would like to see is a non-sticky top bar, but after I scroll it out of view, float the inbox icon off on the right, translucent, so I can see when notifications arrive. Kind of like what [RES does on reddit](http://i.imgur.com/LOoKGWJ.png).

Comment: I originally wasn't sure about the sticky bar. After testing it for more than a day though, I actually came to really like it and like that those controls are always visible no matter how far on a page I scroll. I understand that it can be a problem for some users with smaller screens, so a configurable user preference may be the best solution.

Comment: Why I don't want a sticky header - the introvert reason: this may sound silly, but when I'm at work with an SO answer open, or showing someone else an SO answer, I sort of prefer not to have my photo and reputation showing, so I scroll down a little. I mean, it isn't a secret, but I don't like how it's always there.

Comment: [More or less](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation) [meta-tag:status-completed].

Comment: @TotZam I think the way to solve the problem with small screens is to make the navigation bar's padding smaller and make it sticky when scrolling up but disappear when scrolling down or when landing on SO from an external source. User preferences for UI like this aren't very feasible because this is an important part of SO's UX that reminds people that there is more to SO than answers.

Comment: @Willie OH GOD NO! Not a yo-yo bar, please! D: – The new unsticky bar is perfectly great.

Comment: @Cerbrus How much *more* could there be? :)

Comment: @deceze But scrolling to the top on long answers gives me carpal tunnel.

Comment: @Willie Every keyboard has a *Home* key somewhere… :)

Comment: @deceze I guess the implemented solution makes the more experienced users happy, then. Meanwhile, the novices like me will learn keyboard shortcuts and the world goes on. :)

Comment: Can large rep users like me be allowed to just have the stuff to the right of our image? I have ZERO use for the static links http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343582/295783

Answer (score 97):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The site switcher menu is too narrow and too close to the notification items and too fickle in staying open. It's natural to want to click on the menu and then move the mouse diagonally to the item in the menu you want to click on, which are all on the opposite left aligned side. Doing so almost inevitably means I'm crossing through the neighbouring notification menu item, which closes the site switcher menu and opens that menu instead. Which is infuriating and requires super delicate mouse movements to avoid.

[image: spurious freehand arrows and circles]

Comment: I'd provide a GIF, but that inevitably means exposing the contents of the moderator-only menu, which is probably not a good idea… :)

Comment: I agree it is very annoying, once you click the item, the hover take a place to open the rest of items, which is really annoying.

Comment: i agree this might be a problem sometimes and we do have it on our plate for next iterations. the reason why it works this way is because we wanted to keep behaviour close to old topbar (which is still in use on other sites in the network). so updating dropdowns (including behaviour on hover) and topbar on other sites is on our roadmap for next iterations.

Comment: @Paweł The hover behaviour was fine while the menu button was very wide *and* both the button and the menu items where aligned on the same side. It's pretty untenable when the layout is such that you have to cross diagonally though another menu item… Hope you'll get to it rather sooner than later.

Comment: @deceze i'm sure we will get there as soon as we can. thanks for feedback!

Comment: If I aim for any of the sites in the upper half of the popup, I hit the neighboring icon and the popup is closed. I hit that bug immediately and consistently several times.

Comment: I also find this extremely annoying. What might be related is that the menu opens to the left of where you clicked while the others open somewhat in the middle or to the right. Maybe our users who are used to right-to-left reading find this particular menu easier?

Comment: Possible solution: Align the left edge of the popup with the left edge of the icon. If the webpage isn’t wide enough, align the right edge of the popup with the right edge of the window. This could actually work for all of the icons.

Comment: This is a problem with all the menus, not just the site switcher. For some reason I had no problem when the small menus were anchored left instead of right.

Comment: Noticed this too and thought it was _me_ just being funny. Glad I came here to realise I wasn't completely alone.

Comment: Same - diagonal movement closed it for me.

Comment: The cursed [diagonal movement](http://bjk5.com/post/44698559168/breaking-down-amazons-mega-dropdown).

Comment: we're about to fix it soon. more info [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343180/quick-route-from-meta-to-main#comment444193_343180).

Comment: Im not sure if this is only me or it has been fixed now, but I need to *click* on the icons to bring the window, thus I can take the diagonal path if I desire because the window will be still open unless I click on the neighbour icon

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've just got in this morning - it's changed overnight, you can now take the diagonal route - it's much better :)

Comment: yes, it's been fixed.

Comment: This fix had a big impact on my satisfaction with the top bar. That right-hand section is very nice to use now IMO.

Comment: @JamesThorpe You can take the diagonal route, but you have to click on each icon to open the menu instead of just floating between the menus. This was only half a solution in my opinion. Implementing the diagonal movement detection would have been nice. This "fix" was just disabling some functionality.

Answer (score 91):

There is no link to help center any more:

> [image]

<s>Any new user (who isn't aware of the link in the footer) won't see any way to get help when in need, and this will no doubt increase the amount of trivial questions here on MSO. (by those who will find it.)</s>

Turns out low rep users do have it, so it's less terrible than I thought.

Still, I would like to have it as well - useful as shortcut.

Comment: Apparently it's still there for newbs. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343165/476

Comment: @deceze huh, true. Got it with my sock

Comment: I find it useful as I fairly often want to point people at the relevant section.

Comment: I second finding this useful. To summarize my points on the question posted about this: I use the help link often, to either remind myself of things or to help people. I don't want to hit the footer and search the links there for help. This breaks my flow for helping people.

Comment: Work-around until this is fixed: click achievements, then (in the top-right corner of the achievements box), click badges, then on the badges overview page, use the breadcrumbs to go to the help center. *sigh*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, link in footer still exists.

Comment: If you use the keyboard shortcuts, we've added G -> E for help (H was taken by Homepage), as with all navigational shortcuts, shifting will open it in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks @Oded, not using it myself but other probably are. :)

Comment: The help link is still there for anonymous and users without access to the review queue. We appreciate that this is still an issue for some users and are thinking of ways to fix that - but this will not happen for launch, but some time afterwards.

Comment: @Oded yeah, I know, and noticed you added links to privileges and badges in the achievements dialog, so at least for me that's enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - [We're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation)

The sticky toolbar was sure to be controversial. I'll add myself to the group that does strongly dislike it. I don't really mean the reduced vertical space for the rest of the content, I use a relatively big screen and I'm not really worried about that aspect. But I find the sticky toolbar irrationally distracting, and there isn't really a way to fix that.

So what I'd request is to make the stickiness configurable. I know SE hates preferences, but I thought I could at least ask.

Comment: Other than it being sticky, i like it. It being sticky though kills it for me, i keep finding myself wanting to see what's under it.

Comment: this request seems like the same as the request by @deceze♦
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343132/2809828 ?

Answer (score 59):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) I too am strongly against the white-on-white, I feel like I'm straining my eyes *(don't worry carpetsmoker - my screen is set up correctly)*

I think a light grey (`#efefef`, maybe even lighter) would give enough contrast without spoiling the design.

[image]

<strike>Additionally, I think it would be better for the site switcher menu to not hide when it loses :hover status but rather when it truly loses focus (unless you can tweak the layout so that you don't have to go down, then across?)</strike> *(fixed)*

---

Positives: There is something quite nice about "simpler" look overall and I do like the little things like the badge "jump" when you hover over an icon.

In summary, I am in favour of the change - it's really just the white on white that I can't live with.

Comment: Wow that top bar with gray looks really nice. That is just what I was hoping for.

Comment: @MarcoMan [GitHub](https://github.com/) uses a lighter color, `#f5f5f5`, for the background and `#e5e5e5` for the bottom border, and the contrast looks pretty good. I just added and [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343247/4660897) that demonstrates this.

Comment: White on white looks like polar bear in a snow blizzard. Too much white...

Comment: This gray seems better than black or white.

Comment: Doth my eyes deceiveth me? That nav bar looks a tad light gray :) `#fafafb` - good work!

Comment: This says status-completed, but I'm seeing white on white still on the live site.

Comment: @AndyMercer I've changed it back - I think the new nav colour has only been rolled out for some users...

Answer (score 54):

### Notifications have lost some nuance

When comparing new to old, I do like how compact the new notification section is:

[image: New notifications]

[image: Old notifications]

But I also notice that the "achievement" icon on the old top bar is [glowing green](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230405/new-achievement-notification-is-not-eye-catching). That's a subtle indication that I have a badge somewhere. No particular hurry to see it, so it's not as noticeable as the red number 7 showing my unread inbox count. Meanwhile, the blue diamond is also glowing to let me know that there is something unread in my moderator inbox (typically mod messages and meta posts). Again, these aren't as pressing as flags, so the indicator is a color change rather than a number. As far as I can tell, this behaviour is missing from the new top bar.

The orange box with a 5 in it shows the number of reviews. On the new bar, the color is blue as [Martijn points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343130/1438), so the review notification tends to blend in with the rest. Somewhat paradoxically, it demands more of my attention now. Thinking about it, I think the color is only part of the problem. Since the site-level notifications are in the same space as the notifications I *really* care about (my inbox and achievements) they get slightly confused in my mind. I worry this is going to result in the same sort of notification fatigue I developed on LinkedIn:

[image: Notification fatigue]

(Though, to be fair, I stopped caring about my LinkedIn profile long ago because it wasn't terribly relevant.)

I'm curious if it would be possible to:

1. Restore the "glowing icon" notification for minor items. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
2. Add more color to differentiate the various notification numbers. (I think this is already [being planned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343130#comment443820_343130).) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
3. Move the inbox and achievement notifications before the user's avatar to provide a clear separation between personal and community notifications.

---

So far I like the new locations for most of my cheese. But I do wish there was a quicker path to the help center and meta/main (depending on where you are). I also feel like some of our hidden away [tools](https://stackoverflow.com/tools) have gotten more hidden. I like how clean the menu is, but I'm missing a grab bag of links as the "help" menu eventually turned into. It's a tradeoff and I'm well aware my needs are not mainstream. I just wish there were some path to get to the [geitost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunost#Varieties) for those of us who have a taste for it.

Comment: I fully agree with all the points you mentioned, except #3 - I think it looks better when all the icons are grouped together.

Comment: The lack of color differentiation is a bug that will be fixed before launch.

Comment: yes, we're going to bring back red number for inbox in coming build. we are also working on some improvements for mod navigation that gonna be released hopefully soon.

Comment: Cheers, was going to report this as well now.

Comment: The review-queue button being in the same color, place, and shape as the notifications I actually care about (inbox, achievements) is so distracting that I had to use adblock to hide that element so it is not constantly grabbing my attention. The old orange one was ignorable enough that I left it there, meaning that on rare occasions I could actually click on it if I felt like doing some reviews. Now that I've had to hide the button, I will never click on it.

Comment: @amalloy: I suspect most people won't hide the button (mostly because it's a pain) and that more reviews will be done as a result. But I'm not sure that's a good thing. The review queue is hardly ever personally relevant, but the inbox and recent achievements are _always_ of interest and almost always more pressing. That said, I had similar concerns with the previous topbar change and I mostly learned to ignore the problems. So, maybe they weren't problems? I'm not sure. This is the sort of thing that makes it so hard to evaluate changes like this.

Comment: In addition to a quicker path to meta, it would also be nice if there was a quicker path to your network portfolio. Basically, it would be nice if those 2 buttons can be moved to the top-bar instead of having them just hidden in the user profile.

Answer (score 46):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Some people like to review queues other than Suggested edits. Please make the review button a dropdown like the other ones in the row and show all of the accessible review queues. Also, please allow us to change the number shown to be something other than the number of pending suggested edits, or nothing at all.

Mockup:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css?v=1fd832a99b89">

<div class="topbar-dialog siteSwitcher-dialog">
  <div class="header">
    <h3><a href="//stackoverflow.com/review">review queues</a>
            </h3>
    <a href="#" id="edit-pinned-sites">pin</a>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content" id="your-communities-section">

    <ul class="my-sites">
      <li>
        <a href="">
          Help and Improvement
          <span class="rep-score">294</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          Triage
          <span class="rep-score">174</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          First Posts
          <span class="rep-score">73</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          Low Quality Posts
          <span class="rep-score">72</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          Suggested Edits
          <span class="rep-score">59</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">
          Late Answers
          <span class="rep-score">7</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="disabled-link">
          Close Votes
          <span class="rep-score">8.4k</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="disabled-link">
          Reopen Votes
          <span class="rep-score">123</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check my answer below: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343135/1873567 - the link was a bug, it should take you to the review queue list

Comment: dropdown for review sounds like very interesting idea - we will think about it.. +what @CalvT said.

Comment: Done: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653

Answer (score 46):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) I'd just like to request **the addition of a [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) link** since it looks like there'd be room for it beside [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). I actually use the privileges link more than I do badges because it has a greater influence over my use of the site - where I can review, edit, etc.

Apart from that, I actually have very few complaints about the new nav bar so far.

[image: Add a link to privileges here]

Comment: Yes, please add this! There are many other users who would like this as well: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon/341840#comment434384_341823

Comment: This is a great suggestion, easy to implement, serves a purpose, and solves a problem. Well done! I hope this gets put in.

Comment: Yes please! this is the page i go to the most in the help center, and that seems like a great place for it.

Comment: good idea! it should appear with one of coming builds.

Comment: This appears to be status-completed now.

Answer (score 41):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

[image]

That notification annoys the hell out of me. Like really a lot.
I continuously think I have  a new reply, comment, upvote or whatever, only to discover it's the review queue.

The constant blue icon in my top right constantly nags at the back of my brain, *there's something, there's something.*

Please make it less conspicuous that it drags less attention.
I sometimes spend time in the review queue, mostly not.

But since the menu is now ALWAYS in my sight because it's sticky, it will constantly nag me/be in my face instead of be gone when I scroll down.

I have a simple solution for this:
If I don't hover the menu, let it be gray.

```
.so-header:hover .js-review-button .js-unread-count {
   background-color: #07C;
}
.so-header .js-review-button .js-unread-count {
   background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: I prefer this: `.js-review-button .js-unread-count { display: none; }` :)

Comment: I see what you want, but i don't agree, i do like the reminder to "do my part" just not as prominent constantly

Comment: As an experienced user, seeing that number never makes me want to go and review anything. Absolutely make it distinct from "real" notifications, but other than that it's really just an annoyance.

Comment: @Tschallacka I changed it to `.so-header:not(:hover) .js-review-button .js-unread-count { background-color: #9fa6ad !important; }`, which removes the need for 2 styles and makes it the same color as the buttons when not hovered.

Comment: Yeah, that number is meaningless to me. I'd just as well see reviews off of my top bar entirely. Another thing I really dislike about it: it is a link, while all the other icons there are dropdowns.

Comment: Disagree. We *want* people to hit the review queues.

Comment: @Raphael well, I don't mind going to the review queue,  but i hate fake notifications. The amount doesn't go down, its an sisyphusian task without reward that the number goes down. The number even appears completely random. Thats why i want it only visible when i hover the nav bar

Comment: @Tschallacka So a colorful mark that says "do something!" without the actual number would be okay?

Comment: it would actually. Its a psychological thing I guess. But if i see that number and i perform actions I'd expect the number to go down as a reward until it reaches zero.  If it doesn't it rather have it being an orange numberless ball. The number is meaningless at this moment.

Comment: We made it orange instead: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653

Comment: awesome. Great work @Shog9

Answer (score 38):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Is there any need for users with less than 2k to have the suggested edits button?

Until I get to 2k I can only imagine it would be somewhat irrelevant:

[image]

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, the tooltip says:

[image]

But then leads you to Suggested Edits (https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits). I guess it should actually lead to the review queues (https://stackoverflow.com/review/), but then the tooltip might be a bit hard to calculate!

Comment: yes. users with 100rep got access to review queue for documentation. and afair rest of review sections after they get 500rep

Comment: I guess this is a bug, it should take to the review queues list, instead of the suggested edits queue. The tooltip is right, but the link is not.

Comment: @AJPerez updated - wonder how they would calculate the tooltip though

Comment: yeap, url is bug. fix in progress.

Comment: @Paweł what do the numbers on the review notification indicate? Total of all queues? The edits queue? Or something else?

Comment: @CalvT if it's anything like before, 2k-10k suggested edits, 10k- total review tasks.

Comment: @Braiam I meant the little number indicators that overlay the icon - check other people's screenshots and you'll see what I mean

Comment: Thats exactly what I was describing.

Comment: @Braiam sorry yes get you now - 2k is also the rep you need to be able to approve edits so that threw me off! The numbers on the screenshots in this post vary from around 56 to 866 so no idea what it is!

Comment: 56 is the number of edits in the queue, 866 is the number of reviews in all queues *sans* the close queue. The later only appears to 10k+, the former to 2-10k.

Answer (score 32):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) Stack Exchange icon design issue

Usually the Stack Exchange icon contains 4 blocks in it. Example in the previous top bar and MSE site.

[image: 4 blocks]

But in the new top bar the Stack Exchange icon contains only 3 blocks in it.

[image: 3 blocks]

For the uniformity the icon should be the same number of blocks in other place.

Comment: I suspect at that size the icon would become too noisy with more details and this simplification was on purpose.

Comment: what @deceze said. plus we actually wanted this to be more like a "hamburger" icon (which usually has three bars) but we mixed it with SE glyph to give a tip what's behind that.

Comment: Arul, Good catch. ;)

Comment: @Pawel It's not really a hamburger menu though.  Hamburger menus 1. tend to be displayed as sidebar, 2. often an “off-canvas drawer” sidebar, and 3. almost always display “catch all links”— all the stuff that didn't deserve primary 1-click navigation.  Making it look like a hamburger menu is somewhat confusing in this respect; I expect it to contain links to (in addition to SE Sites) Feed, Drafts, History, About, & Log Out— reflecting the well-designed hamburger menu in the official [Stack Exchange iPad App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8).

Answer (score 27):

There are some glaring problems with this design.

Also, the *sole* metric cited here, "users shown the new top nav clicked navigation links 143% more than those shown the current design" is a terrible metric. Why are we aiming for more clicks to do the same thing?

### **Where is the help??!?!?!?!?!**

There is no access to the help center with the new design! What is this madness?? The same goes for the tour! <sup>*<sub>oh, but it is in the set of links in the footer</sub>*</sup>, you say? No. Not enough. How are new users expected to know *any* of the already semi ridiculous expectations of asking their first question without this content? They aren't, they won't, and it will negatively effect question quality and user experience. These two facets, question quality, and user experience, **should be the bar you look at for improvement**. Not #of clicks before / #of clicks after.

**Why is review a link?**

Seriously, in a set of modals, why is the review icon a link? That alone probably leads to an excessive amount of clicking around, especially considering that if a new review comes up, and you click to see what that alert means, it navigates you away from what you were doing. It should be moved elsewhere. In fact, it should be grouped with **help** and there should be a modal for that set of tooling - those aimed at improving question quality and user experience.

The top bar is now sticky. I get it, but why?

```
header { position: absolute; }
```

This is what I will personally be doing in a user script. If you wish to test this you can use `$("header").css("position","absolute")` in a browser console or by prepending `javascript:` to the jquery snippet and placing it in the url.

This is what my topbar looks like and how it interacts:

[image]

Comment: Help is still there for low rep users who don't have access to the review queue. For users who do, help is still a link in the footer. The review icon will likely get an upgrade in the next iteration to be a dropdown.

Comment: We've interviewed a lot of users who had no idea what the items in the topbar were or that we had navigation at the top right-hand side of the page because they were used to landing on the page and scrolling to the answer. By this time everything is off screen. Clicks weren't the only thing that we measured, but they were an important metric for us, especially for unregistered or low-reputation users. We also tracked searches, because we want searching to increase or not decrease since this will likely result in less duplicate questions asked.

Comment: "We've interviewed a lot of users who had no idea..." Oh, great. Tyranny of the casual user majority.

Comment: @Kurtis: interesting! But I'm not a new user. To me the sticky bar is distracting and contains mostly irrelevant links for me. I never use the Jobs or Tags or Documentation links, and I'll happily use my Home button to go back to the top for the rest. When I am answering I look for the question to get details right, and notifications that distract me from answering are *hindering at that point*. Please separate the daily power user from the unregistered casual visitor!

Comment: @JoshCaswell We've interviewed a lot of new and veteran users, but this is also something that's been asked for on meta and lot of users within this post like. Because some power users don't like something doesn't automatically mean it is a poor design for all power users and we don't care about their needs. Saying things like "tyranny of the casual user majority" may be one of the reasons some people outside this community perceive it as unfriendly to new users.

Comment: I didn't say "new user", I said "casual user". I don't know how else you could describe someone, new or veteran, that doesn't know that there are nav links in the header of literally _every page_ on the site.

Comment: And if those users are numerous or important enough that the design needs to be changed to accommodate them, then so be it, but that doesn't require me to be happy about a more obtrusive presentation of the same functionality.

Comment: "[the sticky bar] is also something that's been asked for on meta"...and negatively scored every time that I've seen.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I so agree: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343582/295783

Comment: @mplungjan: my concern [has been addressed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation). I'm happy again.

Comment: Let me just say that as a power user of SE, I had fixed the *old* bar to be sticky because I want quick access to everything from everywhere in a page.

Comment: Review is now both a link *and* a drop-down. Consistency! https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653

Answer (score 26):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Keyboard shortcuts for the new icons are broken.

The following keyboard shortcuts no longer work:

- <kbd>T</kbd> tabs...
- <kbd>I</kbd> inbox
- <kbd>R</kbd> recent achievements
- <kbd>Q</kbd> mod messages

I use <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd> **all the time**, and these not working may require me to opt out of the beta. I'll see how long I can tolerate this.

Comment: *all the time* ... just admit you're a bit obsessive about your gained achievements ... mr 500K +   ....  ;)

Comment: @rene: I use `I` all the time to be responsive to messages like yours. I use `R` to check if I need to give some attention to old posts (as long as I am not yet capped). Old posts sometimes need gardening..

Comment: this is definitely a bug. will fix it asap.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I take your word for it ... ;)

Comment: This is fixed in the next build.

Comment: And there was *much* rejoicing! Thanks, @Oded

Comment: I have never heard of the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: @matt: original blog post from 2012: https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/stack-exchange-keyboard-shortcuts/. Announcement that the shortcuts are now part of SE proper from 2014: [Announcement: Keyboard shortcuts are now integrated into the site](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/237166). Enable them in [your preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current).

Answer (score 23):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) (now that people have the option to [disable the fixed behaviour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation))

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Make the top bar smaller.

It doesn't really bother me when I'm at the top of the page, but when I'm focusing on actual content, I like my vertical screen estate, [as deceze puts it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343132/1387346).

So at least when you scroll down the page, maybe in a responsive kind of way?

Here's a preview of what that could look like (I made it 30px here, the "BETA" font size had to be reduced a little).

[image: smaller top bar]

And a stylish style sheet to obtain that, in case you want to play with it (NB. this stays small when you're at the top of the page).

```css
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
body.newheader {
/* padding-top:60px; */
 padding-top:33px;
}

input[type="submit"],input[type="button"],button,.button,.btn,[class*="btn-"],.hero-box.double-panel .panel.white .btn {
/*  padding:.61538462em 1em; */
 padding:5px 1em;
}
.f-input,textarea.f-input,input[type="text"].f-input,input[type="password"].f-input,input[type="number"].f-input,input[type="email"].f-input,input[type="url"].f-input,input[type="search"].f-input,input[type="tel"].f-input,input[type="datetime"].f-input {
/*  padding:8px 16px; */
 padding:5px 16px;
}
.gravatar-wrapper-42,.gravatar-wrapper-42 img {
/*  height:42px */
 height:30px
}
.so-header .-logo {
/*  background-position:0 -500px */
 background-position:0 -400px;
 background-size: 151.2px 424px;
}
.so-header .-logo._glyph {
/*  width:25px; */
/*  height:30px; */
 width:20px;
 height:24px;
}
.so-header .navigation .-list {
/*  height:57px */
 height:30px
}
.so-header .navigation .-link {
/*  line-height:57px; */
 line-height:30px;
/*  height:57px; */
 height:30px;
}
.so-header .navigation .beta-badge {
/*  font-size:10px; */
 font-size:8px;
/*  top:35px */
 top:19px;
}
.so-header .secondary-nav .-list {
/*  height:57px; */
 height:30px;
}
.so-header .secondary-nav .-link {
/*  height:57px; */
/*  line-height:57px; */
 height:30px;
 line-height:30px;
}
.so-header .my-profile {
/*  padding:16.5px 10px; */
 padding:3px 10px;
}
.so-header .searchbar input[type="text"].f-input {
/*  height:36px; */
 height:28px;
}
.so-header .searchbar .btn {
/*  height:36px; */
 height:28px;
}
.profile-picture-popup .avatar-change {
/*  height:42px; */
 height:30px;
}
.profile-picture-popup .avatar-change img {
/*  height:42px; */
/*  width:42px; */
 height:30px;
 width:30px;
}
.profile-picture-popup .avatar-change .avatar-description {
/*  line-height:42px; */
 line-height:30px;
}

}
```

*Tot Zam* similarly proposed a [slightly less aggressive reduction of height and paddings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343174/4660897).

Comment: Or…just don't make it sticky and then there is no problem.

Comment: @CodyGray Why yes, it's an alternative to that. Preferably not sticky, that point's already been made. If it's really going to be sticky however, at least have it take less than 1cm of incompressible vertical screen space.

Comment: This is basically what I requested in [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343174/4660897).

Comment: @Cimbali It's just interesting how your duplicate request attracted more votes in less time. Maybe it's your dark themed browser in the screenshot :)

Comment: @Oded I suppose that's the link you meant to put there.

Answer (score 23):

- My first reaction to the site, about 5 seconds in, was

  > EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEK
  >   IT MOVES
  >   THE HORROR

  because the super-mega-expando search box is annoying. Not as much as [previous iterations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101862/eeek-the-super-mega-expando-search-box-is-annoying-part-2), but annoying nonetheless. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Don't animate what I'm already looking at. I click on the box, or type `s`, and start typing a search query. While I'm typing, the damn &()@#$&()^$&*(## thing moves. So I lose track of what I was looking at and need to spend a few seconds refocusing. I wanted to search something dammit! And there's an animation again if I move the focus out of the search box. WHY??????????

The good news is that this is the only major flaw! It's definitely not as bad as the previous top bar change. So thank you, I guess.

- I really like that the boilerplate doesn't take much space. Not like the current design where if you have a 16/9 landscape monitor you'll probably end up with less than half a monitor's worth of content of the front page, between the OS artifacts, the browser artifacts, the top bar and the huge rectangle with the site logo.
- Thank you for making the top bar usable without having an insanely wide browser window! The narrowness of the search box in its off state is unfortunate, but I think that's an acceptable compromise (as long as it expands without animating).
- I'm ambivalent about the sticky top bar. I don't see it as useful, but it doesn't distract me much. It might be annoying to waste the space with browser windows that are not very tall though. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Make the stickiness a configuration option. Stack Exchange's user interface doesn't have enough configuration options.
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Put the site name in the top bar. For two reasons.

  - For people who don't have an account, the indication of what site this is is useful. Especially since this top bar looks quite a bit like any other trendy website's top bar these days.
  - For people who do have an account, the indication of which Stack Exchange site this is is useful. Sure, SO has a distinctive icon, but many beta sites don't, a few are even non-unique.
- When the mouse hovers above the colored numbers on one of the top-right boxes (inbox, achievements, review), the number moves. WHY?????? I'm trying to read the number, don't move it! Just because you can make animations in a browser doesn't mean you should. Seriously, stop that, please. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Don't move the numbers.
- Where's the “about” link? [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Show an “about” or “help” or “tour” link to new users. When I go to some random website which is more than two pages slapped together, I want to know what this site is about, who runs it, etc. This is especially important for a site that users can interact with. Here, there are links for “about us”, “tour” and “help” but they're buried somewhere towards the bottom of the page — essentially impossible to find without searching.
  A good organization could be to show “tour” and “help” in the top bar for anonymous visitors and low-rep users. For veteran users, put those links in under the Stack Exchange slash hamburger menu at the top right.
- There are four icons at the top right. Clicking the square bra opens a menu on the page. Clicking the trophy opens a menu on the page. Clicking the pen-and-paper switches to a different URL. Clicking the Stack Exchange hamburger opens a menu on the page. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Make the review icon consistent: open a menu with links to the various review queues (plus `/tools` for 10kers).
- “Unanswered” is gone from the toplevel menu. Ok, having it under “Questions” is enough. “Badges” is gone from the toplevel menu. Yay!
- I see from a [mod's screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343130) that if you're a mod, the mod menu is inserted in the middle of the icon array, so some of the icons are moved. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Put the icons in a consistent location, add the optional icons at the end (i.e. at the left, since the icon array is right-aligned).

While you're at it, could you please fix the regressions introduced by the previous toolbar redesign?

- [Make the inbox icon easier to access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210019/make-the-top-bar-inbox-dropdown-click-target-easier-to-access). It used to be in a corner, then it moved to some random middlish place, and now it's in a different middlish place. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Put the inbox icon in a corner.
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Replace the [square bra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta/207461#comment662122_207461) icon by something recognizable such as an envelope.
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Give me [back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198613/feedback-request-new-top-bar-and-multicollider-redesign/199634#199634) a [reliable count of votes I've cast today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239601/reliable-count-of-votes-that-ive-cast-today).
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Remove the list of badges next to my avatar. This information is extremely minor and shouldn't waste space on every page. [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Put my username instead. Seeing my name is a very convenient way for me to see that I'm logged in on the site. Seeing a tiny icon doesn't have this effect.
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Restore the feature that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the search box opens the search results in a new tab. This is a more recent regression, dating back to a [jQuery update](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284996/we-have-updated-jquery-to-1-12-4-please-report-related-bugs-here/285110#285110). This feature would make the sticky top bar a lot more useful: searching is the one thing I often want to do when I'm in the middle of writing an answer (to look for older posts to cite on a related topic) or when I've scrolled down to the bottom of a question (to look for a duplicate).

Comment: _"Put the site name in the top bar."_ It's been stated that logged out users do see the full logo and not just the icon, similar to how Meta is set up. _"Show an “about” or “help” or “tour” link to new users. "_ Likewise, the team said that users below a certain rep get the help center link.

Comment: "Where's the “about” link?" If you have more than 500 rep, it isn't shown as they need space for /review. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343167/792066

Comment: I don't get your annoyance about the numbers. Why would you want to read the number when you are putting your cursor on top of it?

Comment: @KodosJohnson I see that there's something interesting in this part of the screen, so I go to click on it. While I'm moving my mouse and I have my eyes on the goal, I read the actual number. And it moves!

Comment: that's very valuable feedback, thank you! let me quickly answer to some points you've made: 1. we keep site name for anonym users and for meta (both logged in&out). glyph is only on main SO for logged in. 2. help is visible for logged out and "low-rep" (internal naming) users. at some point we replace it with 'review' icon, but help is still accessible from footer. 3. rethinking review interaction (no dropdown etc.) is on our todo list. 4. nav for mods is also something we're working on. 5. we gonna *slightly* update topbar on other sites soon as well to be more in line with new header on SO.

Answer (score 21):

One thing that confused me a few times now was the counter for the review queues. It's now directly besides the inbox and achievement counters.

The inbox and achievement counters are about me, the user. The review queue (and also the moderator flag counter, which I can't see on SO) are about the site.

I found that confusing, though this might go away over time. I'd generally prefer to make those different types of counters distinct in some way, but I'm not sure if that is possible without disrupting the rest of the new design.

Comment: See [Jon Ericson's answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343131/424903) which was posted after yours, apparently things and stuff will be done about the lack of distinction in that corner of the bar.

Answer (score 20):

I was just looking at https://github.com/ and I think SE should take a few design ideas from their header. This example demonstrates how some of the complaints brought up in other posts can be addressed.

[image: GitHub topbar]

1. Their header is not dark, yet still has enough contrast which separates the top-bar nicely from the rest of the page content.
2. There is minimal whitespace and padding on the top and bottom of the navigation elements - enough for it to look good, yet not too much that it wastes excessive amount of screen space.
3. The search bar is in the front of the top-bar and not floating randomly in the middle. The search bar can be placed in the beginning or end of the top-bar, yet it doesn't belong in the middle. The height is also shorter than GitHub icon, which makes it look better. The current SO search bar is for some reason taller than all the other navigation elements, making it slightly jarring.
4. They just display their icon and not the GitHub company name, and no one has ever complained about that. I think once people get used to how the SO icon currently is on the main SO site, it will be fine. The StackOverflow words can probably be removed from meta.
5. A large element that takes up a lot of space on the SO header is the reputation and badges count next to the avatar. I know it is a nice moral boost to always have your accomplishments visible, yet I'm really not sure this is necessary to always display. Removing this information would clear up some horizontal space in the top-bar, thus increasing usability. I personally would vote for usability over seeing my rep and badges. If too many users like this display and this isn't removed, another idea would be make the numbers two lines and move the rep number on top of the badge count, which would at least add a drop of horizontal space to the bar.
6. Yes, there are few less tabs and icons on SO than GitHub, yet the GitHub bar still seems to be *sooo* much less crowded even after I added a few placeholder items.

Comment: 7. Most importantly, *it is not sticky*!

Comment: 4. we also display glyph only for logged in users on SO. we keep full logo for rest. 5. we can't simply get rid of badges and rep. it may not be important for you but it is important for lots of our users who care about tracking badges & rep becasue it's part of gamification. 6. i think actually github has less icons and tabs...

Comment: @Paweł 5. I know a lot of users like the rep and badges and that is why I also suggested stacking the numbers on 2 lines. 6. I said that GitHub has less tabs and icons, yet I as I mentioned, I tested by adding additional placeholder tabs and icons and it still seamed less crowded.

Comment: @CodyGray I actually don't mind the sticky, so I didn't bring it up.

Comment: Note that the Github header is only 1px shorter than SO's (59px vs 60px). It might be that the box-shadow makes it seem larger.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That's interesting because the overall appearance seems a lot smaller, or at least less invasive of screen space.

Comment: Yeah, now that I look at it, it's probably the borders. Github has none, whereas SO has a thick top border and a thin bottom border, plus the shadow.

Comment: To put the SO search box next to the logo: `.-logo,#search { order: -1; }`

Comment: "Their header is not dark" This is... no longer true, for some reason.

Comment: Agree with all things said, that exactly describes my experience and concerns. I think it is worth making a new thread pushing these issues.

Comment: @ETHproductions It's funny how GitHub changed their top-bar to black only 2 after I complimented that I liked the light-gray. I actually think the new black bar is too stark and contacted GitHub's support to let them know.

Answer (score 18):

This post is my initial feelings on the new bar. I'm going to use it for a few hours, based on Shog's [advice](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5748024#5748024), but I want to document my first impressions/issues with the new bar.

The new bar is thicker than the current black top bar, but the "Ask Question" button seems to start at the same location. This makes the page feel more "squished". This is a minor detail. Related to that "squished" feeling, is the lack of contrast between the navigation and the page content.

[image: Squished Top Bar]

---

I've navigated around the main and meta sites for a little while now and I can safely say that I am not a fan of the sticky navigation bar. It is distracting and contains links to things that I don't need immediate access to. I click on "Questions" 1-2 times a day. Usually, I spend my time watching specific tags, not watching the newest questions. I click on "Jobs" a handful of times a week. I don't use the documentation button on the navigation bar. Instead, I use the documentation link inside of the ways I am watching. This gets me directly where I want to be, instead of requiring me to navigation the documentation main page.

[image: Documentation I use]

I can't remember the last time I needed the "users" or "tags" links. The search on Stack Overflow leaves a lot to be desired, so most of my searching occurs through Google.

The other indicators are a great way to interrupt what I'm doing. With the black navigation bar, I can answer a question, work on reviews, etc. with the bar out of sight. If I get a notification, I don't see it immediately. Now, as soon as I get a notice, I am distracted by the new indicator.

[image: Great...now what?]

---

Moving the mouse down into the site selector is tedious. It's already been [mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343136/189134), but I think it's important to mention again. The easiest path to take once the menu is open is a straight line, not down then left. Unfortunately, the straight line causes the box to close (because I hit the review queue "menu"). Worse, it doesn't close completely, so in my confusion to reopen it, if I mouse over any of the other menus, there are multiple popup menus.

---

I haven't used the new bar on my phone or tablet yet. I will document those when I do.

---

**Summary of first impressions**: I am trying to find things I like, but that stickiness is really making me hate it. I can get used to the new icons and the links being moved around, but I don't think the navigation bar being stuck there constantly is actually *helping* me navigate around the site.

I don't use any of those links consistently enough to need immediate access. The indicators on the right are more of a distraction. That makes it feel like wasted space to me.

Comment: On top of the documentation link in the tag, there's also a jobs link in the info bar if you're using the new tabs. So really neither of those links are necessary outside of the front page.

Answer (score 17):

[status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) (now that people have the option to [disable the fixed behaviour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation))

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Decrease height and padding

There still seems to be a bit of extra whitespace surrounding all the navigation elements.

Currently the average height is 57px and the padding is 16.5px.

```
height:57px;

.so-header .my-profile {
    padding:16.5px 10px;
}
```

> [image]

If you decrease the height and padding even just slightly, it still looks okay and it wastes less screen space.

```
height:40px;

.so-header .my-profile {
    padding:13px 10px;
}
```

> [image]

This should make users concerned about the nav [eating up their screen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343174#comment443887_343103) happier.

Comment: @Oded I don't think making it "unsticky" solves this request. I actually like the sticky bar, I just think top-bar is unnecessarily tall. I don't mind the top-bar being sticky and taking up some space since I think it has a purpose, yet I still don't want unnecessary space used.

Comment: I understand your point of view. We will look at reducing the height, but not for launch. I don't believe the designers will reduce it to the extent you have shown. Perhaps a user stylesheet will be best for you right now.

Comment: @Oded I'm okay waiting for this until after launch, as long I know it is being considered. Should this be changed to reviewed instead of declined then?

Answer (score 16):

As numerous others have pointed out, "Review Queues" notification is extremely annoying.

Also, **it makes no sense at all**. Please see the below picture:

[image: it makes no sense at all]

I have just finished my 20 suggested edits, as you can tell from the graying out of "Suggested Edits" section. Still, the notification shows "65 unread", which must be the number of suggested edits. I can't even *begin* to describe how wrong this is:

1. It's annoying.
2. I don't wont it to show "unread"s if I cannot review any suggested edits.
3. Why is other categories ignored? Don't you want my involvement in other categories?
4. It's annoying.

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request): Please make it possible for the users to subscribe to the review queues they like. For example, I personally don't like to Triage.

And then, make the indicator show the number of review queues that has items, AND that user has subscribed, AND the ones that user has not exhausted the daily limit.

I can promise you that I will be more engaged in the review process if Stack Overflow does this.

Comment: This particular issue is being discussed. We're working through solutions and will address this in the near future.

Comment: This is how the review queue notification always worked - it is the same way as the black top bar. I am finding it a bit difficult to parse what exact issue you are having here - can you explain in detail?

Comment: @Oded: It shows the number of available suggested edits, even when I have completed my quota of 20 per day. That's one of my issues. The second one is that the notification being too prominent, but that has been pointer out by others.

Comment: Yes, as the old one has. This is not a change in behaviour.

Comment: The old one didn't evoke the same "notification" feeling though.

Comment: Fixed-ish: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653

Answer (score 15):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) : [We're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation)

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) I'm really not a fan of sticky sections on desktop browsers. Could we get an option to unpin it so that it doesn't stay visible when we scroll down the page?

Answer (score 13):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I really love that the Ask question button is gone when you're on the Home tab:

[image: no questions asked]

and you only get that option if you managed to navigate to another tab. That should reduce the influx of low quality stuff dramatically.

[image: question can be asked]

So basically the new top bar is both improved navigation AND a quality project.

Well done!

Comment: FWIW, I'm seeing that button everywhere. Maybe that's just a deterrent for low-rep users? :P

Comment: @deceze are you also using the new nav?

Comment: @rene I'm also seeing it everywhere - and using the new nav (and I've less rep that you so @ deceze's comment isn't right)

Comment: OK, it must be due to my low-rep then. Point taken.

Comment: @rene I've waaaaay less rep than you

Comment: I'm on Chrome / Win 10, and just disabled all my plugins: I can still repro.

Comment: that's weird. we will take a look if we can reproduce it. basically 'Ask question' button was moved to top section of sidebar. it's not on every page but only on some of them. however it supposed to be on home.

Comment: Hilarious. Cheering for a change... only to learn it wasn't intended :).

Comment: @Paweł repro-ed at my end: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vihw.png using Chromium 55.0.2883.75 (Developer Build) built on Debian stretch/sid, running on Debian 9.0 (64-bit)

Comment: @rene - got any ad blockers running? User stylesheets/scripts?

Comment: @Oded nope, sorry. I disabled all those when I repro-ed. And I don't have ad-blockers installed at all. On this laptop that is. I can try to repro when I'm at home tonight at a different box.

Comment: Is the button there in the source of the page?

Comment: @Oded nope, no evidence of it being there. I did find it for the working tabs, obviously

Comment: @Oded here is a screenshot with my two DOM's, at the top with a question button, at the bottom without  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXYID.png

Comment: OK, digging further. I can't seem to manage and repro though :/

Comment: I'm able to repro this, both on Meta and Main. No "Ask Question" button on the "home" tab in new nav, but it's on all my other tabs. Latest Chrome, windows 7.

Comment: OK, only on the homepage and when using the "expanded" view of the new nav. Fixed in the next build...

Comment: Kudos for finding that @Oded ... thanks!

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) The header where review buttons are in review tasks used to be sticky too but now they are going under the nav bar

[image]

I'm sure it is not just disappearing bacause I can see it if the header is higher

[image]

It clearly needs a `margin-top` as high as the nav bar is

Comment: This will be fixed in a few minutes: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343147/new-top-nav-should-not-overlay-review-bar

Comment: I like your gifv's, what tool did you use for them?

Comment: @TravisJ - [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) it is 100% free

Answer (score 13):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
I like the new header and design, though I did find a bug with the modal windows when going through the close queue.

At a certain time I could drag the model window in such a way that I couldn't drag it back or reach the close button.

This is not a critical bug in my opinion, merely annoying if one wants to review the text still and then drag the modal window back in place, or to change your mind on the close reason

I took a small screen shot of the problem
[image]

As [DavidG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1663001/davidg) remarked, the problem is more of an issue for smaller resolutions. As he pointed out, he cannot even see the top bar, and he can hardly click the duplicate reason. In the comments, we decided to add the screen shot of his problem as these 2 issues are related

[image: Small resolution no top bar and duplicate of is hardly reachable]

> Actually I think this is more of an issue that you think. I just happen to be using a laptop with a small screen right now (1366x768) and with a bookmark bar in Chrome the top of the modal is not visible. If I make the vertical size a bit smaller, the top of the modal is completely inaccessible.

As Pawel remarked this has not to do with the new navigation, I switched back to the old navigation and there the behavior is different.

For example, the modal popup actually goes above the top bar, as you can see here

[image]

So there is never the possibility that the top of the modal window would be inaccessible with the old top bar, but with the new top bar both DavidG & me have experienced this problem

Comment: Actually I think this is more of an issue that you think. I just happen to be using a laptop with a small screen right now (1366x768) and with a bookmark bar in Chrome the top of the modal is not visible. If I make the vertical size a bit smaller, the [top of the modal is completely inaccessable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArgsA.png).

Comment: @DavidG Luckily you can close the modal window by clicking next to the modal window, that's why I didn't think it such a big problem. It is of course annoying that you cannot move the modal or access the title bar

Comment: The issue isn't with closing it, it's being able to select 'duplicate' as a close reason.

Comment: @DavidG Should I edit the answer to include your statement as a bug, or would you like to add your concerns by editing it?

Comment: Sure if you like - I don't mind either way. As long as the devs get the feedback, that's all that really matters.

Comment: @DavidG I added your issue to the post, feel free to correct anything if you want ;)

Comment: this mod popup definitely needs some work but i don't think it's related to new header. you can dismiss it by clicking anywhere else outside the popup. plus, there will be the same issue if you move it outside the viewport. so for now this is [status-deferred] (at least if we talk about new header).

Comment: @Paweł I would disagree, I reverted to the previous top bar, and there I can never come into the situation that the top of the modal window is hidden behind the top bar. I have added an extra screen shot demonstrating the more correct behavior with the old top bar

Comment: I'm sorry, I initially misunderstood this issue and was thinking about something else apparently :(. Fix is waiting in repo for next build.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel I guess my explanation was not clear enough

Answer (score 11):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) “Full Page” Stack Snippets can’t be closed

When you click “Full Page” below, try to close it.

```js
$(window).one('blur', function() {
  alert('You can’t close me!');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Click “Full Page” <span style="float: right">^^^^^^^^</span>
```

Comment: reproduced. looking into it right now.

Comment: fix is waiting in repo for build. thanks for reporting that!

Comment: @Paweł It’s not fixed. There’s no button to exit full screen..

Comment: Looks like a z-index problem. The so-header has a z-index of 1030; the popin has 999.

Comment: oh you're right. i missed that .popin thing. fix incoming..

Answer (score 11):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I thought I was going nuts but I've just confirmed that the colour of the reputation notification is blue if it's been added by an Ajax call (i.e. sat on the page and someone votes on a post of mine):

[image]

However, it is green (the correct colour in my opinion!) when the page is refreshed:

[image]

It looks like the `span` gets a `_positive` class on refresh that is missing in the Ajax update.

Comment: This bug is known and will be fixed before launch. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

One of the things I appreciate about the existing top bar is not having to click to switch between the site switcher, the inbox, and the achievements dropdown once one of them has been opened.

The arrangement of the icons is different in the new version, but it'd still be nice to at least be able to go between the inbox and achievements without an extra click. Ideally, being able to switch between all dropdowns even after mousing over the "review" icon so long as the cursor doesn't leave the topbar would be good too.

(I made a noble effort to try recording a gif to show what I mean, but failed. To see the behaviour I'm talking about, just compare the existing topbar on, say, MSE with the new one here.)

Comment: I think it actually *did* work like this yesterday. The problem is, the sites (formerly Gen-u-wine™) button is now *really small*, and so most of the sites menu expands under the other buttons... So when I'd try to move the mouse from the button to the sites list, I'd end up opening the mod inbox instead. **Edit:** [report is here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343180/quick-route-from-meta-to-main), marked "planned" - but looks like balpha already made a rough fix for it, hence the behavior you observe.

Comment: What he ^^^ said. Perhaps we could figure out a better fix going forward.

Comment: I have a fix, if interested. This script will use the SE debouncer to keep the menus open as long as you are focused on them **and** long enough so that if you move over to another it will open that one in place. The code essentially came from SE a long time ago and I slightly modified it and have kept it around. I run extensive userscripts. The debouncer SE wrote is actually really nice (love it) so it handles a lot of edge cases. It should also work with touch (haven't tested). Here is the script 4 free: https://gist.github.com/travisjj/3c50be52ce4da566867c624e8777d0a8

Comment: cc @Oded See TravisJ's comment above :)

Comment: I spoke to the team and the consensus is that we will keep the current behaviour as is - click to open a new menu. I am told this is the more standard / common behaviour seen across the web.

Comment: @Oded Why don't they just expand on hover? Why else is a cursor there?

Comment: @phi - the cursor is there to show they are clickable.

Comment: @TravisJ Could you make into a userscript?

Comment: @JF - Yes, I already have it in place. Would you like me to make a free chrome extension in the store for that snippet?

Comment: @TravisJ I’d just like it as a userscript (I don’t use Chrome) :)

Answer (score 8):

I sort of like the new design now it has more colours BUT:

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)

I have ZERO (0) need to look at or ever click the static links to

- **Questions** - I have them on the page and I lose my keywords if I click on the Questions link. I have a bookmark with [unanswered tagged JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript%20or%20jquery%20or%20html) that I use exclusively
- **Jobs** - I have a job
- **Documentation BETA**  - I am answering questions now - I do not need the majority of the nav bar taken up by a link to somewhere else
- **Tags** - SO has all the tags I need in the searchbox on the right
- **Users** - I do not ever look for users

What I DO want to see while I am scrolling are new achievements or new comments to questions. They are FAR on the right, on the periphery of my glance. I do not understand the UX need for the links to places I never go to take precedence to information I need all the time.

The contents of the red box below can be removed or moved to the far right for all I care. And the contents in the gren box put back in my line of sight

[image]

Comment: There are apparently [hordes of people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week#comment444532_343228) who fail to find or use the existing nav links at the top of the page. (!) [Getting these links more into their faces](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343132#comment444436_343132) seems to be a top goal with this redesign.

Comment: I am certainly not one of them @JoshCaswell - quite the opposite.

Comment: Well, same here. Of the five links, I use two, and even those very infrequently.

Comment: What if you didn't have a job? It'd be good to preferentially hide undesired links. Also, I consider it bad practice, and usability, to have icons with no text (I don't count title text).

Comment: The job offers lived on the right where I could ignore them.

Comment: adblock easily gets rid of all those tabs. Unfortunately that won't move the icons around.

Comment: How clever are you @KevinB ! Great suggestion

Comment: Now i'm trying to find a gist or snippet that will give me back the larger logo that you get while you're not logged in that i can apply with robogist. Guess all it really needs is _glyph removed

Comment: https://gist.github.com/tentonaxe/b2e22f5d8e85b5d515939ebaa23fb656

Comment: Adblock: `stackoverflow.com##.-main`

Answer (score 7):

## Paging down hides content behind the sticky navigation

Before the new navigation, I could easily read long questions and answers by paging down using <kbd>Space</kbd> (presumably <kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>PgDn</kbd> work the same way). With the current implementation of the sticky navigation, text slides behind it, which means that this navigation style has to either be disregarded in favor of arrow keys, supplanted with arrow keys to "fix up" the page amount, or switch completely away from keyboard navigation to the mouse.

Please adjust it so that paging down brings the bottom of the presently-shown content to the top of the effective viewport, not placed behind the header.

---

**After loading a page**:

[image: Before paging down]

**After paging down with <kbd>Space</kbd>**

[image: After using space to page down]

The text that I want to read next is now behind the navigation. It should be directly below it:

[image: What I expected to happen]

**Bonus animation**

[image: Animation of problem occurring]

This was taken with all extensions disabled, hopefully ruling those out. Note that an entire comment ("Can we opt out...") disappears behind the navigation in this example.

---

Environment

- macOS 10.12.3 (16D32)
- Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)

  - LastPass: Free Password Manager 4.1.39 (also when disabled)
  - React Developer Tools 0.15.7 (also when disabled)
  - Redux DevTools 2.13.2 (also when disabled)

Comment: @Oded I've not participated in this way before — with [tag:status-completed], should I expect to see the change already, or is it waiting for a future deploy? It doesn't appear to be live for me (even after a page reload).

Comment: Should already be OK. I can't repro, which is why I marked it as such. What browser/OS are you on, in case this is something specific (also - if you have any user scripts/extensions/plug-ins - they might interfere).

Comment: @Oded oops, that was a bad bug report on my end; I've added that and an "expected" picture, to make sure we are on the same page.

Comment: To confirm - this is still an issue for you? What happens when you disable the different extensions? I am on latest Chrome, Windows 10 and can't repro.

Comment: @Oded yep. I just disabled all 3 extensions and recorded a GIF of it happening.

Comment: I've just confirmed this doesn't repro on Win10 with Chrome56 but MacOS Sierra with Chrome56 (through BrowserStack) this **does** repro.

Comment: @Oded this is actually a much **bigger problem** than I originally thought, as when I am linked to a comment, it appears behind the navigation, *completely hiding the comment*! Would you like me to add another answer, edit this one, or something else?

Comment: It is essentially the same issue - paging down causes part of the page to be obscured by the header. A couple of people are looking at how to fix this - no need to make any changes/update this post/post a new question.

Comment: @Oded yep, it's certainly the same cause, just wanted to make sure y'all were aware of another (probably more common) way of triggering the behavior.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an "issue", but a matter of browser behaviour vs design. The design stipulates a sticky nav, but the browser couldn't care less. The browser will scroll down the amount it states no matter the design of the page.

Answer (score 7):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (in the next build)

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The link to the homepage has no visual cue when hovering over it like the rest of the menu items where the background turns gray. In other words, the hover effect is missing on the logo. For consistency I think its background color should change on hover like the rest of the navigation bar items.

[image]

I'm also not crazy about the reduction in width of the homepage link. With the current (and soon to be old I assume) navigation, I click the site's text/icon link possibly more than anything else in the navigation, but I didn't realize how easy this was until I had to focus on clicking this much smaller icon instead.

I'd also like to see the "stackoverflow" text returned if room permits. Seems strange to me that the site has gotten so minimalist as to not even show its own name.

Comment: This is notably missing. I'm guessing they didn't add a hover color because it would make two bugs very obvious: The logo is misaligned with the rest of the site (it is too far to the left - it should be aligned with the text), and the logo has no left padding.

Comment: Left padding fixed: `padding-left: 12px; margin-left: -12px;` [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNmCw.png)

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) When I click on the review button, why am I taken to Suggested Edits queue instead of the list of review queues? I don't even have enough rep to review suggested edits. It takes a whole extra step now to get to the rest of the review queues.

**Extra step === less likely to bother with the other review queues.**

> [image]

Please switch it back so the button takes you to the list of queues.

Comment: Duplicate of [this other answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343135/4320665).  Also very related to [another suggestion to fix the same problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343139/4320665).

Answer (score 6):

It's not as ghastly as I imagined from the previously published screen shot.

- I rather like that the notifications are more closely grouped with the other personal info.
- I like that narrowing the browser steals space from the filter rather than MyStuff scrolling off first, since we will likely have to live with it.

That's all the positive comments I have.

I still don't think the nav/view Tabs belong in the same space. Stack Overflow is about "Questions". Who spends time browsing tags as a primary activity? Or users? I understand Jobs will always and forever be foisted upon us as a *key thing*, but if I was to ever browse them or tags or whatever, I'd open a new tab for them so that the much much more important question view would still be there.

It basically seems to be designed to highlight the things Stack Overflow wants us to use/visit, rather than facilitating the focal point of Stack Overflow (i.e. "Questions and Answers").

It's <strike>stupid</strike> suboptimal and lacking conceptual integrity to have the search/filter in the center.

1. Personally, mine is permanently set to filter to the tags I watch. I don't need it super handy to search something else
2. It looks highly non-standard since most everywhere puts it top right.
3. When I do search, I usually use Google for a more comprehensive search. On the rare occasion that I use the built in search, I use it in a new tab so as not to loose my place in `Questions`. The UI ought to favor, facilitate and accept that `Questions` are the primary focus of Stack Overflow (not Tags, not Users, not Docs).

Since the nav tabs now inhabit the same space as the filter/search, I would **expect them to be fully integrated and they are not**. If I click `users` then go back to "Questions" **the filter I had is lost**. I understand why, but the new presentation implies more smarts than it has.

Taken together, especially that the Filter/Search box is the first to yield space, it should be on the right.

---

I am not a fan of the sticky bar - I thought sticky was just supposed to be for new/low rep users? I do like that it means you can always see Notifications, but that does not justify its existence.

I **do not need** to be able to flick over to `Tags` (or anything else) at a moments notice. I **do need** vertical space.

Even as a sticky, a dark background would help identify it as *something else*.

Answer (score 6):

This may be slightly off-topic, but: The Close Votes queue has over 8,600 entries. All of the other review types have a combined 798 entries. What does the count of 846 above the Review Queues button represent?

> [image]

Comment: The counter doesn't count the close queue. And caching, lots of it. Also the counter is about all the outstanding reviews, not only the ones you are able to do (you have reviewed 846-798=48 items).

Comment: The best you can do with that is using stylish and add this css: `.js-review-button > .indicator-badge {
    display: none; 
}`, the information is not really useful right now

Comment: The review numbers shown now are the same as before and due to a combination of many factors they bear little relation to the count of review items. See [Notification for reviews shows way too many](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742) and hundreds of other similar reports across the SE network, with response from SE evolving from [meta-tag:status-bydesign] to [a reluctant admission that the current situation is not optimal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238472/review-count-fix-it-or-lose-it/238515#238515).

Comment: Review numbers are removed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The homepage logo link is too small. To get to the homepage, we need to click *exactly* on the logo:

[image]

This is in contrast to all other links that take the full height of the navigation bar and have extra padding on both sides:

[image]

Comment: clickable area for logo will be increased in coming build.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently I don't get counted unless I vocalize that I actually like something in the design, so here goes:

- I like it white
- I like it sticky
- I like it with the search bar in the middle
- I like it with the menus on the right
- I like it with the user card thingy where it is

Here is what I would like to see changed, but I can write—and have already written—a userscript to change if they are not changed:

- I could take or leave the rest of the buttons on the left hand side.
- I think that removing the bottom border makes it much less intrusive.
- I think the review button should have a menu linking to the individual review queues, and the 10k+ tools. This would also be a good place to put the moderator flag review stuff.

Comment: Of course this will be downvoted to oblivion because those who actually like it the way it is won't be scanning through every answer and upvoting the ones that approve of the design, and those who dislike the design will be vehemently scanning through every answer and downvoting the ones that approve of the design. Yet this will be taken as evidence that no one likes the design, and everyone thinks it should be something different. This is why voting is a useless measure in this case.

Comment: _"but I can write—and have already written—a userscript to change if they are not changed"_ - If that's the result of a re-design, something went wrong with the re-design.

Comment: Re voting: You can't blame the _"against"_ people for _"for"_ users' in-activeness. People that dislike the design aren't responsible for keeping everyone voting.

Comment: I absolutely do not understand how someone could like the top bar being sticky. The other things just seem like normal, subjective opinions, but making the thing sticky so that it takes up permanent room on my screen when I'm trying to focus on other things just seems absolutely unjustifiable, and I honestly cannot understand how someone would ever be *okay* with that, much less *like* it. Maybe it is a fundamental difference in how different people use the site. If you treat it like a chat room, I guess getting immediate notifications would be important.

Comment: @Cerbrus no one is forcing you to use an invalid metric to justify your arguments either. The stuff in the last block is wishful thinking, it doesn't have to change for me to be happy with the design.

Comment: @Cody I love instant gratification. Simple as that. Keep in mind that my voting controls are sticky as well.

Comment: It's like you were eating waffles and got syrup all over your screen!

Comment: @cody I also love waffles and syrup, so that is a possibility

Comment: I like the sticky header because it lets me know immediately while I'm scrolling the depths of Meta if someone needs clarification on something I've posted. I like the sticky header because I can immediately and easily access certain parts of the page while my hand is already on the mouse. I was looking up an answer and trying it in my code, found another search worthy issue, and need to search it? The search bar is already right there even though I'm scrolled down to the answer section. I decide halfway through reading something that I want to review? Boom, it's right there. TLDR: I like it.

Comment: @CodyGray Liking the bar being sticky is as much a subjective opinion as the other points. Like Kendra, I also like the sticky bar. I like that I can immediately see new notifications even if I am not currently on the top of a page and I like that I can easily navigate to any of the links on the top-bar, no matter how far I have scrolled down on a page. Maybe it is just that my screen size is large enough that I don't mind using a drop of space to make navigation easier.

Comment: I guess that's the difference. All of the people who are addicted to notifications love the stickiness. I try my hardest to *ignore* the notifications. I get oodles of them every day, and just don't have time to read them all. Sometimes, if I don't sign in for a few days, the counter goes well over 100, I think about reading them, so I click on the icon, but don't want to open 100+ tabs, so they all get cleared and I never see them. Oh well, it's rare that I miss anything important. I'd just as well have the whole notification system go away completely. I certainly don't want *more* of it.

Comment: @Cody http://stackexchange.com/users/current/?tab=inbox

Comment: @TinyGiant - on your stackexchange.com profile.

Comment: 948 pages, Tiny Giant. How do I know which ones are "new" and which ones I've already seen? Would be nice if the highlighting of new messages was persistent there.

Comment: @CodyGray I just tested and you are correct that it does not highlight new messages. [I've posted an uber meta feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290931/288751)

Comment: Can you write me a userscript that removes the static links to places I never go and puts the icons with "new comment added"  and "achivements" back in my line of sight? I am sure my http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343582/295783 answer will be voted to hell

Comment: @mplungjan I'll write something up tomorrow.

Comment: That drop-down thing? It happened. It happened **because of all the nice things you said:** https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653

Comment: @Shog9 Ooo something good happened because I said nice things? I should do that more often.

Answer (score 6):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

When editing the communities list, the "Add a Stack Exchange community" text is cut off on the top and bottom:

[image: Font is too large]

This only happens when using the new top bar.

I'm using Firefox 45.7.0, Windows 7.

Comment: On Firefox 50.1.0, Windows 8.1 too

Comment: This is being looked at. Thanks for reporting.

Comment: @Oded I have the same error on the previous search box too: https://i.gyazo.com/84825708f7ad3b074bc29957c71459ce.png Firefox 51.0.1 Windows Vista 32bits

Comment: @freestock.tk - thanks for confirming this isn't a new header issue.

Answer (score 6):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) **Alignment issue with people reached tooltip**

The tooltip of the people reached is partially hidden by the top bar.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: People reached tooltip]

The actual tool tip content is

> Estimated number of times people viewed your helpful posts
>   (based on page views of your questions
>   and questions where you wrote highly-ranked answers)

Comment: @Oded - I just came here to report this same bug, but it was marked status-completed in February. Is what I'm seeing a regression, or is the fix not live for some reason? Should I re-report elsewhere? Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) - for reference.

Comment: Seems to have come back, @Chris - someone is looking into it.

Comment: @Chris : It was [reported here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349758/2451726)

Comment: Ah - search fail! Thanks @Arulkumar!

Answer (score 6):

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) (Psuedo-tagged this as a discussion because it's not really a feature request or a bug.)

[image]

I'd like to know how useful the "Questions" link is on the top nav. I realise it's been there for eternity and that it shows *all questions* with the most recent at the top. However, we have a new set of tabs below that (i.e. the [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav)) that flips us between different sets of questions. Couldn't the "all questions" tab just exist in the secondary nav? If I manually create a tab that mimics it (no filter, order by newest) then clicking the "Questions" link even automatically selects the new tab.

Maybe it's a much-used link and I'm just being too finicky but I personally have never felt the need to click on it. Does anyone else use it? I can imagine it being more useful on meta to see a feed of new questions coming in, but on the main site, it just seems to be taking up a lot of horizontal screen estate.

Not sure this discussion will go anywhere, but I'm interested to hear other people's opinions.

Comment: If you are in the documentation section of the site, how do you get back to Q&A?

Comment: @Oded Yeah, that was the only thing I could think of, but the SO icon takes you home again.

Comment: Home != Questions - they are different lists, sorted differently.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I suggested adding a tab to the secondary nav that had the same list of questions.

Comment: I'd be curious how many people actually used that uncurated list of all questions too.

Comment: I never use it. I have a bookmark with /unaccepted/tagged/jQuery+OR+javascript - see my answer for more comments on useless links http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343582/295783

Comment: @mplungjan Exactly, that's part of my point. I have a tab on the new navigation rather than a bookmark. But the questions link is just a waste of space, at least it is for me.

Answer (score 6):

I feel like there's an xkcd comic (or two) that says what we're all thinking…

[image: Workflow]

Or alternatively…

[image: UI Change]

---

That being said, the new topbar has some ways to go. My first impression upon visiting this site was that *it looked professional.* The main reason for this was the contrast between the thin, black header and the big white part beneath it. But now, with the white topbar, I'm getting… warm, fuzzy feelings. Puffy and such. It feels like I'm on TVTropes.

I really would not have taken this site seriously if I had first visited it while the new topbar was at the top. **Appearance *matters*.**

Answer (score 6):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

The old header was half the height of this new design. I very rarely use the header to begin with, so I would appreciate it if the new header was a little shorter.

Here's how the header is now:

[image: Big and fluffy]

You can shrink the header from 57px to 40px without any loss in functionality.

[image: Compact]

It's not as short as the old one, but it's a good compromise.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343181/5875416

Answer (score 6):

### Not standard logo placement

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) The different height position is easy to notice when switching tabs:

[image: Height Position]

Comment: Funny. I was looking at the top of the image and thinking "is that *really* easy to notice?". Quite some time to determine it wasn't just the change in colour. Then I noticed at the bottom of the image...

Comment: I meant 'easy to notice' once you're aware of the issue. Like "an easy way to check it is switching tabs".

Comment: Yeah, it's burned into the back of my eyeballs already, now. The bottom one now reminds me of a very old "flip paper" animation with a frog. Something on TV from..., well, not recently. I think it was in "Black and White". Now I'm really starting to ramble...

Comment: this is because label "stack overflow" in our logo is not perfectly centered (with glpyh). so when we have full version next to perfectly centered text (in this case it's navigation) we have to adjust it a little so "stack overflow" label doesn't look off. when we use version without label, we have to remove that adjustment for the same reason - to make it vertically centered. and by "centered" i meant visually centered.

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) the number inside badge got hidden

I noticed a bug after closing a list of stack exchange sites, I'm not sure if this only for items to review number, but you can test this also, simply click the list of sites:

[image: click the sites list to open it]

Then hover your mouse to list of items to review:

[image: hover mouse to number of items]

Then hover your mouse back to list of sites, you will see the list opened again.

Then click on the body to hide the list, the numbers will disappear with the menu.

Minor, but I think it is kinda important.

Comment: Afaik, the review indicator badge with numbers shouldn't be dismissible, or at least, when it's dismissed, it shouldn't appear again.

Answer (score 5):

The review button looks solitary with all the others being menus. Unlike achievement and the site switcher, which flank the review button, the later doesn't present you a menu. It looks oddly out of place, maybe it should be moved to be besides the user profile link, like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe it should open a menu with links to the review queues.

Comment: I suspect this might be to do with frequency of use going from left to right. Maybe just me but I tend to use inbox most, then reputation, then review queue, then site switcher. Not saying it's necessarily the correct order - but maybe that's why it's _currently_ in that order?

Comment: We are considering options for the review button - it may end up with a menu, may be some other option.

Answer (score 5):

After spending the day with it I can say: I like it. Contrary to what others have said, I like having it sticky. I can get a quick glance at any notifications at any time. There's just a couple of things I would change.

1. Make it darker. It's been said over and over again but the white-on-white is annoying. I've already started running some custom CSS to make it darker. In it's dark state, it looks great.
2. I wish it didn't report how many items are in the review queue. I'm a bit OCD about keeping my notifications clear and constantly seeing 800+ up there drives me a bit crazy. It was easier to ignore how many items were in the queue before. I still like seeing the rest of my notifications at a glance though.

For the time being, I've made the review queue count disappear until I hover over it and it at least feels better to me.

```
.so-header .js-review-button .js-unread-count {
  opacity: 0;
}
.so-header .js-review-button:hover .js-unread-count {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Am I the only one using this that thinks the white on white is awesome? I think the bottom border should be removed, then it would be even more awesome.

Comment: "I like having it sticky" "I wish it didn't report how many items are in the review queue.[ ...] It was easier to ignore before" does not compute!

Comment: @Braiam It was easier to ignore the *review count* before. I like being able to see the rest of it at a glance.

Comment: There was a review queue count stamped on the old top bar, too. Why did this not bother you as much? Why do you say it was easier to ignore? Maybe because it was a different color than your inbox notifications?

Comment: @CodyGray I think that's precisely the reason.

Comment: Ditto on making it darker.  White on white is VERY hard to differentiate, especially for those of us with older eyes.

Comment: Review thing is fixed: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653

Answer (score 5):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) for the reasons listed by Paweł in [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week?page=2&tab=oldest#comment444533_343275).

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug)

---

**This can now be fixed by [disabling the sticky nav in preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation).**

---

Yes, I know we have a mobile site but I prefer to use the full, desktop site on mobile.

When viewed on mobile the new header is cropped on the right when viewed at anything but 100% zoom.

The "Review queue" and "Stack Exchange" icons are lost and cannot be scrolled to.

The search bar is also deformed in to a white square making it unclear what it actually is.

[image]

Comment: the magnifying glass icon in search field is back.

Comment: @Oden I don't see the relevance of [that comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week?page=2&tab=oldest#comment444533_343275) to the bug in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like something meant for a mobile device. I wouldn't mind seeing that on my phone but on my desktop it looks out of place.

Comment: we don't have mobile update on our roadmap for now.. but some day, maybe.

Comment: @Paweł ...in which case I would rather it stayed as a desktop-oriented design. I hate it when websites treat my HD desktop monitor (and desktop browser, and desktop input devices) like a phone.

Comment: @MichealJohnson I wouldn't exactly say that. Mobile menus like these nearly always have a hamburger menu on the side and nothing else to click/tap/press/etc and this one has the different links still in the header itself.

Comment: @CalvT It still looks like the kind of thing I'd expect to see on a mobile device, not a desktop. Maybe a tablet rather than a phone. Desktop interfaces should be small and inconspicuous, not big and easy to tap on. Put it this way: it looks the way everything looked when I ran Android on my laptop.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - we went with a split of the icon, bringing it back to what it was like with the black top bar.

It'd be nice if the flag count was its own clickable element, going directly to the flag queue instead of needing to go through the dropdown. Changing this element:

```
<span class="indicator-badge js-unread-count">20000</span>
```

To this:

```
<a class="indicator-badge js-unread-count" href="/admin/dashboard">20000</a>
```

Seems to work fine. Bonus points if there was a way to make it not move around on hover, but that might be too big a design change.

Comment: That seems a bit too finicky to not accidentally mis-engage to me. That's a tiny tiny click target…

Comment: @deceze In my tests, it seems fine... for me, on my MacBook trackpad with young fingers and eyes. Point taken.

Comment: Dogs are excellent trackpad users, as everyone knows. That's not representative of men slowly beginning to see the beginnings of middle age on the horizon with glasses who mostly push the cursor around randomly and rely on auto-correction when typing.

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) The `z-index` is incorrect for the job search location bar. This causes the list of suggested locations to appear above the new navigation bar when I scroll up. [Link to affected page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies). The main `/jobs` page is also affected, as well as the linked `/jobs/companies`.

[image: Where to find the problem]

[image: Incorrect Z-Index]

Answer (score 3):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Don't know its browser specific issue or not. But when i click on this url: https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current
then click on the sandwich icon then click on the search box and dropdown which appear after click on sandwich icon is disappear.

[image]

It happens first time only after that its working fine.
Browser (firefox : 51.0.1 (32-bit))

Comment: Exact duplicate of this [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343349/2451726)

Comment: We are looking into this - seems to be unique to Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) for the reasons listed by Paweł in [his comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week?page=2&tab=oldest#comment444533_343275).

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I don't get it. [The main site](http://www.stackoverflow.com/) gets a tiny, nice icon.

[image]

And meta gets a huge banner logo.

[image]

What's the point in this? Do you want there to be space consistency? Because there ain't consistency there.

Extend the search bar for all I care. Just let them both use icons.

Here is a possible design:
[image: no stack overflow text]

Comment: Meta doesn't have Jobs or Documentation…

Comment: main site has full logo when you're logged out. it's because brand recognition etc.. after you log in, we keep only glyph. for users logo is known enough to hide "stack overflow" text. we're also trying to save some space there and get rid of distraction (SO main site has more nav items than meta). as for meta, we keep full logo for both groups - logged in and logged out. why not using glyph also for meta? logo is too similar to main site and we think it makes sense to show full version. plus we have more space in header because there's no jobs & documentation.

Comment: @Paweł Please, make search extend instead.

Comment: I prefer the much larger meta logo, since the logo is the icon i click the most often... While i had the new header enabled i found myself clicking questions instead, and wondering why the list of questions i was getting wasn't what i was expecting.

Comment: @haykam How about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57acg.png)?

Comment: @JF That's awesome.

Comment: @Paweł How about the proposal I added to the answer?

Comment: @JF it's good idea, however we have some specific guidelines for branding and usage of our logo. then we have other sites (localized SO sites) using similar logo where we would have to figure out "minimized" version as well. plus we dont see meta logo being an issue. so that's why it has status-declined

Comment: Ok, so never happening. RIP.

Answer (score 2):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) The topbar design is for desktop browsers, for mobile browsers we have the mobile theme. We are not putting resources into changing the desktop view to be mobile friendly when we already have a specific mobile theme.

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)

On mobile web, full site, when you zoom in, the links on the top all get mixed up with each other.

[image]

Comment: It isn't designed for mobile use - that's why we have a mobile theme... (click "mobile" in the footer)

Comment: @Oded right, but I don't like the mobile theme...

Comment: @Mithrandir So compile a list of things that should be changed, and ask for them to be changed. :P

Comment: _"The topbar design is for desktop browsers, for mobile browsers we have the mobile theme"_ - this is 2017 guys. You can't release a design that you _know_ is broken on mobile. This is ridiculous.

Comment: I use the app...

Comment: Why use user agent sniffing at all? Why not switch to the mobile view based on the viewport size?

Answer (score 2):

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)[status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro)

Firefox / Windows.
Zoom turned off.

Something wrong with pictograms, pixels on the borders are cutted off:

[image]

Also the help pictogram is not vertically aligned:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Using latest Firefox on Windows 10. Given that these are SVG, they should scale just fine. What versions of Firefox and Windows are you on? Do you have any add-ons/plugins/user scripts that might interfere?

Comment: @Oded Firefox 51.0.1 on Windows 7 and 10. On both windows it looks exactly like on the screenshot, plugins disabled

Comment: Strange. Same version, Windows 10, I can't repro at all. Are you getting any errors in the console? Did you clear your cache and refresh the page?

Comment: @Oded hmm cleared cache, disabled all plugins but still the same. Strange indeed. Probably you can add a screenshot in my answer to see how it looks by you (with disabled zoom)

Comment: I see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLVs2.png (but, I am on a high DPI screen - 4k display).

Comment: @Oded Ok looks perfect, but I am on normal 96 dpi monitor so it can be the case why you cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Could be an issue with the browser not being able to figure out sub-pixel hinting on 96 dpi :/

Comment: @Oded BTW from [other answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343174/4157407)  - second screenshot also has cutted off pixels.

Comment: I think that's mostly because they changed the padding themselves. I have put this up on our bug board to be looked at.

Answer (score 2):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (in the next build)

### Glitch/Flickering search bar on Enter (Mozilla Firefox)

[bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Once I press Enter the search bar visual behavior becomes bugged:

[image: search bar]

Firefox 51.0.1 Windows Vista 32-Bit

ps1: this only happens when I press Enter, not when I click on the search button (weird);

ps2: same behavior with the mouse over/not over the bar;

ps3: same behavior on SO/SOmeta.

Comment: No repro using relevant modern webkit based browsers (chrome, chromium, vivaldi, opera, neon, brave). Seems to only happen in Firefox.

Comment: @Oded this doesn't appear to be fixed. (separate question [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344172/new-search-bar-flickers))

Comment: @Oded  rev 2017.3.6.25312, still flickering.

Answer (score 1):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) (note: this was not a new header issue but a pre-existing one)

When i am viewing a job offer, while scrolling, i can see the page is flickering and the Top nav-bar is keep on playing hide and seek

[image]

Flickering of page is not able to view here, So here shared the video link,
http://recordit.co/m4XwPro0lk

This is the URL, i used https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/114547/angularjs-developer-wissen-technology

Answer (score 1):

I actually like the theme in itself, it looks rather professional and modern. However to me the whole thing feel a bit cramped. Before "Jobs" and "Documentation" were added it probably would have worked rather well.

Then if you throw in a custom tag declaration as well the top of the page starts to look really busy -
[image: stack nav with custom tag]

So really my feeling is that I like the style but dislike the overcrowded feel.   A dark style would be nice too.

Comment: I second the dark theme. It would be nice if the "jobs" and "documentation" were removed, but that may never happen as they're likely to be big revenue generators.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just wanted to point out some weird with the auto-expanding search bar. If a user is wanting to select some text that's already in the search bar then it runs away and has to be chased down despite being double-clicked on :)

This behavior could violate the [princple of least suprise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Answer (score 1):

The top border of the new navigation looks quite nice.

[image]

But since a few websites are using the exact same position to display a loading animation which looks very similar to the top border it can be misleading for the user.

Example YouTube:
[image]

The user could think that something is still loading. I know, after the first few page loads the user will realize that this is not a loading animation but rather only a style element. 
I don’t rely have a solution (other than removing the border), but maybe someone has an idea how the border could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

<s>**Two things regarding the search box:**</s>

<s>[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) When using the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to navigate through the page, the search box at the top gets focused first. This feels odd as I'd expect the logo to be focused first and the search box to only receive focus when tabbing from the *Users* link.</s> - I'm not sure how this happened when I first tried it, but I'm now unable to replicate this.

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) When one focuses the search box it has a nice smooth animation. If we then move away from it, it feels like it goes back to its default state far too quickly - this animation isn't smooth at all.

Comment: regarding focusout transition: i see that too on meta right now (however it _feels_ fine on main site). will take a closer look at this, thanks!

Comment: I personally am fine with the search box collapsing quickly. When you want to use the search, it expands slowly but that is fine because you don't care about the stuff that it overlaps. But when you don't need it, you want it to go away as fast as possible so you can click on something else. At least that is my perspective.

Answer (score 0):

[bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug) The styling of the top-bar is... odd... when I view the site on half my screen. I often have the browser on half my screen, because I have only one screen and want to have my editor on the other half.

The logo on the left is squashed against the left border of my browser.

[image: Normal view]

If you scroll right to view related questions, then the bar is actually staying in place, showing a really weird half-bar.

[image: Half a bar]

Compared to the current bar it is also very crowded, but I guess that was a design decision. Making it less crowded moves the important parts of my screen, which would be worse.

[image: Old bar]

---

User Kaiido uses an even smaller window, which will cut off the right-most icons completely in the fixed header bar. I would suggest making the bar behave differently after a certain breakpoint.

[image: Cut off]

Comment: What browser version are you running?

Comment: Chrome 56.0.2924.87 for Windows 10

Comment: And you have disabled the fixed position right ? Because with it , I get this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH2Dd.png (the top-bar doesn't scroll with the page content, and I'm unable to access rigth most links (the ones I use the more). I'm not posting as an answer, because it's actually the same issue as yours, but IMO this deserves a [meta-tag:bug] tag. (repro on both FF and chrome on osX non-retina with page width around 600px)

Comment: Yes, I have disabled the fixed behaviour. Well, I did when I posted that at least.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sort of in the same camp as @mplungjan here: the top left now has a lot of things I don't have much use for, and the stuff I want is on the right.

Where I differ though is what I use: the hamburger. I read 4-5 sites regularly (so thanks for having a list of 5 sites!) and I like to switch back and forth.  The mouse drag distance to the right (and eye distance) is much more than it used to be, since the rest of my interactions are on the left side.

I think that some of this is unavoidable, and I will live with, but in particular two things would be nice:

[feature-request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

- On Meta, any chance we can have a way to get back to the main site on the top left, or somewhere near that?  I feel like this is a *very* common action, and having to open the hamburger on the right side takes *forever* relative to what it does on the main site.  Maybe just add a fourth word, "Main".  (I know I can use G-M keyboard shortcut, but I'd like a mousey way for the what, 95%+ of users who don't use the shortcuts.)
- Can we get a new keyboard shortcut to open the hamburger/site switcher? That way I could at least have a slightly faster option for switching sites (short of using Chrome bookmarks or something...)  Or even keyboard shortcuts to go to the top 5 sites.  (<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd> for example - W for switcher, 1-5 for (top site #)).

Thanks!

Comment: FYI: we're going to update topbar network wide. It's going to be small change, mostly to keep things more in line with new structure on SO.com. So we definitely want to move site switcher to the right. Regarding meta link request: this is interesting idea but it's too early (it's been one week since we launched new header and we still need more usage data) for us to judge if we really need it there or if there's maybe something else we should prioritize. But again: idea is interesting and I will keep it in back of my head (or actually in some doc).

Answer (score -1):

Great job guys. I just have a suggestion. I have inspected the element `header` and removed the `box-shadow`. I think it looks more clean IMHO. See the print.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Screens have been landscape for a long time, so the idea of a top bar when you already have a sidebar seems redundant and wasteful. Wouldn't it make more sense to add nav bar to the sidebar? Or at least make it user-selectable?

Answer (score -4):

First I just want to say I love the overall design, I do agree that it may look better with a darker background however another user made a good point that the page is primarily white anyways so its a small difference.

I do also love that its sticky, I find myself reading very long questions fairly often and its nice to have it there for notifications and to quickly navigate away without having to do a lot of scrolling.

Two suggestions I would make are, first to reduce the height to somewhere around 70%-80% of what it is, and lastly to get it out to the whole network as soon as possible. I navigate between multiple different sites and its extremely disruptive having the network list move back and forth.

Comment: we do have plans to slightly update network sites topbar to be more in line with new structure we use on Stack Overflow. so yes, it's on roadmap.

Comment: *"I do also love that its sticky, I find myself reading very long questions fairly often and its nice to have it there for notifications"* I've seen a couple of people say this, and it doesn't make sense to me. I also find myself reading long Q&A often, but I never want my concentration to be interrupted by blinkenlights. I want to finish reading first, and *then* turn my attention to whatever else needs it. Why is it that you enjoy having your concentration broken?

Comment: @CodyGray I don't find that it breaks my concentration at all, I will mentally take note of it changing but continue what I was reading; or If I'm actually waiting for an answer or feed back I will look at the notification quickly to see if that's what it was. Interestingly this is also how I handle notifications in windows, outlook, and visual studio.

Answer (score -7):

[status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) - we will not bring a "click to scroll to top" functionality.

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) I am still missing the "click navbar to scroll to top" like Google+ for example uses it.
On questions with multiple/long answers this is highly missed on my side.

"Pos1" key arguments: yes there is a key but on a website, especially on searching, I barely use the keyboard after I added my search term. Rest is done with the mouse only.

Comment: [feature-request]? UPDATE: it may actually exist somewhere already, not sure.

Answer (score -9):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) A compromise between sticky and non-sticky.

Make it non-sticky when scrolling down, and pop back in when scrolling up.
The Chrome browser on my phone and tablet do this and I find the behavior intuitive, friendly and respectful of the limited real estate available.

It gives those of us that find the sticky nav bar distracting the extra vertical real estate, and keeps it handy when we want it.

Comment: [No, please no!!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon/341892#comment435473_341892)

Comment: This is even worse than a plain sticky bar. I absolutely loathe this behavior.

Comment: I just got served a version that does this and find it obnoxious, that's just me though.

Answer (score -22):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) Please add a blurred background to the topbar:

[image: Blurred!!1]

Here’s the CSS:

```css
@supports (-webkit-backdrop-filter: none) or (backdrop-filter: none) {
    .so-header {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
                backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be superfluous if [it wasn't sticky in the first place](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343132/476) *cough cough hack phlegm*, but if it *has* to be sticky, at least make it cool. +1 :D

Comment: @deceze I, for one, have the old topbar [sticky](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/34727) and with [a blurred background](http://stackapps.com/q/6968/34727).

Comment: You monster! ;-)

Comment: One of my problems with sticky top bars is that I keep thinking “There's something behind that. I wanna see it.” It's not a good feeling. *Strengthening* that feeling would be downright cruel to people like me.