# How does Stack Overflow (technically) perform opt-in like A/B tests?

Tags: support, a-b-testing

I've only recently seen the new post about the top bar being A/B tested during these weeks, and that currently this week bug tests will be their focus. Nevertheless, how do you structure the system in such a way you're able to make users "opt-in" into A/B tests and subsequently change the stylesheets served to the user, or even just the HTML.

Are there services that do these things or it's all developed in-house?

Related: [Help test the new Top Nav: phase 3 testing runs this week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This isn't as complicated as you might imagine, since "opt in" alpha testing only applies to logged in users with accounts (you enable it via your user preferences screen). We don't expect the number of participants to be anywhere near a large number (in relative terms). This means that we *essentially* just use a `HashSet<int>` of the account-ids that are in the alpha test, and a list of the currently **enabled** alpha tests (so we can turn them off if there is a problem) and just wrap up all the related tests into a utility method that we can call in the UI code (and, more rarely, logic code). For example, the navbar code is *basically* just an `if` test in the razor cshtml:

```
@if (Current.InAlphaTest(AlphaFeature.NewNav))
{
    <div>the new thing</div>
}
else
{
    <div>the old thing</div>
}
```

`AlphaFeature` here is just an enum of features that are available for alpha-testing. The `InAlphaTest` method does all the worrying about which tests are active, whether the current user has an account, and if so whether they are in the alpha-test. CSS is a little trickier, but there's two viable options:

- include an additional CSS resource if enabled
- add an extra class to some root element that triggers different CSS behaviors

Both work, but ultimately the key thing there is "carefully", because CSS can have nuanced results on random pages.

As for backing storage for this: we use a redis unsorted set to track the accounts in each alpha; enrolling or leaving is essentially a [`SADD`](https://redis.io/commands/sadd) / [`SREM`](https://redis.io/commands/srem). We don't go to redis everytime we check, though - which is why there's some text about a possible delay between checking / unchecking the flag and seeing the change. You need to wait for the in-memory cache (`HashSet<int>`) to be observed as getting stale - then we'll hit redis and load the current sorted set into local memory. We *could* probably do something more clever there so we can spot true changes, but... meh: it isn't a problem. We only solve actual problems.

So basically: we keep it deliberately simple and obvious. We like simple and obvious - they make code easy to maintain, easy to refactor, and *usually* keep things pretty fast (by avoiding unnecessary abstractions and complications that you aren't really utilizing).