# New Top Nav should not overlay review-bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

The new top navigation seems to overlay the review bar:

[image]

This makes reviewing slightly more 'tedious' since I would have to scroll up for each review in order to click the buttons.

And also (self-explanatory):

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed in the next build. I changed most places that handle scrolling in some way to ensure that the sticky top nav doesn't obscure anything it shouldn't, but this was one I missed. Thanks for noting!