# New Top Bar - Where's the "help" menu gone?

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

I often use the `help` menu to quickly get to the `Help Center` when looking for snippets to post on answers whilst reviewing them.

This is what it used to look like:

[image: The word "help" with a down arrow located just left of the search bar.]

This seems to have now disappeared from the New Top Nav:

[image: There is no longer a link titled 'help' and none of the icon menus indicate they contain help information.]

I appreciate the links are at the bottom of every page however I feel it would be more beneficial to have the `help` menu, especially for newcomers who are still familiarising themselves with the site.

Is there a reason it's been taken off?

Comment: For high-reps that was deemed no longer needed. http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5747416#5747416  but I didn't find the source

Comment: @rene thanks. What's deemed as "high-rep"

Comment: @rene But I still have no idea what I'm doing!

Comment: "High rep" (Not what I would call 500 rep...) or no, I used the help center link often to easily get there to refresh my memory or to quote/link pages for users here on Meta. Not loving this particular change...

Comment: @deceze yeah, we know. That is why you have the diamond... so we can easy recognize those type of users ...

Comment: I *like* my dunce cap, thankyouverymuch!

Comment: we keep help icon for users who don't have access to /review yet. once you get access to /review we just replace help icon with review. "high-rep" vs "low-rep" was our internal naming convention for those two cases. nevertheless, for "high-rep" users Help Center is still accessible from footer. (this is actually area where most of websites put "help" link so it's quite common pattern. and yes, i know there are other sites too :))

Comment: also reported [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343167#343167) by ShadowWizard.

Comment: @rene I've just had a scroll through there myself and upvoted that very answer :)

Comment: @Paweł If I'm writing a comment at the top of the page, and I need to link to the help center, I don't want to have to scroll down to hit the help center. I used the help center link _at least_ five-seven times a week, and I'm not going to appreciate having to slip to the bottom of the page to access this. If I want to remind myself of something or help someone else learn something, I don't want to be forced to hit the footer and search those links for the help link. Everything else I can make myself get used to, but this breaks my flow for helping people, especially on Meta.

Comment: I have to agree with @Kendra and since it's now sticky this would make even more sense. I don't particular want to lose my place on a page to hit the Help Centre.

Comment: @Kendra i understand that and I'm really sory but please try to consider fact that majority of our users didn't use that help link in top bar. people just don't read help usually so for majority of users this link was simply useless. your effort trying to teach others (and linking to help) is priceless but we still need to consider needs of other users as well. that area in header is very "expensive" and we're trying to keep there only essential and most useful things. but i agree that we, as company, need to do better job at informing users about help. but link in header is not a solution...

Comment: @Kendra We're looking at just adding a keyboard shortcut that opens help in a new tab, would that help ease your use case?

Comment: @Paweł maybe provide a link to the "Help Centre" next to "chat" and "log out" which can be found by selecting the end icon (when switching between SE sites).

Comment: @TimPost that would work definitely for me, yes.

Comment: @Paweł there is moving cheese around, and taking away parts of the cheese. I didn't expect the new top bar to have less links. Still not the end of the world, but it's just another reason to dislike it.

Comment: @TimPost that would suit me also.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I agree with your comment. For me it doesn't make sense to remove "help" from an accessible place such as the top bar.

Comment: @TimPost That would definitely help, I would be happy with that. :)

Comment: @Bugs your suggestion about putting it next to "chat" and "logout" links is something we have plan for.. we have dropdowns update on our plate and this is one of the ideas we have. so it's definitely on roadmap.

Comment: I think I'm in the majority of users who never uses the help menu--but I'm also one of the users that often tells some of our newer posters to please go to the help menu and get some information about how to ask a decent question.  I don't think making those posters scroll all the way to the bottom and hunt for the help button helps my cause any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's back.

(at least for me)

[image: The help menu is now the question mark icon on the far right of the top navigation bar.]

Comment: Likewise. I noticed it a couple days ago.

Comment: Yeah I noticed a little while back and popped a question on Tim's answer but haven't got a response. It seems fitting to make this the accepted answer now though.

Answer (score -23):

We have a couple of problems intersecting here. First, the people that can probably most benefit from clicking on the help link seldom or never click on it. That we need to make help more 'just in time' across the board is something we've known for quite a while, and it's something we'll do.

Removing it for experienced users is (according to a whole lot of testing that we completed) the best possible use of that very constrained space, for everyone that *doesn't* often go out of their way to help other users; we're sorry that we overlooked the need for you to have ready access to it.

We're going to add a keyboard shortcut that opens help in a new tab. That's something very convenient to have *regardless* of the presence of the link, so it's just smart to do. It'll be discoverable on the privileges page.

Will update this answer with details of the keys once the build goes out. And again, did not mean to overlook this case - we as community critters use it all the time too and I guess it was just so automatic that it never came to mind.

**Update**

`G -> E` will be the shortcut (H currently occupied by the homepage), which you can use after you enable keyboard shortcuts in your profile 'preferences' section.

As with other navigation keyboard shortcuts, you need to hold shift to open it in a new tab.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you able to share how often some of the other links are utilized? How often are "Tags" and "Users" used by experienced users?

Comment: Excited to get the shortcut- It'll be an improvement over the old process anyway. I'm glad we got such a quick response on this. (And it fixes my one major gripe with the new top bar.)

Comment: So how does one find the list of keyboard shortcuts without going to the help page first? Is it buried in the profile settings somewhere?

Comment: @JonEricson it says when you enable them. `When enabled, press ? for help` Which throws them up for you to use.

Comment: I think rather than just downvoting this answer (not that it bothers me) it would be worth adding a comment as to why you feel it's worth downvoting and maybe suggestions etc.

Comment: That's all a very bad idea. We're used to refer users that have missed to research there first, to go there.

Comment: I frequently "used to use" the dropdown menu for the Help section myself (before the new navbar). They want to make a new navbar, then they should keep the most useful stuff available. It's bad enough that they want me to "Hit the Home button" to go "back to top", that I'm to let go of the mouse and use a hotkey. 95% (surf) usage is the mouse. Are we back in DOS 5.0 days?

Comment: Why not just add a profile preference, so one can use the old bar if they want?

Comment: Having a different skin for us old-timers is confusing in its own right.  I don't personally need the help menu much but I frequently post instructions pointing to it, and now it looks like it isn't there any longer.

Comment: I was looking for Help just now but I had to search meta before finding it. A single link on the List of Stack Exchange sites menu would be helpful and not too intrusive.

Comment: @Oded Any chance we could get the help link added to the site switcher as well?  You could have it as a link right next to the chat link.  I do not use keyboard shortcuts and having to keep going to the bottom of the page is getting really annoying.

Comment: @NathanOliver - we are looking at options, that's certainly one of them.

Comment: I don't see any problem in making it fit. I've made a picture in Paint showing how it could fit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4pkN.png

Comment: @Oded, thanks. Just seen that the help menu is now located next to chat and log out.

Comment: ME TOO!  ME TOO!   I was looking at a really awful question from a first time user (rep=1) and I wanted to say "Read the Help information that you can find .... "  oops.  I couldn't find it!   The idea that they might stop in the middle of asking a question to follow a link is iffy. [I'm being nice]   The thought that they will scoll way down and find "help" in that bar that is used for legal boilerplate on most sites [you know the one that people never read!] is even iffier.   BRING BACK A BIG BOLD HELP ICON, PLEASE!

Comment: What the actual...? I *really* don't see why the site name on top has to be split into a non-linking logo and a separate Stack Exchange icon, and this vital link has to go. I mod on Graphic Design, and the links in the help menu are essential to guide both new and existing users to the right content. Hiding things behind a keyboard shortcut is horrible UX imho.

Comment: Tim, I see the help menu is now back. Is this something that is being tested or here to stay?