# Help icon in the new top bar

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

We should have a help button in the top bar. It is inconvenient to scroll to the footer and then find the help link. It was there in the previous top bar and that was more convenient.

**EDIT**

My question is different because I am asking for a feature. But the linked question is asking for the reason "Is there a reason it's been taken off(the navbar)?". The answer does not satisfy my question because it is refering to the reasons. I am asking whether it is possible to get  the help button back. That will increase the ease of use. Thanks.

I saw `pawel's comment` but would like to keep it open to know if there is some other plan they have for the help icon.

**Note**
[It is mentioned in the top navigation update as well](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update)

> Access to Help - this is currently available in the nav for anonymous & low rep users. We’re not sure it’s necessary as a persistent nav item, but we are thinking about it. 1, 2, 3, 4

Also through this question I would like prioritize the fact that the help icon is necessary for seasoned users as well cause it contains help centre link. Most of the cases seasoned users need detailed answer.

Comment: This is already on the open issues list: [Top Navigation Update](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343653/2675154) (search for: "Access to Help")

Comment: Workaround: Keyboard shortcut G -> E

Comment: Possible duplicate of [New Top Bar - Where's the "help" menu gone?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343165/new-top-bar-wheres-the-help-menu-gone) See also [Pawel's comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343165/new-top-bar-wheres-the-help-menu-gone#comment444100_343165): *your suggestion about putting it next to "chat" and "logout" links is something we have plan for.. we have dropdowns update on our plate and this is one of the ideas we have. so it's definitely on roadmap.*

Comment: @Veve, that could be the answer to this question. Instead of making people have to look into comments there or here.