# Review queues do not belong there

Tags: feature-request, top-bar

There is a block with in-site navigation and a block with user-specific information. But for some reason the <kbd>Review queues</kbd> button is placed after the user-specific block. It would be better to place it in the first block.

Also I think they are more important than lists of users and tags. Why would a novice user likely need to search for users and tags?

[image: screenshot]

By the way: **currently this button is the only link to the other page between 3 buttons opening dropdowns**. If I click it as any of 3 buttons around, I'm navigating to the other page and it is an unwanted navigation!

PS: [I'd like to move SE sites button too](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343986/4928642).

Comment: But it is user specific, because it depend on your privileges by reputation. Users with less than 500 rep can't review posts, while they can view questions/tags/users

Comment: The way I see it, if the devs put the review queue button in such an inconvenient place, they clearly don't want me to use the review queue. So, I simply removed the button with uBlock Origin. Problem solved! :D

Comment: @JackManey, you mean the place they placed it, or the plase I propose to place it?

Comment: @Qwertiy The former.

Comment: I give you credits that tags... could have been placed in a more subtile way, it's unlikely someone just reach the site and use... tags

Answer (score 2):

I think you're wrong - It does belong there, because the left block is for quick access to discover content on SO, while the right block is about metrics and moderation.

A user can review when they have at least 500 reputation and as you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues), it's a Moderation Privilege, so I don't understand why you think it should be anywhere else.

You wrote *"currently this button is the only link to the other page between 3 buttons opening dropdowns"*. So? If you click on the badges, or on your thumbnail you don't see a dropdown either.

The only thing I agree with, is the lack of importance of users and tags. I too believe that about 95% of the users will *NOT* (Thanks @KevingB!) likely need to search for users and tags (But perhaps I'm wrong - I don't have access to the statistics to support it) and they can safely be moved to the footer area - As they did with the [Help menu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343165/new-top-bar-wheres-the-help-menu-gone). This make the necessary space to include the large logo of SO as you suggested:  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343985/the-stack-overflow-logo-is-too-narrow

Comment: It's like in gui programs top-level menu where one of the items was an action, whan others are opening submenu hase always been considered a bad practice. There are 4 icons in the same style, they look equal, but one of them leads to other page, when the others don't. It's bad. It's absolutely clear it's bad.

Comment: @Qwertiy What's "gui programs top-level menu" where can I see it? And when you say "always been considered a bad practice" can you show include a reference that support your harsh claim?

Answer (score 1):

The way I see this (literally), the "review queues" button is part of the user-specific block. And since this is an action that can only be done by users who are logged in, it is in the right place.

I could imagine new users looking for specific tags or users; either because they had a problem with a specific technology, or were looking for a famous user. For example, they might be looking for Jon Skeet, or for "frosty" - the pseudonym that Ross William Ulbricht used in the famous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15445285/812149) that exposed him.

So, in my opinion, this button is in the right place.