# Quick route from Meta to Main

Tags: discussion, status-completed, top-bar

After multiple years of use, one of my "muscle memories" is navigating from Meta to Main, something I do fairly frequently after seeing something in Hot Meta Posts etc.  On the old navigation it was easy - first click Stack Exchange, then move my mouse straight down and click the Main site:

[image]

This functionality has now moved over to the right hand menu, and is a slightly worse experience:

[image]

Upon clicking, if I move down, I'm either near the scollbar or the logout link, and have to move across as well.  The other alternative is to just aim for the large gap to the left:

[image]

But in doing so, my mouse crosses the blue lines and the menu closes.

Is there a different, quick route from Meta to Main that I'm missing that's not as frustrating as the new dropdown menu?

Comment: Create a bookmark in your internet browser or go back to old version until new one becomes permanent, I think are the only options. It's annoying so opted back out of it

Comment: Agreed. This has also been mentioned [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343166/189134) and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343136/189134)

Comment: @Cal-cium Bookmarks become a bit tedius for all the different sites on the network - SO isn't the only one I do this on.  I'm not averse to change, but when simple things get worse it's noticeable.

Comment: @Andy Yes - the answer by Deceze in particular is exactly the same.

Comment: Use the links in the handy-dandy Community Bulletin!

Comment: I usually just click on my profile. The main user/meta user links there feel easier to me than picking a menu item for some reason.

Comment: @Don'tPanic That still takes you to your user though, rather than being able to jump straight back to the question list

Comment: That's true. I usually go to my profile anyway after switching back to check my "all actions" tab to remind myself if there was something I meant to revisit. I forgot that other people have functional memories and don't need to do that. :)

Comment: Are the keyboard shortcuts an option for you? I just found out, through a command I've never used, that there is a "Go To..." option with a sub option of "Main". `G` --> `M`, or `G` --> `Shift` + `M` if you want a new tab. This command works the exact same on the main site, except it brings you back to meta.

Comment: @Kendra Perhaps, yes!  Though for some reason they don't appear to work for me on the main site at the moment, that's something to look at tomorrow though and it's meta->main that's more of an issue for me

Comment: we did it this way because it's more in line with behaviour of "old" top bar which still will be in use on other sites in the network. although you're right it's not perfect. and we will fix it with one of upcoming builds.

Comment: @JamesThorpe have you enabled them in both _Meta_ and _Main_. I found shortcuts not to be working on _Main_ because I had yet to enable them for my main user in settings.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, just click the **help** menu, then **Back to Stack Overflow** and ... oh wait ...

Comment: @Bugs ah, quite possibly not - am on mobile now, but will check when back at a desktop

Comment: The hamburger SE icon should really be click based, not hover based... or better yet, have the links all be right-aligned instead.

Comment: @TylerH In Chromium and Firefox it appears it is now click-based (at least for me). OP says `my mouse crosses the blue lines and the menu closes`. That's not happening for me.

Comment: @Nateowami Just got in this morning - the behaviour has indeed changed overnight - you now need to click on each individual icon to expand their menus, rather than clicking once on any of them and just moving your mouse around to expand each

Comment: this issue has been fixed and should be now on production (and looks like it is).

Comment: @Paweł Yes, it's much better now, thanks!