# Not a fan of the "Questions" link being highlighted; what purpose does it actually serve again?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, top-bar

This relates to the [new top nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343103/1079354).  Those that *can't* see it will still observe this behavior.

I know this is the base behavior, but I'm no fan of it.

> [image]

I *think* it's meant to behave as a pseudo-breadcrumb and inform me that I'm looking at a question.  That's okay-ish, but if I click on it, I'm taken naturally to ***all*** questions on the site.

Given that this is reasonably close to my click-habit - that is, out of habit I navigate first to the main page and then to topics I'm interested in - this is actually quite jarring and tough to navigate through.  Essentially, I add more clicks to get to questions I'm interested in.

It also violates some expectations of what the Questions tab really needs to do, since I can't do anything in particular with all questions.

Would it make sense instead to either change the verbiage to "All Questions", or to have the tab serve a more useful purpose, like allowing us to encapsulate our favorite tags in it instead?

> [image]

No, I have no idea how that's supposed to look, but I don't really think that the "Questions" (or for that matter the "Tags") tab(s) serve us that much value.

Comment: If you click on the "questions"  button on the old UI, it turns orange as well, this just carries over that behavior (go incognito, click on "questions", and you'll see what I mean). Could it be perhaps that this is just making how it used to work more noticeable?

Comment: @TimPost:  It definitely is.  This is a holdover and existing behavior which I entirely acknowledge, but that doesn't mean that this behavior makes much sense anymore.  It feels strange to me that the Questions (and honestly Tags) tabs are now thrust more into the spotlight, despite them not having much practical use; if I want to see the questions I care about, I have to click on the icon to the left, *then* click on the tab I want to pay attention to.  I'm thinking that the top bar simply brought this to a head.

Comment: That was the first thing I turned off when I wrote my modifications user script, that and the bottom border, then I decided to remove the questions link entirely along with the jobs, docs, tags, and users links.

Comment: I think what's even more confusing is, opening the questions page by clicking on "Questions" highlights the tab, while opening the exact same page by a click on the logo doesn't highlight the tab, however it's the exact same page we see.

Comment: I agree that it is weird... But not sure how it supposed to look too. Using different colors, maybe?

Comment: @baao isn't that the home page? I do think they are not the exact same page.