# new Top Nav: reputation change - bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, top-bar

New Top Nav reputation change show us notification about reputation change (green square) but doesn't change reputation total score (red square). Even if i open achivements panel - nothing is changed in green square. It changes only with page reload.

[image]

Old Top Nav changes your total reputation in ajax manner. Is that bug or by design?

Comment: I thought the achievements number had been changed to green instead of blue?

Comment: @CodyGray already - yeah =) But still

Comment: So this is an old screen shot? I don't mean the green square that *you* drew, by the way.

Comment: @CodyGray i take it 30 min ago. Not sure if anything changes from that moment exept css styles

Comment: [This is what it should look like](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343130/366904). I note there that a bug is mentioned: the color is blue on web socket updates.

Comment: @CodyGray - that's fixed and deployed (requires a page refresh, but subsequent websocket updates will be the right color).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

The new header has a different HTML structure, and I didn't notice that rep changes were not updating anymore.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Gland to know, thx for fast response