# Flag count disappears after closing the moderator inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, top-bar, moderator-tools

With the new top bar, the flag count disappears after opening and closing the moderator inbox:

[image: a shiny jiff]

While this makes sense for the inbox, it doesn't make sense here.

Comment: Side-note, since this is a bug report, shouldn't this be posted as an answer to the [featured post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week?cb=1)?

Comment: @Tunaki That's what everyone is doing, but the original post seems to say otherwise: *"Please create a new post with the ‘top-bar’ tag if you find new bugs."*

Comment: Ha, missed that...!

Comment: Yeah, that's on my list of things to fix :)

Comment: @Oded also - any reason one figure says 137 and the other 136 as shown in Undo's example? Surely they can't be pulling the count from different places (especially given the tiny amount of time before expanding the drop down)?

Comment: @Jon - probably a flag got handled between page load and popup load. The blue bubble doesn't update in real time, the popup is always up to date.

Comment: @Oded ahh... I could load a page and the blue bubble would be accurate, wander off for half an hour then load the popup - got you. Not sure it's worth it, but should the popup update the bubble then?

Comment: That's a thought. Updating it in real-time would require a bunch of work, but a "open popup, check value and update if different" should be a cheap way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We ended up separating the flag count out - just like it was/is in the black top bar.

Comment: Much better. It feels a little bit *too* noticeable/big/bold now, but I'm probably just used to how it was before. Thank you!