# Missing Close Button Due to z-index Issue

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

The stack snippets close button is missing after clicking "Full page".  It appears to be an issue with the `z-index`.  The iframe for the stack snippet has an inlined `z-index: 1030`, but the close button has a `z-index: 999` on the style rule `.snippet-code .popin`.  The result is that you can't click on the close button and have to either reload the page or modify the style using developer tools to close the snippet view. Changing the `.snippet-code .popin` rule to `z-index: 1030;` corrects the issue.

[image: Attached screen cap to demonstrate where the problem is occurring in the code]

Can we get this corrected, please?

Comment: Also reported [in this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343170/2607247) on the announcement post.