# New Nav cuts off the tops of my words in the More Stack Exchange Communities box

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

This is specific to the new nav - I tried, and it's not broken on the other sites.

[image]

I'm on Firefox 50.0.1 (x32) Windows

Comment: What browser?  [Seems fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngFTt.png) for me (Chrome 56.0.2924.87 on Windows 10)

Comment: Edited.  FF50 Windows 10

Comment: @James, also, are you using the new nav bar?

Comment: Yes - using new nav.  Also just confirmed I'm seeing the same problem with FF 51

Comment: We are looking into this.

Comment: [Reported already](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343379), also the same issue in the [Your communities textbox too](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343349)