# Achievement icon in new top bar is shaded green even when there's no badge achievement

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

After multiple feature requests ([1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343130), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343216)) in the latest top bar update, the different notification colors were added back. However, the achievement icon (not the count, the icon) turns green even when there are only upvote notifications.

[image: icon color demo]

For notifications and reviews, the count is colored but not the icon. For achievements, the count and icon are colored, even though I did not receive a badge. I expect the icon to be colored only for badge notifications.

Comment: The old achievement icon did turn green.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, when there were badge achievements. I'm saying that it's always turning green for me when there are *any* achievements now.

Comment: I think @Tiny meant that it turned green for rep changes too; that's my impression concerning the old icon at least.

Comment: @AndrasDeak the old icon was covered up when there were rep changes. If it turned green for any notification, that's still inconsistent with how all the other new icons behave.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. I always browse at 90% zoom, at which point the colored background can be seen

Comment: Maybe it's the other icons that need to change then. Why's it always gotta be the achievements icon that has to change to suit every other button? :P

Comment: I think you'll have the distinction when it is colored but doesn't have a badge, no?

Comment: Seems to be fixed now http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343130/5233410 based on the same post referred to in OP

Comment: @Nkosi I'm not observing the expected behavior, as the screenshot shows

Comment: I don't get what you're moaning about, the icon always changed green when there was a rep change.

Comment: @Lankymart the number, not the icon. The icon was only green for badges. Also, I'm not "moaning", I'm reporting a bug.

Comment: @davidism not what I remember, I don't get badges very often *(crux of spending time in low traffic tags)* but I get rep changes all the time and the bar graph icon used to go green.

Comment: @Lankymart - that it did, doesn't mean that was the right behaviour.

Comment: @Oded I'm lost, so the OP is saying it didn't, both of us are saying it did? So I'll refer to my previous statement...what are they moaning about?

Comment: @Lankymart - OP is reporting a bug. The bug has become a lot more apparent in the new design. I don't know why you have to go into personal attacks on a bug report though.

Comment: @Oded just trying to make sense of the question...the reason for complaining was wrong whether it was a bug or not it's been one for ages.

Comment: @Lankymart - where do you see a complaint? I see a bug report.

Comment: @Oded whatever! The OP reported based off a falsely, that the icon only changed green for badges, which was incorrect, it's been that way as long as I can remember.

Comment: And I am saying that though "it's been that way as long as I can remember", @Lankymart, that behaviour was wrong since then... Just because a bug existed since the dawn of time doesn't make it any less of a bug ;)

Comment: I'll just leave this here... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210637/on-rep-changes-highlight-icon-in-top-bar-instead-of-showing-number/210638#210638

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this bug.

As others have commented, this isn't a change in functionality - the black top bar behaved the same (though it is more difficult to see, as the number pretty much covers the icon).

The new design shows this much more clearly - and it is a bug - the icon should only highlight when you have unread achievements.

I have fixed this bug now - the fix will be available in the next deploy.