# Different behavior of items in the top bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, top-bar

I've looked and haven't seen this behavior reported yet. In the old top bar, once you clicked to see your inbox or your reputation changes, you could hover your mouse over the other items and they were automatically displayed. With the new top bar, you need to actually click again to see the items.

I'm not sure if this is the intended behavior, just reporting this in case it was not.

Old Top Bar:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We changed the behaviour after feedback.

When trying to select sites from the communities drop down, the mouse could easily move outside of the button onto the next button, causing the drop down to close and another to open.

See this answer for an illustration of the problem:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343136/1583

Comment: I see. Yeah, I understand the issues that the previous behavior could bring, just making sure the change was on purpose, since I hadn't seen anything about it. Thanks