# Why was this site suddenly renamed to "Questions"?

Tags: discussion, design, top-bar, user-experience

It is a convention that the name of the website has a prominent spot on top or is the most top left most element. Therefore this site now either called "Questions" or "Top Questions". The URL says stackoverflow. I am so confused!

[image]

Comment: You may be interested in this comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week?page=2&tab=oldest#comment444533_343275

Comment: Interestingly in your screenshot, the top left corner does correctly state stack overflow

Comment: I think that *Questions* would be a very cool name for StackOverflow. We should rename it immediately!

Comment: It's called Questions because Quora was already taken.

Comment: Suggestion: make the search box say *Search Stack Overflow*. That is what GitHub does (which is *also* just a logo, a search box and some tabs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the page title in browser's title bar.
A logo is enough to identify a popular brand and here, it does.
"Questions" is the tab to access questions.
That is navigation pane and each icon including "Questions" are tab titles.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question as it just begs the question. But of course it's my opinion, and the green check mark says otherwise.