# The review icon number, what does it mean

Tags: discussion, review-queues

This little bugger

[image]

What does this seemingly random number mean? It changes constantly between 10 and 70 for me, without any logic to me, and I can't seem to influence it.

So why is this number the number that it is, and why does it change so often. Because at this point it's just an annoying [meaningless number to me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343256?noredirect=1#343256) and [i'm not the only one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update?cb=1#343663) it seems.

I tried looking at meta for an explanation of this "magic" number, but I couldn't find any, so here's the question:

How is this number compiled/calculated, and what it should mean to me.