# New search bar flickers

Tags: bug, search, top-bar

The new search bar in the top has a bug.

After you enter your search text and press search (or enter) the magnifier icon overlaps the search text and flickers two times.

Browser/OS:
Firefox 51/Windows 7

Does NOT appear with
Chrome/Internet Explorer 11/Windows 7

[image: search icon flickers]

Comment: are u on ubuntu?

Comment: no, as I wrote in the question I use Windows 7.

Comment: Reproduced with SeaMonkey 2.46 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already noted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343532/4074148), marqued by [Oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) on Feb. 13 as

> `status-completed` (in the next build)

Comment: The current build is *rev 2017.2.21.25181* and it's still happening. I'll try pinging Oded via that answer.