# New design broke hovering on the buttons

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, top-bar

Try to click on any of the top buttons and ***hover*** to the left or to the right. The previous behavior (consistent across all Stack Exchange sites) is basically this:

1. Click
2. Hover
3. Opened "popup" disappears
4. New one (from the button you hover to) appears

**Old:**

[image]

The new one, however, is missing steps 3 and 4.

**New:**

[image]

Comment: I way prefer this behaviour to the new one... now, too many clicks are required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design.  When it behaves as you propose it makes it extremely difficult to move the mouse from where you click to open the popup to the actual popup itself without moving over one of the other icons, closing the popup and opening another.  This problem did exist on the old design, but was less of a problem due to larger icons that are further apart, making it less likely to accidentally hover over another one when moving onto the popup.

Comment: Oh? Are you sure? I see correct hovering. Any link to the bug report or better a gif/video for the old behavior? I can move mouse into the popup, scroll, click, everything... Or do you mean it like this - a user might accidentally move the mouse through the bottom (or bottom-left) edge of the near icon?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week/343136#343136

Comment: @davidism +1 so it's that. Well a possible fix might be to make hovering through the `svg` tag directly (pics are small).

Comment: This new behaviour is annoying, and I can only disagree (strongly) that the hover behaviour makes it "extremely difficult" to avoid accidentally hovering over another icon. One simply moves the mouse *directly downwards* -- an exceptionally *easy* movement to make. The hover is convenient. Forcing additional clicking is inconvenient.

Comment: I fully agree with @phils comment, this new behaviour has too much clicking required and is quite annoying. I would argue that it was not difficult to move the mouse at all, if one has full hand-eye coordination, and not suffering from some medical disorder (or hungover). After all, OS X behaves this way. Maybe it would be a good idea to make it a switchable option, if that is possible? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297859/new-toolbar-cant-click-once-and-then-open-menus-by-just-moving-mouse