# People reached popup chopped off by top bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, tooltips

This isn't major and is probably picky but I happened to notice and so thought it would make sense to report.

See screenshot:

[image]

I'm using Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit) and zoom is 100% although this doesn't make much of a difference. On IE 11 the text is visible but the top of the popup is still slightly cut:

[image]

As I said, not major but thought I would point this out. I can't see if it's been logged before but maybe mistaken, especially if it's been logged as an answer.

Comment: It was [reported and fixed already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343357/2451726). But it breaks again.

Comment: Thanks @Arulkumar I had a feeling it would have previously been logged in an answer somewhere. But yeah definitely broken again.

Comment: I read it as "People reached popup, chopped off by top bar". That sounded messy.

Comment: @Arulkumar more evidence that SE performs next to no regression testing. sad.

Comment: I am interessted what this z-index-fix is breaking then. It seems to be a endless war.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fixed now:

> [image: impact]

Tooltip text flows to the bottom now.