# Apply the pop over tooltip to the Profile tab's people reached section

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, tooltips, people-reached

As I know, there is an alignment issue [reported for the people reached tootip](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349758/2451726). Once the issue is fixed, my feature-request is to apply the new tooltip to the **Profile tab**'s people reached too.

When we are viewing the people reached from the [Activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current), the new pop over tooltip is visible.

[image: New tooltip]

But when we are viewing the people reached from the [Profile tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=profile), it is still showing in the old format.

[image: Old tooltip]