# Developer Story tab tooltip behind top bar

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, developer-story, tooltips

I have just noticed that the tooltip on the Developer Story tab in my profile is behind the top bar. So you really can read only the half of the message. I tested Chrome and Firefox, which both have this issue:

[image: tooltip behind top bar]

Setting the `z-index` of the span element to `5050` above could solve this issue:

```
<span class="icon-warning-label has-tooltip">
    <span class="informative-tooltip display-above size-200 text-centered" 
            style="z-index: 5050;">...</span>
</span>
```

Another alternative would be to show the tooltip at the bottom of the icon.

Comment: Related: [People reached popup chopped off by top bar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349758/4642212).