# Can the podcast please stop making episodes about cryptocurrencies and NFTs?

Tags: discussion, podcast

I subscribed to the Stack Overflow Podcast because its description matches me and my interests perfectly:

> The Stack Overflow podcast is a weekly conversation about working in software development, learning to code, and the art and culture of computer programming

<sup>From [the RSS feed description](https://feeds.simplecast.com/XA_851k3)</sup>

As a person who really enjoys teaching folks how to make software, and keeping abreast of new developments in the software engineering world, I have been enjoying the past few years of episodes as ways for me to enjoy hearing how people work together and develop software to make new and interesting solutions to real-world problems. Y'know, the whole reason Stack Overflow exists

Blockchain as a distributed, cryptographically-signed ledger is a very interesting technology that has the capability to solve lots of cool real-world problems and make folks' lives better. Building atop that a way to track ownership is interesting, too. However, as I currently understand it and as is described on the show recently, Ethereum NFTs are not that; they're basically fancy URLs that anyone with enough Ethereum can claim ownership over.

On the show they only talk about Etherium NFTs, and sometimes tangent into discussing cryptocurrencies like Dogecoin. These discussions don't involve any software engineering, nor development, nor coding; just Etherium NFTs, how to create and use them, what they are for, supply-and-demand, returns on investment, etc.

**This all doesn't seem to fit the show very well**; it's ostensibly a show about the kinds of problems that Stack Overflow solves. If someone goes onto Stack Overflow and asks a question about Ethereum or NFTs or similar topics, their question will be closed as off-topic. If the hosts of this podcast love this topic and want to talk about it, I think they should! But perhaps on a new show, **maybe create an [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) podcast.**

Comment: usually the best indicator that your content is missing your audience is how much the audience consumes it or accesses.  If the viewership isn't suffering from the current subject of the podcast, why would they avoid it? and if it is, surely they will.

Comment: @KevinB If you were making a podcast, wouldn't you rather be proactive than reactive? Either way, as far as I'm aware, most podcasts only see download numbers. People like myself have their followed podcasts on auto-download, so even if I remove it from my queue and never listen to it, or if I skip the episode after a few seconds, they still always see 1 download from me.

Comment: @BenLeggiero Do you think it could be balanced by a podcast on the dangers of software being used in a way that enables (greedy) people to damage the environment?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I think that a podcast about the ethical concerns of creating popular software would be really neat! As you imply, it could include power usage at-scale, but also things like managing a social network and the mass mental health issues that entails

Comment: Unfortunately I'm never interested in SO Blog or Podcast. Their constant appearance in the side bar, as well as the titles, has long given me the impression that it's a mix of "soft adverts" and random unrelated stuff.

Comment: That time is not far away when memes will reviewed in stack overflow, which is good in a way XD

Comment: +1 for this whole post, but especially your last sentence. I had no idea there even was an Ethereum Stack Exchange, and now I know, and I'm that much more flustered.

Comment: I'm surprised that you're surprised that the podcast is tending towards the same level of quality that most new questions on the site demonstrate.

Comment: Wait, someone actually listens to that podcast?

Comment: I would love more software-related blockchain talk. Smart Contracts for example, but uh, those are not so sexy to talk about to get the easy clicks.

Comment: Both cryptocurrencies and NFTs are stupid attempts at making something from nothing. I agree w/ this post.

Comment: @KevinB Keep in mind that there are a gazillion podcasts out there... lots of folks just like to talk even if no one is listening.

Comment: There are a lot of places to hear about NFTs and cryptocurrencies, less so for the actual blockchain technology. Why not offer something unique, especially since this is a programming site not reddit or twitter?

Comment: Historical notes: [FTX scandal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankruptcy_of_FTX) (late 2022) and several participants in the podcast with a vested interest in cryptocurrency going up (allegedly) left the podcast.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Stop listening.

Sorry, I know that's not what you want to hear. You were good to voice your
opinion, but the likelihood that this is going to change is next to zero.
Stack Exchange has a long history [1][2][3][4][5] of doing the unpopular thing,
and then ignoring negative community feedback. Money has gotten involved in the decision making, instead of keeping to the original spirit of the podcast.

Even when the topic finally does change from NFT, it's likely just going to be
some other non-programming money based thing. So just read the tea leaves, and
move on.

1. [Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965)
2. [We’re adding more user controls for cookie consent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359358)
3. [We are switching to system fonts on May 10, 2021](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364048)
4. <s>[Please unpin the accepted answer from the top](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326095)</s> (this was [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) at the time this answer was posted, but the company has since changed their mind and it is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))
5. [Help test the new Top Nav: phase 3 testing runs this week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103)

Comment: How are 2, 3, 5 unpopular, given their high positive scores?

Comment: Thank you. It's what I initially did (just stopped auto-placing it in my up-next queue), but I put this out here hoping I might be able to help stuff become better, cuz I really like their engineering- and coding-related discussions.

Comment: "Money has gotten involved in the decision making..." I think people are too quick to blame money for problems. It's not the money. It's the shortsightedness that comes with caring *only* about money, which quickly derails an organization from providing a quality service. SO additionally has a problem with wanting to push a sociopolitical worldview as well, although that is not particularly relevant to *this* particular event. In other words, SO as a company simply does not care about its founding mission anymore, for a variety of reasons, which is a more fundamental problem than money.

Comment: @GoodDeeds look at the answers sorted by votes. On meta, almost everyone has permissions to upvote things, but not everyone has permissions to downvote things. This causes posts to rise in votes there if they are good a small amount of users

Comment: "Stop listening.". That's one possibility. If the SO podcasts mostly contain advertorials or irrelevant content, another possibility would be to stop producing them and concentrate on more important stuff.

Comment: @jpmc26 Experts-exchange didn't start out as a horrible site.  But about 12 years into its run, it had turned into such a festering mess that Joel decided to create "a non-evil alternative."  About 11 years later, SO went full-on evil with the whole Monica mess.  I wonder why there seems to be a 12-year limit on Q&A sites remaining worthwhile?

Comment: How is 4 unpopular? The question is highly upvoted and the most upvoted answer is in support of unpinning the accepted answer.

Comment: @DonaldDuck The request was [tag:status-declined] at the time of writing. The company changed their minds some months later after this answer was posted.

Comment: @E_net4 That makes sense. I edited to include that.

Answer (score 13):

Stack Exchange just followed up with an entire [3](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/03/29/from-web2-to-web3-how-developers-can-upskill-and-build-with-blockchain/?cb=1) [more](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/04/04/from-smalltalk-to-smart-contracts-reflecting-on-50-years-of-programming-ep-511/?cb=1) [articles/podcasts](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/04/05/from-cryptography-to-consensus-qa-with-cto-david-schwartz-on-building-blockchain-apps/?cb=1) on this, around the start of April, instead of delivering us the pranks the majority of us like. I was about to create a new question asking what is going on, but figured I'd have to make it an answer of some kind here, as my question would have been closed as a duplicate.

I find it embarrassing to be a part of a community associated to, and relying on, a company which spreads propaganda and misinformation of this kind. It's an abuse of the respect that the developer community owns. SE should be ashamed of themselves for this.

It seems there's only 2 possibilities here:

1. Do everything you can to run SE into the ground. They will no longer be able to abuse the trust they have.
2. Join the crypto currency crowd in their game to bribe SE, and pour money at SE to make them stop spreading this infestation.

Either way, we lose.

Comment: This is the worst prank.

Comment: @RyanM This can hardly be called a prank. This is bordering crimes against humanity

Comment: My assumption is their pulse surveys continue to get responses putting those buzzword bits as high in demand among users who don't block ads, thus driving them to produce more content in those areas. It's no surprise that while we were dealing with an influx of garbage answers about chatgpt that they suddenly started shooting off AI related blog posts and podcasts. the interest is clearly in optimizing for $$, not useful content.

Comment: @KevinB I am probably to blame for this myself, as I tend to click on those articles just to rip my head off at the stupidity I read there. I don’t listen to the podcasts, though. And the comment section is always a fun place to go.

Comment: 99% of the time my comments on the blog never get approved.

Comment: @KevinB Mine sometimes do, but my latest comment on the «web3» article was declined. It’s my first comment on the blog in a long time.

Comment: No clue what the comments were (the blog is fully staff-controlled), but it wouldn't surprise me if they suppress comments negative to the topic itself regardless of how constructively it's phrased. The blog is probably one of their key SEO grabs, and negative comments wouldn't be great for the image they're trying to convince google's algorithm they have

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine I often get that impression myself, and I tend to believe they partially do this, but there are negative comments leaking through. The majority of the comments on the «web3» article are negative towards the article, which runs counter to your assumption.

Comment: it depends on the subject matter of the article and whether or not there's pending comments to counter the negative. You're far less likely to see standalone negative comments on a post about something SE did, for example.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with [Steven Penny](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/407819).

I've long ago decided to just ignore everything on the Stack Exchange network except interesting questions on the HNQ supercollider and a few select chatrooms I've been in for almost a decade now. I don't even use it to ask programming questions anymore because (and pardon my French here) it has gone to shit over the past years.