# What is the purpose of the top bar update?

Tags: discussion

I want to know what added functionality was this intended to add?

I'm trying to understand why the change was needed in the first place.

Comment: Did you happen to [read the blog post](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation) about it?

Comment: not a fan of it either. it takes up too much space. here's how to disable it http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation

Comment: That image was so big it crashed my RSS reader.

Answer (score 8):

I like everything about the top bar update (well mostly everything).

For more information on the rationale behind the change, see [the blog post](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/?cb=1).

Not much else to provide here as far as an answer goes.

### Related

- [<sup>[blog]</sup> How Stack Overflow Redesigned the Top Navigation](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/Why-Stack-Overflow-Redesigned-the-Top-Navigation/?cb=1)
- [We're Soon to be A/B Testing Some Changes to the Top Nav](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav)
- [Phase Two of Top Navigation Testing Begins Soon!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon)
- [Help test the new Top Nav: phase 3 testing runs this week](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week)
- [We're adding a setting to disable fixed/sticky navigation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation)
- [Top Navigation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update)