# Has the top bar redesign met its goals?

Tags: discussion, top-bar

Back in November 2016, the [first announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337745/were-soon-to-be-a-b-testing-some-changes-to-the-top-nav) of the new top bar was posted. Since then, there have been a [few rounds](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341806/phase-two-of-top-navigation-testing-begins-soon) of [testing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week), before it was [officially released](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update) on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow. Even since there, there have been many bug fixes and updates to further improve its purpose.

We're now six months into this and three months into the official release. It's been mentioned that this top bar will be migrated across the network. Before that happens, I think we need to talk about whether or not the top bar is performing as expected.

In the [second round](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343103/help-test-the-new-top-nav-phase-3-testing-runs-this-week) of testing, a single stat was shared:

> Both previous tests showed great results: users shown the new top nav clicked navigation links 143% more than those shown the current design.

Since then, there have been some changes:

- [The stickiness is now user configurable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343483/were-adding-a-setting-to-disable-fixed-sticky-navigation)
- [The review count has been removed from the icon and replaced with a "live" count on click](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653#346653)
- [The number of reviewers seems to have dropped since implementation and suggested edit reviewers per review has been dropped to 2 from 3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown)

---

Has the top bar change resulted in improvements in any of the following areas?

- The second test showed an increase in navigation bar clicks, has that translated into measurable changes in searching before posting a question?
- Has the new navigation increased click through and application submission on the Jobs side?
- Has the new navigation increased the click through and participation in Documentation?
- We have seen a negative effect of the new navigation bar, in terms of review tasks. Notification fatigue is one possible reason for this and was [mentioned during the testing phase](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343216/189134) (repeatedly). Now that we've experienced this down side and had to change another portion of the system to adjust for this, what was the expected outcome? Further, how will this situation be prevented when it is rolled out to the other sites on the network? How will notification fatigue be reduced or eliminated so that the number of reviewers doesn't decrease so dramatically?
- Has the usage of the help link changed by both high rep and low rep users? "Help" was initially removed from the top bar and users were told to use the link in the footer. It has since been readded to the site change drop down. Did that reintroduction see a change in usage?

Finally, this question is based on a response to Shog's answer where the number of edit reviews required was changed to 2 (from 3).

> [Are there actually any measurable positive effects from the top bar redesign?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown#comment472704_349125)

Comment: It's not that there is less reviews because of the top bar, the difference is that now there's less *suggested edit* reviews because the bar links to *all* review queues, not just that one, so more people are finding other queues, rather than just going to suggested edits because that's where the top bar takes them.

Comment: Just want to chime in that I requested they add help to the drop down next to chat and I do use it.  I use it mainly though as a link to get to the badges and privs pages.

Comment: @Servy, the graphs in [Shog's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349125/189134) seem to indicate that number of reviewers across all queues is down.

Comment: @NathanOliver you can skip that help button by clicking the trophy instead and going directly to badges/privileges. :p

Comment: @KevinB Awesome.  Was that new to the new nav or was that there before?

Comment: pretty sure it was added with the new nav

Comment: Cool.  Well thanks again.  Makes life easier.  I guess the help link isn't as helpful anymore ;)

Comment: I'm working on an answer to this, but it may take a bit to pull together all the most current info (because it's Monday and a few folks are out of the office).

Comment: Please make it easy to nav between SE sites again... I used to use the top left to do so, now it only acts as a homepage to the current SE site I'm on. Less functionality for "power users" on what I assume is a mostly-poweruser site? I hope SO is not using "# of clicks" as an inherently good metric or anything -- could just mean the information architecture is ineffective (which I argue is true).

Comment: @HC_ The functionality is still there. Click the Stack Exchange logo on the top right and the same menu is there.

Comment: I'd kill to have the inbox(es) back on the left. It's where my eyes naturally scan SO and I haven't been able to train myself to look top-right as consistently. I'll quite often be surprised to see 2-3 notifications.

Comment: I was looking for the help link just yesterday and found it only in the footer after a page search ("control+f"). Totally missed it in either the dropdown or footer by just trying to find it. It's not very "discoverable" for such an important link.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker IIRC this link's position changes with you rep level. I think new users have it in the top bar.

Comment: I still dislike switching from stack network site on the right instead of the logo on the left.

Comment: Well, as far as I'm concerned, it's complete garbage and only way to live with it was to install custom stylesheet posted by someone here on meta. It's also super confusing, since nav bars are now inconsistent across SE.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Is "may take a bit" a _wait until people are back in the office_ kind of thing or a _six to eight weeks_ kind of thing? I've checked this page several times in the last 48 hours to see if there's a response.

Comment: I actually like most of the new top-nav. (Notable exceptions: the occasional review guilting and I'd like it _slightly_ darker grey.) I would, however, like to see the answers to @Andy's questions.

Comment: @Michael sorry for the delay, I added an answer below.

Comment: I've grown to like the notifications/inbox on the right. It makes finding SO answers far less distracting when I have notifications as I almost never notice them. And I'm never tempted to click the review notification button. But... I'm not sure if that's the desired effect or not...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your questions align pretty well with the measurable primary and secondary goals for the redesign that I listed a few months back in, "[How Stack Overflow Redesigned the Top Navigation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/14/why-stack-overflow-redesigned-the-top-navigation/)" - so I'll mostly just stick to your list, with some additional stats thrown in where they help to clarify.

**Has that translated into measurable changes in searching before posting a question?**

The average daily number of searches on Stack Overflow has increased since the launch of the redesigned top bar. Previously on an average week we had ~210k searches. After the launch of the redesign, we now average ~265k per week. That's approximately a 25% increase in searches.

[image: Search Traffic]

**Has the new navigation increased click through and application submission on the Jobs side?**

This one is trickier. The new navigation has increased clicks within the top bar to jobs by an additional 36%. We think this contributes to an overall awareness of jobs on Stack Overflow. But it's difficult to directly correlate those clicks with an increase in applications given the anonymous browsing patterns of jobs seekers (applies are fairly equally distributed between anonymous and registered users), the fluctuation of available jobs, the time of year, campaigns, and ongoing experiments within jobs.

[image: Navigation clicks]

**Has the new navigation increased the click through and participation in Documentation?**

Yes. Click throughs on documentation in the top nav are up by about 100%. Overall engagement and activity in documentation has increased. Overall traffic in documentation has almost doubled and contributions are up by about 20%.

**In terms of review tasks...**

These are down more than anticipated, and we recognize that this is not an ideal outcome. We're reviewing the current solution and identifying a set of experiments on different designs that we want to run to try to bring it back to a close level to where it was before we launched the redesign. It's also important for us to address this issue before we launch pieces of the new design to the greater community (this is one of the reasons that we haven't rolled it out yet.)

**Has the usage of the help link changed by both high rep and low rep users?**

The usage of the help link in the top bar has seen a dip (~25%) for anonymous users and a larger dip (~50%) for registered users. When looking at total traffic to the help section the dip is less dramatic (about a 7% decrease) — which tells us people are navigating to help page other ways (like links in comments or the help link in the footer). We're also considering a series of testable solutions along with the review queue test to drive this back up to the pre-redesign level.

**"Help" was initially removed from the top bar and users were told to use the link in the footer. It has since been readded to the site change drop down. Did that reintroduction see a change in usage?**

We saw a small uptick with the re-addition of help to the site switcher, but not enough for us to think it's a perfectly findable solution.

**Have there been other improvements based on the redesign?**

We've also seen a bump (~7%) in users who sign up and users who log in.

One additional note: inbox notifications and achievements shown have neither improved nor decreased with the launch of the new design.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Regarding your very last comment, was it expected that inbox notifications clicks would change? I am making the assumption the answer is "yes, because the mac bar is sticky by default". I am surprised that hasn't changed due to it always being visible for many users.

Comment: @Andy We did expect these to go up, but improvements to inbox and achievements weren't primary goals of the redesign.

Comment: I feel much better about the redesign now that you've shown it had most of the desired effects, even if I personally dislike it.

Comment: The thing that bugs me about the redesign is that the site-switch menu is *on the wrong side* (compared to all the other sites) and it irritates the bajebus out of me when I try to use it and its not where I expect it to be. Hopefully that'll go away when it goes cross-site.

Comment: @Draco18s it bugs me too. Hopefully we can get an update out soon that will re-align SO top nav with the top bar on the network sites.

Comment: @Draco18s - If you use chrome, I made a [small extension for that](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stacktopreorder/ghakoiegoehkphelnkokdicepdhmbbhg).

Comment: @TravisJ I don't typically, but I'm sure someone will find it handy.