# Why the sites menu is on the right corner on Stack Overflow, and on the left on all other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, design, top-bar, stack-exchange

Is there any concept behind the different behaviour, except of webdesign reasons?

For me this is inconsistent, leading to unnecessary mouse movements, when wanting to find the menu, going to left first, as it is there on all Stack Exchange sites except Stack Overflow itself. Is there a reason behind it? Why is it as now, or why is it not changing?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/02/14/why-stack-overflow-redesigned-the-top-navigation/

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349204/has-the-top-bar-redesign-met-its-goals/349386#comment474616_349386